# What do people get by focusing on doing only janitorial moderation?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-abilities

I've been reading [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling) other [similar posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions/252772#252772) and [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), but I couldn't quite get it.

What do those "janitor moderators" get? That is, supposing there are people who do **only** that, which I believe there is. Their service is quite amazing, and they seem to get **nothing** in return IMHO.

Thinking about it... Isn't the Stack Exchange Networks's gamification set in place to motivate people into posting *quality* questions and answers? **Maybe** we could add "to moderate" into that system.

Comment: But it **is** built into the system. Badges for moderating (reviews, for instance), the higher the rep the more moderation tools available. Users can vote to close and delete content. This is **all** moderation.

Comment: @Oded yes, but if you spend time only moderating you won't get anywhere in the game. Or will you?

Comment: That depends on what game you are playing. If the game is - curate great content, then yes, this is everyone winning.

Comment: So, if I get this right, your answer would be something in the lines: "Moderators get to curate great content, what else would you need?"

Comment: @Cawas If it works...

Comment: I had two points. One is that **everyone** who votes, closes and deletes content is moderating. Whether they have a diamond next to their name or not. The second is that by moderating, we keep the site a place we want to keep going to - that's the incentive.

Comment: Cool, but I'm talking about people who do only janitorial moderation. I myself couldn't do it, and I'm simply trying to understand what motivates them. Sorry I'm very bad at conveying my ideas into words... :P

Comment: @Cawas What motivates you to try to earn Imaginary Internet Points?

Comment: @Servy ha, I was waiting someone to ask that. Maybe the main good reason is: explicit recognition. This leads to all other motivations from my point of view there.

Comment: @Cawas You might be interested in the interview with Peter Mortensen, who is a very active non-diamond editor - http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/27/peter-mortensen-editor-in-chief/. Some find satisfaction in helping others with answers, others like to improve existing content.

Comment: @RobW very interesting read indeed. I'll go deeper soon enough, but from what I can tell it still doesn't answer my question. Damn, I'm terrible at asking questions...

Comment: I participate because I hate Googling for crap and I like learning new things that I would never have the ability to learn as fast without StackOverflow. That's my intrinsic motivation.

Comment: @staticx Now, from my point of view, that's an even better answer than Robert's one.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We get a small sense of satisfaction by our meager attempt to make the world a slightly better place by relentlessly taking out the garbage whenever we can.

We often wonder why more community members don't feel the same way.

Comment: We are also probably gluttons for punishment.

Comment: This "attempt to make the world a slightly better place", together with everyone's else valuable input (not just the comments) is good enough for me. Thank you all!

Comment: You also get [guns, a monkey costume, and a nice tux](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5G5dp.png).

Comment: @user1228 - Old post, I know, but I hope [PeterMortensen](http://www.hovedetpaabloggen.dk/2011/09/20/wikipedia-er-der-mon-en-laege-til-stede/) doesn't find out about your comment - he can't change the grammar or spelling in that image!!

Answer (score 12):

You need to be careful when it comes to gamification.  If you take it overboard then you start replacing intrinsic motivation with extrinsic motivation, and doing so actually *harms* the effectiveness of those users.

There are a lot of people that already have a high intrinsic motivation to perform many of this site's moderation activities.

Comment: Interesting. What would that intrinsic motivation be?

Comment: @Cawas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation#Intrinsic_and_extrinsic_motivation

Comment: Not asking definition, I want to know what motivates some people to perform the janitorial moderation, in specific. ;-)

Comment: @Cawas And I'm telling you, it's an intrinsic motivation.  If you don't know what that means, read the link.

Comment: @Cawas: "driven by an interest or enjoyment in the task itself, and exists within the individual rather than relying on external pressures or a desire for reward."

Comment: @staticx thanks, that's a beautiful quote from Servy's link. I had read it. And it's exactly as I knew. But it would still let my question open... Because, unlike the accepted answer (by Robert), that doesn't tell me a reason, just an excuse. Subjective stuff.

Comment: @Cawas: In other words, people want to make the world a better place just because. That's the essence of Robert's answer.

Comment: I disagree there @staticx. There are many very good reasons to want to make the world a better place, even for selfish people.

Comment: @Cawas As per the link, it's an inherent part of human nature.  It's built into us biologically.  It is not a logical choice.  You don't *choose* what motivates you.  It's a chemical reaction in your brain.

Comment: @Cawas: Intrinsic motivation isn't necessarily selfish. It's the ideal type of motivation. Unlike a Drill Sergeant yelling you in the face and making you run 6 miles. Some people might be intrisically motivated by that, but most are externally motivated.

Comment: @Cawas Of course not everyone is intrinsically motivated to do everything.  I am asserting that most of the people that moderate on the site do so because of this intrinsic motivation.  Obviously that's not everybody.  People that require extrinsic motivation don't tend to moderate here all that much.

Comment: Servy, let's not get too [philosophical here... Talking about "choice"](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10957/1670). I now understand your point, but I choose it doesn't answer my question. I was first trying to understand it, then I was only trying to tell you why of my choice. @staticx I didn't say anything about "intrinsic motivation" being selfish, you just assumed that on your own. Now, what you mean by "ideal type"? If you mean it's "the better type" I rather stop talking here.

Comment: @Cawas: It's in the Wikipedia article. "Students who are intrinsically motivated are more likely to engage in the task willingly as well as work to improve their skills, which will increase their capabilities.". You did say selfish : ".. even for selfish people .."

Comment: @staticx I didn't mean that for the article at all. My point was simply what's written. (Not only altruistic people but) even selfish people can find good reasons to want to make the world a better place.

Comment: @Cawas Sure.  The point remains that they're doing it because the act itself makes them feel good.  That's exactly what being intrinsically motivated means.  They're doing it because they enjoy the act, not because there are advantageous consequences.

Comment: @Cawas: That's a non-sequitor. If you are selfish, you are selfish.

Comment: @staticx No, it isn't.  If you perform charitable acts because they make you feel good, then you're acting selfishly.  You're doing the act to make *you* feel good, not because you have a moral imperative to help someone else.  An altruist is someone who helps someone else because them *must*, not (necessarily) because they *want to*.  Obviously there is some overlap there.

Comment: @Servy: I don't think that fits the definition of intrinsic motivation

Comment: Servy, if you do it because you enjoy it, that is doing it for an advantageous selfish consequence. Again, too subjective dude. And thanks for "backing me up" on @staticx comment! :P

Comment: @Cawas: you just confirmed what I said

Comment: @staticx I never said that moderators aren't selfish.  I'm simply saying that the selfish consequence is intrinsic, not extrinsic.  The benefit is out of an internal biological consequence of the act itself, not because of some externally provided benefit.

Comment: @staticx you're mixing concepts and playing with words. Continue at your will, but I'll simply give up. Just let me ask you this, where did you learn the word "non-sequitor"? I'm guessing you might watch SGU (where I learned it). :P

Comment: I learned it in school. Does it matter?

Comment: @Servy: right, I agree. I am just debating philosophy at this point

Comment: @staticx nothing really matters... anyone can see... :D

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation @Cawas

Comment: @Shog9 not only related, it contained my answer there as well... Hidden somewhere. :P

Answer (score 4):

I fix grammar, which I suppose is a form of janitorial duty, because proofreading is a compulsion. I just can't help myself. I also cast the occasional close vote.

Comment: you fix titles and formatting too, right? If you focus only on grammar than you might sometimes be part of a problem rather than a solution

Comment: Grammar, spelling, titles, formatting, RFC 2606 domain names. And I try to have a look at tags while I'm at it.

Comment: *"RFC 2606 domain names"* - must admit, that's a new one for me.

Comment: One of only two RFCs where I know the number off by heart, because I've typed it often enough in edit comments. (The other is 2468.)

Answer (score 3):

My version of the truth: I hardly ever find questions that I can/want to answer given that I basically only have skill in high velocity tags with lots of off-topic/duplicate content (Java, JavaEE, Javascript, Node) and tags I simply don't feel comfortable contributing in for various reasons (javascript, C++); on top of that I simply have limited time available on the boss' clock so I often can't spend the time needed to properly answer something. Regrettable, but I'm not going to complain I have a day job that keeps me busy.

But I do search for those questions to answer with that hope of actually finding one that fits within my limitations. And while I'm searching, I see plenty of things that need work - that's the understatement of the century, I see truckloads of things that need work. So I edit and flag and comment all my time away - leaving no time at all to actually answer stuff in the end.

If you can't make the big contributions, then at least make the smaller ones I say. It all adds up to the same result: better content. Its not a process that racks up much reputation, I must admit :)