# Add CrossValidated to list of migration sites in the Close Dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, migration

As most are aware, we are limited to 5 standard migration paths. The current migration paths are:

- Meta Stack Overflow
- Super User
- Tex
- DBA
- Sharepoint

If users want to migrate to another site, they have to use a custom flag which can sit in the [review queue for extended periods of time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260118/custom-reason-flags-open-for-over-two-weeks) before being acted on.

Lately, I've noticed that we have been getting a significant number of custom flags requesting for items to be migrated to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  A [previous request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189174/suggestion-to-include-crossvalidated-se-in-sos-off-topic-list) to add CrossValidated was declined, but after looking at the migration stats for the past 90 days, I think we might need to reconsider.

Over the past 90 days, we have migrated a total of 11 questions to the Sharepoint site, which makes me wonder if it should still be included as standard migration path.  The [top sites with migrations for the past 90 days](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) are below:

> [image]

While not as many migrations as the other top sites, CrossValidated placed in the Top 5. By adding this site as a standard option it would send these to close vote queue for community review and it would remove the need for many of the custom flags that moderators to process.

Can we reevaluate the sites included in the standard migration path and possibly include CrossValidated?

Comment: 32% rejected. .. stop migrations to meta: )

Comment: I've sometimes wondered why that list isn't just dynamically set based on recent migrations so it can automatically adjust to changes like these.

Comment: @joran It would probably be confusing if if changed too often. We still occasionally get flags asking where the migration options for Programmers and Server Fault went.

Comment: I'd like to see a per-user dynamic list. I have multiple times flagged for a move to codereview, but never voted to migrate to any of those top-5 sites.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the list can't include every site on the stackexchange network.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Seems that could be addressed with some simple UI changes: "The following are the five most common migration destinations over the previous 90 days. If you do not see the site you believe this Q belongs on, indicate it using the Other option.", and add a custom close reason option at the bottom just like there is on the previous screen.

Comment: Code Review and Programmers are SE sites *about programming* and yet we want to add a *statistics* site to the list? Seems like we are missing some rather important ones as it stands...

Comment: Though they may have crept up the list there is no way the community is going to get this one right...

Comment: @Bradley The apparent similarity of Code Review and Programmers actually causes more problems. A while back, Programmers specifically asked to be removed from our list of unlocked migration destinations because many Stack Overflow users were using it as their garbage dump for bad questions. I'm not sure if Code Review ever did, but they probably would have eventually. There's less risk of that for a statistics site. It is more obvious which questions do and do not belong.

Comment: Automatic migration anyway is risky. What if the questioner doesn't agree and rather wants to delete its question of if he/she doesn't have an account on the target site? [What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) doesn't cover these points.

Comment: @joran: Indeed. Why not just a free-text search to search the site to migrate to?

Comment: [I asked for this previously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179672/why-flagging-a-post-as-off-topic-doesnt-include-crossvalidated), so I would love to see it. But the idea of dynamic migration based on tags was also debated on the old meta site quite a bit: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags

Comment: The 5 most common migration paths are the 5 most accessible options (i.e. no custom flag required). Call me crazy but this is a major confounder of your migration path metrics. The 5 most accessible options will *always* continue to be the most used.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon While I agree with your statement, however when we have Sharepoint as a standard migration and it's not being used, maybe it's time to reconsider that last standard option.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon [stats.se] *isn't* on the convenient-five list but it *is* in the top five for migrations in past 90 days. Conversely Sharepoint *is* on the convenient-five list but *not* in the top 5 sites of past 3 months. I agree with your general point of course, but it seems [stats.se] is bucking that, lending more support to the question at hand.

Comment: @CodyGray Code review, being a beta site (at this time), isn't eligible for being on the community close vote migration list. When they graduate, I suspect that they'd still ask not to be on the list with the likelihood of all the poor 'is this code right?' questions that they'd get bombarded with from SO (similar to what happened with P.SE).

Comment: I think instead of having this kind of question every now and then (there are other "reconsider migration path list" questions) we should settle on a metric to determine the list, and implement it. E.g. "top 5 migrated/request within last 100 days, recalculated every sunday"

Comment: @CodyGray "The apparent similarity of Code Review and Programmers actually causes more problems" <- what if the migration options to these sites was based on the user's participation on those sites?  I am fairly active on Code Review (css/html tags), so I am familiar with what makes a good question there... not so much on Programmers.  So in my case, CR would be in my migration list but not Programmers.

Answer (score 26):

I am a regular user/contributor to both [so] and [stats.se] and am probably responsible for  some of the migrations from [so] to [stats.se] for questions in the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag. (Likewise I've probably contributed to flow of questions coming the other way.) There has been a lot of discussion on [stats.se] about what is/is not on topic there as regards software-related questions that happen to be for statistical software, like R. I now think the regular [stats.se] users have a pretty good handle on this, although the reject rate of CV -> SO migrations could do with being reduced. Likewise, certainly as far as the [so] [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag goes, I think we have a good group of high-rep users that are familiar with both sites and know when a question is ripe for migration or not.

This is by way of introduction; tl;dr; I'm biased :-)

I support this suggested change. It would make my life easier, and the lives of other users in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) easier too if we had an easier way to move questions to the most appropriate related site. It seems clear that this would reduce some of the load from the Moderators here and at an approximate rate of 55 questions per 90 days isn't going to overly burden the Mods on [stats.se].

I don't think it is sensible to retain an option to migrate to Sharepoint if that option is very rarely used.

If this feature-request is implemented, it would make sense to review the list at some interval; annually, biennially? As the SE network changes and evolves, and as the popularity of particular software wax and wane it would make sense to review the top-five list *if changes are going to be made to the list in the first place*.

My one caveat is that it would be nice to have more detailed information on trajectories in these migration stats; migrations SO -> CV may be high in this quarter but on the decline (I don't know but could CV have been higher in the list previously) or this could just be a blip related to some high-profile MOOCs focussed on R and Statistics having taken place in the past 6 months. If this were the case we wouldn't want to update the list to include CV.

Answer (score 14):

I'm very active on Cross Validated and somewhat (but much less) active on Stack Overflow on the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag.  I have flagged questions to be migrated to CV from SO, and may well have been responsible for some of the flags you've gotten.

I generally support this proposed change and agree with the points made by @GavinSimpson (in fact, I asked on meta.SE for this change a year ago: [No option in 'flag -> close -> off-topic -> belongs elsewhere' for migrate to stats.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194002/no-option-in-flag-close-off-topic-belongs-elsewhere-for-migrate-to-st)).  He and the other high-rep SO:`r` users have exercised good judgment on this issue.  I would think adding the close option would make this task easier for them.

@CodyGray also raises good points about the knowledge / ability of regular SO users to determine the appropriateness of such migrations.  People can skip or filter out such cases, but I suppose the concern is that not all SO close queue reviewers are as self-aware and conscientious.  I can make two points here:

1. We have a very active group of reviewers on CV.  We would not be overly troubled by ~55 inappropriate migrations per 90 days, if we got some.  That is only about 1 every other day, and I suspect most of the migrations are appropriate anyway (as noted above).
2. I'm guessing the potential problem is more that people without the requisite knowledge would be inappropriately flagging in the first place if the option were provided and the floodgates were opened.  In light of that concern, I think @Bergi's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261072/add-crossvalidated-to-list-of-migration-sites-in-the-close-dialog#comment45433_261072) is excellent: If it is possible, it would be best to have the options list be dynamic so that the option to migrate to CV shows up for those who have successfully flagged a few times before.  On the other hand, I wonder how much trouble this would be for SE's developers, but I think we'd be OK even if this can't be done.

Comment: Why not give people with some amount of rep the option to migrate?

Answer (score 8):

I answer statistics-related questions on SO and often enough the questions are not about programming but rather more conceptual. It would make everybody happier to migrate those questions to CrossValidated, so I'm absolutely in support of this proposal.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not necessarily saying I disagree with this, just thinking out loud…

Right now, since the path isn't unlocked for normal users, all of those migrations to Cross Validated are triggered exclusively by moderators. I realize you guys can't and aren't expected to be experts on what is on topic for every other site in the Stack Exchange universe, and a 5% rejection index isn't half bad, but you're proposing opening this route up to the community at large… A community that has proven itself a *terrible* judge of which questions are worthy of migrating.

I'm concerned that may not be such a good idea. Since I can't see this data, I'll just have to ask: of the questions that you guys have had flagged to be migrated to Cross Validated, how many of those flags have you accepted and gone ahead with the migration? And how many were on questions that should have just been deleted?

And even those statistics will only tell us about the track record of users savvy enough to raise a custom flag requesting migration. What about the masses in the review queue—especially users who just earned the close vote privilege and are still learning the ropes?

I'm a prolific close voter, but I don't think I've ever been to Cross Validated. The only thing I know about it is that it's a site for statistics questions. That's nowhere near enough knowledge for me to be voting to migrate questions there. How many Stack Overflow users are also active on Cross Validated and/or likely to be familiar with their guidelines for what is on topic? If the barrier to migration remains high, people will be more likely to go and read their Help Center pages. If it's listed right there in the close dialog with a short, simple summary, and you see anything vaguely statistical—clicky clicky.

If we did do it, I think we definitely need to get concurrence from the Cross Validated moderators. Maybe one of you mods can ping them and ask them to check out this question (if you haven't already)?

Comment: Many of the migrations to CV probably occured in tags of languages mainly used by statisticians, in particular R. Would it be possible to have the migration paths depend on the tags? I know that the R community has asked to have CV included in this list before (and repeatedly?).

Comment: @Roland The migration is already dependent on tags in the sense that at least one tag must exist also in the target site. ([What is migration and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)] Is this enough or what should be done?

Comment: @Trilarion I don't think this is enough in this case, because there are, e.g., c++ and java tags on CV. And I don't trust the java community as much as the r community to get this right, i.e., to judge quality standards correctly.

Comment: @Roland But this rather means that tags are probably not so relevant for determining migration suitability when there are c++ and java tags on CV but they aren't used really for a lot of programming. Then I would rather not make migration paths dependent on tags? Or how should it look like?

Comment: I mean include CV in the list for some specialized SO tags (r, python, ..., look at the migration statistics), but not in general. Or even better, have custom made migration paths for the large SO tags (when they are the primary tag of a question) and a default for smaller tags.

Comment: I'm pretty selective when it comes to sending questions to CV, the first thing I always do before accepting a migration is check the rep of the user flagging on the target site.  More times than not, the flags I'm reviewing are from established users on CV who know the content and know these questions fit there.  My reason for starting this conversation was two-fold - CV seems to get a large number of flags and Sharepoint migrations aren't being used - maybe it's time to reconsider what we have in that last spot.

Answer (score 3):

I mostly agree with this, with one major reservation.

I don't know that I feel like there is still a really good understanding of when a question goes on CV and when it goes on SO for questions about "How do you use [statistical language] to do [x]".  My primary tag is [sas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sas), and I tend to disagree with about half of the migrations to SO from CV.  Not because they're not exactly programming questions, but they're questions that would require understanding some degree of statistics to answer.  I only have limited proficiency in R and thus don't read that tag as much (and that's certainly where the bulk of this would go), so perhaps in R it's more clear - or just the user community is so much larger that it's something that size takes care of - but I'd want to be totally sure we have a good understanding of what question goes where.

This is things like "How do I find the standard deviation of a number in SAS".  Yes, that's sort of a programming question, but it's also a statistics question, and often it requires some of both to answer.  While that particular one is fine in either site I imagine, more complex ones involving finding particular models and such seem more statistical in nature, but sometimes come over here for whatever reason just to be rejected back.  (I would give examples, but I don't think you can search for migrations from other sites.)  I would be concerned that we'd end up having too many bit-of-statistics-lot-of-programming questions possibly going over there if this were added.

Comment: This question is about migration from SO to CV. You mainly seem to discuss the other way around.