# Why were comments suggesting a move to Code Review removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, code-review-se

The question: [PHP: Optimize If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740109/php-optimize-if-statement)

To me this looks like a clear cut case for migration to Code Review. It's code that works, and the question is *"Is there a better way of writing the following block of code to easily be maintainable?"*

So I made a comment that it should be posted to CR instead. The OP replied with "thanks for the link". A diamond moderator then commented that "it needs a redesign rather than code review", to which I replied "...so?"

The comment thread's contents (not word for word because the comments are now removed, but the content is accurate):

> I think this belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead. - Juhana
>
> Thanks for the link. - OP
>
> @Juhana It needs a redesign more than a code review. - Moderator ♦
>
> @Moderator ...so? - Juhana

When I reloaded the page, the comments were gone.

Ok, if my last comment was too blunt, I apologize. I was merely trying to say that if code requires redesign (rather than cosmetic polish) it would *still* be on-topic at CR and the amount of required work was irrelevant. But why delete all comments instead of just that one?

Then I posted this comment:

> @Moderator Did you just wipe out the comments? Why? - Juhana

...and it was immediately deleted. I would have appreciated a brief explanation first.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: looks like a good post to migrate to CodeReview to me, I flagged it as such.

Comment: That question looks perfect for Code Review to me...

Comment: Yep, perfectly reasonable for Code Review. I don’t know why the comments would have been deleted.

Comment: @minitech, we don't want people cross posting and I assume the Mod who deleted them was thinking the same thing, less dups if the user waits for the migration.

Comment: @Malachi: Moderators can migrate posts, though.

Comment: @Malachi Yeeaah, but you can still read deleted comments in the notification inbox.  Especially a short one like that.

Comment: @minitech, sounds like the OP already had Cross posted.

Comment: If the reason was to prevent cross-posting, deleting would have been counterproductive since the OP had already seen the comment. Delete comments + an additional "don't cross-post" comment I would have understood.

Comment: @Malachi: <del>No, they don’t have any other accounts.</del> Apparently they used a different account. How fantastic.

Comment: @minitech: Yeah, I've noticed that.  I have no idea why that was done...

Comment: FYI: [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) (CR's main chatroom) has a feed for all [meta-tag:codereview-se] questions asked on MSO.

Comment: Given the direction this has gone, I'm putting this here so the question is "linked" rather than just "related": [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/500202)

Comment: Deletion of comments without explanation seems heavy-handed and won't help the poster of the comment learn to do better.

Answer (score 18):

As a quite active user on CR I will tell you what I think:

Comments like yours induce cross-posting. That is an issue discussed [on CR Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2052/is-cross-posting-soxcr-getting-popular-if-yes-what-can-we-do-about-it), as well as [here on SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261072/add-crossvalidated-to-list-of-migration-sites-in-the-close-dialog). These comments are generally disliked by moderators (from what I hear in CR chat) as they increase adminstrative cost.

Additionally to the already highlighted problems with cross-posting your first comment became obsolete the moment OP acknowledged it by commenting back "thanks for the link".

Obsolete comments are subject to deletion. This has always been that way and is SE-Wide policy.

**On the "why the removal"-comment:**

It is not constructive to the post at hand. Inquiries concerning moderator decisions should be taken to [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) or Meta. I assume it got deleted for that exact reason.

Comment: I've never heard or read that obsolete comments can be deleted. Can you please show me some posts showing why that's the policy? (I don't doubt you're right; I'd just like to learn more.)

Comment: @Kevin chech out the [comment privilege help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). "Comments are **temporary** post-it notes". You might also check the flag dialogue of a comment. Among too-chatty and off-topic there's also obsolete.

Comment: I think the goal was migration, not crossposting. Also if we would have to delete obsolete comments we could delete a lot (say at least 50%) of the comments. I guess that nobody wants to do that really.

Comment: @Trilarion we don't **have to** delete obsolete comments. They just **may** be deleted any time. Also, even if the goal was migration, this comment still warrants cross-posting by OP, and **has** in fact done that (see below answer)

Answer (score 11):

The question has already been cross-posted, [but with a title change (by me)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57011/displaying-content-based-on-the-current-time).  Although the OP indeed didn't ask for a design review (which *are* off-topic), it doesn't belong on SO.  The code itself does look okay to me, but that's probably not saying much since PHP isn't my area of expertise.  That said, I'll let the community decide if the question should stay open, as this one doesn't need my mod hammer.

As for the comment-wiping, that may have been done because they're either no longer needed, or because the moderator disagrees.  They're only comments anyway, so it doesn't matter if they get removed.  You could still request an explanation behind the removal on Meta, though.

Comment: Migration was not possible? And I wonder why you asked the question on CR? Do you want to have it answered for yourself or to you want to have it answered for the original poster?

Comment: Ah I just saw that you didn't ask the question on CR, just edited it. Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 8):

The entire post, question and answers, seem to match *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

I have flagged the post, and I don't know if it would help to have others flag the question.

The reason for not wanting the comments is because of cross posting and duplicates from this. The user is new to the Stack Exchange system and will very likely cross post when given the suggestion that this post would be a better fit for Code Review. And then there would be a duplicate that would be closed on Code Review when this original is migrated.

So that is probably why they deleted the comments.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this question is actually offtopic on SO in the first place, which is a prerequisite of any migration.

The question seems to essentially be: "is there a conscice language construct for representing this structure?"

It's slightly clumsily asked but I don't see that as making it OT here.

Comment: I'd disagree that being off topic is a prerequisite. If something is on topic on site A, but will get significantly higher quality answers on site B, there's nothing wrong with a migration, despite it being under the 'off-topic' reasons. I wouldn't say the population of such questions is very large, but it does exist.