# Are code review questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, help-center, code-review-se

According to [The help Section page *What topics can I ask about here?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) these subjects are on-topic:

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Similarly, there are various things on that site that are stated as off-topic, but questions asking for code improvements/reviews is not listed as off-topic anywhere.

Yet people often close-vote such questions as off-topic since there is now a separate [Code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I always found it strange that individual users are allowed to dictate what's off-topic even though there's no community consensus.

Anyway, I think the root of the problem is the on-topic page, it has not been updated to be aware of the Code review site.

I therefore propose that code review questions are formally made off-topic with an edit to the on-topic page, as this already seems to be some silent policy among close-voters.

Ideally, it should also be added to Close vote -> off topic -> Belongs on another site -> Code review.

**EDIT :**

Please note that my main concern here is whether or not questions asking for improvements/reviews/how to improve performance should be considered on-topic on Stack Overflow. The whole "how to export stuff to the Code review site" debate is secondary.

Comment: (And please add http://electronics.stackexchange.com and http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to "Belongs on another site" too!)

Comment: for reference: "belongs on another site" was [formally rejected by the codereview community](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311348/1803692)

Comment: I usually leave a custom reason suggesting CR *but* also recommending that the OP check their guidelines **first**.

Comment: additionally relevant discussion on codereview meta: ["If SO had a close-reason for Code Review, how should it be worded?"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6243/37660)

Comment: In addition: the "belongs on another site" list is populated by successful migrations to target site. You can see the stats in the [10k tools](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/). Be aware that changing the list has been discussed multiple times, and also rejected multiple times.

Comment: the presence of more focused site does not automatically make it off topic for Stack Overflow.  To my knowledge, code review questions, if reasonably scoped and well written, have always been acceptable on SO.  So closing just because CR.SE exists is not appropriate.

Comment: That. Exactly that ^^

Answer (score 8):

This is the current migration statistics on Code Review:

[image: migration stats]

As you can see of the ~60 questions migrated from SO in the **last 90 days**, 12% were closed as off-topic. Now let's put this into a little context:

- There's quite some sites with a higher migration volume. I don't have the current stats, but [almost a year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261072/1803692) there were 200 migrations to DBA over the span of 90 days. I suspect that this hasn't gone down, but rather increased.
- Migrations to Code Review are **all** performed by moderators, since Stack Overflow currently does not have a migration path to Code Review. **Still** 10% get rejected.
- There's a significant number of questions that have been [considered for migration](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Code%20Review&user=125580&room=8595), of which a significant number have been checked by Code Review regulars, resulting in comments that regularly have to state that the question is **not a good fit** for Code Review.
- Sometimes this leads to heated discussion <sub>([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268722/1803692))</sub>. Then a number of questions is cross-posted to code review *anyways*. This contributes to the fact that one of Code Review's close-reasons is applicable to **50%** of the closed questions which translates to **20% of questions asked**.

Overall users on Stack Overflow don't really benefit from a migration path, because the migration volume is so low, and other more viable options would have to be kicked out. In addition to that Code Review would have a significantly increased administrative load with user-based migrations.

I'd assume similar concerns apply for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) and [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Seems like the key here is to educate the diamond mods then :) But seriously, 12% of 60 = only 7.2 questions that caused trouble in 90 days. That is not much at all! It means Code review would get 0,08 problematic questions per day from SO, or if you will, one problematic question per 12.5 days. How is that even a problem? On the other hand, Code review got 90% of questions that weren't off topic. I would guess this is where most of the new Code review users are coming from too.

Comment: this is the questions that actually really are migrated. I have not the slightest idea how many, but there's a significant dark figure in play here, piling up in declined moderator flags for migration, misled comments corrected by regulars and additionally closed questions that were "migrated by hand" (aka. cross-posted)

Comment: @Lundin There have been 5,000 comments in the past year on SO questions that mention or link to CR. Maybe 20% are unrelated to migration suggestions, so 4,000 comments about moving to CR. There's generally 1-3 per question, so let's say 2. That's 6 questions per day. That's **20%** of  CR's current question load, **without** widespread exposure on SO.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets **200x** as many questions per day as CR. If even 1% are inappropriately migrated, our site becomes 2/3 crap overnight.

Comment: @Zak It is not relevant what the average SO user thinks, or rambles about in comments. But rather what those with 3000 rep and close vote privileges think. Anyway, the main concern here is if these questions are on-topic on SO or not.

Comment: @Lundin The **vast** majority of those comments **Are** from 3k users. Usually of the form "**I am voting to close this as Off-Topic** because it belongs on Code Review"

Comment: As to your clarified question. It's a duplicate that's been asked on Meta many times.

Comment: tl;dr if somebody wants a review of **a specific programming problem**, and the question meets all the usual SO requirements, then it's an On-Topic SO question (it would \*also\* be an on-topic CR question)

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, it depends. See: [A Guide to code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for a comprehensive run-down of which kinds of questions are appropriate for each site. (tl;dr it usually comes down to how specific the question is).

IMO, the problem is not the rules. It is people who do not understand the rules. Code Review has waged a Stack Overflow re-education campaign for *years* now. Mainly in response to the (for us) large volume of people recommending SO posts to Code Review that would be immediately closed as Off-Topic.

Even after all this time, the majority of people on SO who write a comment saying "Voting to close as belongs on Code Review" do so on questions that are, either, On-Topic SO questions, or completely Off-Topic for Code Review.

This is one of the main reasons why [Code Review voted to reject a SO --> Code Review migration path](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311348/what-is-the-latest-on-adding-code-review-to-off-topic-migration-options).

In short, for your proposal to be feasible, people on SO would have to actually understand what makes an Off-Topic SO quesiton, and what makes an On-Topic CR question, with far greater frequency than at present.

Comment: Code review has some of the clearest scope of all Stack Exchange sites. I really don't see how could people with a minimum of intelligence could misinterpret them. We aren't talking about the average user here, but trusted users with 3000 rep who have close vote rights. So it seems quite a bit exaggerated that this would be such a big problem for Code Review. Where are all those posts that were closed because people were told to post on Code Review instead of SO? Any statistics for how common they are?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your understanding of the scope of Code Review?

Comment: For examples: Just review this list for every occurence of CR users telling other people that they're recommending inappropriate questions to CR. http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Code+Review&user=125580&room=8595

Comment: @Lundin while we at Code Review appreciate that you think the guidelines are clear (and we do, trust us), the reality of things is that we actively monitor each CR mention in SO comments in an attempt to mitigate off-topic questions being cross-posted. Maybe you should come and hang out in our main [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) for a while some time if you are curious about how we manage things from Code Review's end.

Comment: Just speaking from personal obsevations: Of all the comments on questions which suggest Code Review, at least half are inappropriate in one way or another. Anecdote: It happened a long time ago now so I don't think I can find the link, but I once got into an argument with a **100k+** user who didn't understand CR's scope **at all**