# Question was put on-hold and now I have the answer code to post

Tags: support, review-queues, on-hold

I had a tough question that was put on hold, but I added clarifications and sample code to improve.

I have sinced worked out a complete solution and would like to post the answering code since other commenters are interested as well. 
It's in worse shape now because I had to post the answer in the question.
Can one manually submit for review?

topic here: [Script to transpose chords in a song sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549924/script-to-transpose-chords-in-a-song-sheet)

Comment: It was closed for being too broad, and with good reason. You complained about the comment, but with 3000 reputation, you should know by now that post looked like a question asking "gimme the code". It might be fine after revision 3, but it was closed with a good reason

Comment: After the last revision (#4) I would probably vote to leave closed if I came across it in a review as it now reads a bit like *"I solved a problem but is there a better way to solve it"*.

Comment: Re: original revision, I have to agree with the close reason: too broad. The question can be splitted into many specific subtasks (with bottom-up approach): 1) transposing a single chord, 2) transposing multiple chords, 3) detecting which is the chord line, 4) align the transposed chords correctly [the bonus question]. Re: current revision, maybe you're looking for [codereview.se]?

Comment: [Just because a question does or can have an "answer" does not make it an acceptable question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258432/can-a-question-with-an-accepted-answer-be-closed-as-unanswerable)

Comment: It wasn't opened when I last commented. But yes, it's clear the downvotes came from the meta post here teaching me a lesson. Peruse the Applescript tag, which is what I look at daily. A post with more than 6 votes up or down is VERY rare these days. lol. Without the history, the few applescripters on here will now see that question and all the down votes and be like "what on earth?"  *shrug*  I don't care. All I cared about was getting the thing formatted with an answer.

Comment: That's [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) for you... I'd suggest a little more patience, if you want a question re-opened. When you edit a closed question, it automatically gets pushed into a review queue that can end up re-opening your question in the first place. That said, as it is right now, your question is a request for a code review. You have working code that you want to make more efficient. That's off-topic for SO, and is quite possibly the reason the question got downvoted.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: It’s not valid to close this as “does not seek input from the community” as the user is seeking our input and support. This is the support site for stack overflow; please don’t turn away people asking for our support; especially when we tell them to bring up question specific issues on meta.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I'm not having _"issues comprehending what they were asking"_, but thanks for the passive aggressive language. I'm just saying this question can do with some editing, preferably by the OP.

Answer (score -6):

> I had a tough question that was put on hold, but I added clarifications and sample code to improve.
>
> I have since worked out a complete solution and would like to post the answering code since other commenters are interested as well. It's in worse shape now because I had to post the answer in the question.

You're right, putting the answer in the question is frowned upon and will be edited out.

The question itself could use a little editing to be on-topic; but once it's edited it is an on-topic question (that is, none of our close reasons fit, which I suppose is a rather utilitarian way of looking at it, but nonetheless).

> Can one manually submit for review?

The typical way this should be handled is to edit the question according to the close reason's issues; and then you can flag your own question for a moderator to review.

Editing your question will also 'bump' it into the review queue, allowing members of the community to determine if it should be re-opened.

As a general piece of advice, you want your question to seem broadly applicable to others; so while you may be focused on your particular problem, you want to use words that others may use.

The problem you pose in your question is about algorithm to use for a modulating pattern that is more concise than the one you're using.  [It's probably squarely on topic for codereview.stackexchange.com; but no less on topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312863/are-code-review-questions-off-topic) (though hopefully you'll get a more targeted reception on codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for this. There was some unfortunate and/or hasty meta things that happened to my question, however, I made it worse by being hasty (and a little whiney). If I had just made the edits and waited 3 days, the hold probably would've lifted on its own. Instead, I brought the wrath of the meta-effect by my hastiness (and ignorance. I've never posted in meta before, and RARELY post a question of my own, I only check SO daily to help folks with Applescript questions).