# Add Cross Validated to the list of alternative Stack Exchange sites on the on-topic help page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope, close-reasons, migration

Just made a close vote for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62336712/6574038) that IMO could have been perfectly migrated to *Cross Validated* (CV), because it was of purely statistical content. (Even if the question already has an answer, it would still fit better into the CV collection.) The three votes were not unanimously, namely two for migration to CV, one to adding focus/details, therefore the question was closed as ["This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

When the user clicks on that link, the help page suggests nothing at all where they may ask their statistical question. If the user is (still) curious about the close reason and reads the relevant section **off-topic because...**, they may click on ["viewing [on-topic] help center article"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the hope that this will shed some light on the matter. However, even on the second page there is no hint that statistical questions are off-topic and should be asked on ***Cross Validated.***

Moreover, I and another user vote for migrating to CV, and OP does not get any hint that one of the reasons might be that it belongs there. If anything, they conclude that the question **probably** was not on-topic because it was rather statistical. I now have somewhat a bad conscience about that, partly because it was also a **new user**.

That CV is missing on the list is also somewhat inconsistent, since CV appears on the close-reason list for voters. Furthermore, the fact that CV is among the [top five percent of migrations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261072/add-crossvalidated-to-list-of-migration-sites-in-the-close-dialog?rq=1#comment45786_261072) should still apply and CV should therefore appear on the list.

**Most importantly**, new users seeking help might think that statistical questions on Stack Overflow are not so badly off-topic because they are not explicitly listed on the "still not on topic" list. I read tons of purely statistical questions of new users in the [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) tag every week.

So please add [***Cross Validated***](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) to the "another Stack Exchange site" list at the bottom of the [on-topic help site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)!

#### Example:

- People interested in statistics ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Please include/suggest an example of the text that needs added.

Comment: Also I think the part about "*Moreover, I and another user...*" onwards should be discussed separately in another question.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Done so! Taken from the CV [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) page.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Separate question? I thought I had elaborated on all the good reasons why to add CV to the on-topic help site.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Removed "side question" since it may be confusing and I believe it's already being discussed somewhere else on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now done. I updated the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page in the Help Center to add Cross Validated and a couple of other sites that I find to be highly relevant. I also added icons, which tends to help in recognition and association.

The list there is manually maintained, and it obviously didn't get updated after the unlocked migration targets changed the last time.