# Unable to flag answer with upvotes

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710674/html5-localstorage-remove-all-data/12928790#12928790), for example, should **never** have been upvoted, but because it was, I am unable to flag it as "very low quality." (Note it is not the accepted answer, either)

Why remove the "very low quality" option at all?

---

**EDIT:** The linked answer was removed. Here's a screenshot: [image: Screenshot of answer]

Comment: Well, the theory is that posts that really are very low quality wouldn't ever get upvotes.  Of course, this assumption is invalid, even if it makes sense at first.

Comment: Maybe its because I don't have enough rep, but the URL doesn't link to a specific answer for me.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The answer has been removed, and my "not an answer" flag is now labeled "helpful."

Comment: I just flag link-only answers as custom flag, "this is a link-only answer".

Comment: @neminem That increases the diamond mods' queue, [which is already very, very long](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260118/custom-reason-flags-open-for-over-two-weeks). It's better for everybody to use other flag reasons.

Comment: Then perhaps we should get a proper link-only answer flag? It doesn't really fit "very low quality", and it is an answer.

Comment: @neminem [According to Shog9 they're actually not answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/186381).