# Can we have some moderator queue stats?

Tags: discussion, flags, statistics

Would it be possible to get some stats on the moderator queue *(I think that's what it's called - the place where our flags can go)*.

The timeframe doesn't matter much, whether the stats are *from like July 2014 or even Jan 1st 2014 to present*

Can we get the following stats:

- total number of flags that went to the mod queue
- total number of flags handled by mods (*and not the community like the LQRQ/close queue*)
- the number of those that are comment flags
- the number of those that are *other* flags on posts
- the number of those that are *other* flags on comment
- the number of those that are *not an answer* flags
- the number of those that are spam flags

I'm not sure how it all works, so I don't know if like a duplicate flag would show up in that data at all or not. But I hope you get the idea of what data would be nice to see. I'd like to see this data out of curiosity and to be better informed on feature requests that I have.

Comment: @rene It will be helpful. For example, if I have a feature request on better handling comment flags, it'd be nice to see if they get a lot of comment flags as it is or not. It will be helpful for me, that is for sure. It will likely also be helpful for others that don't know it will help them yet, since we don't know what the data holds and what improvements the community may be able to come up with out of it.

Comment: Shouldn't your question be: If I want to propose feature request that help improve the quality of the site without increasing the workload on the mod-team, which parts should I focus on?

Comment: @rene not at all

Comment: I think this data will help us understand the current situation and propose better ideas/feature requests to help the site. It's hard to propose a good feature request without understanding the actual system and seeing the data/volume of flags. I support this, +1.

Comment: Shog9 has been tracking these stats, and I checked with him to see what we're allowed to share, or if he'd want to tabulate this himself. In the meantime, here's a graph of total / other / comment flags as of June: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260118/custom-reason-flags-open-for-over-two-weeks/260127#260127

Comment: Just remembered, there's also this question by Shog which has some stats: [Stack Overflow is not yet a vast wasteland: a history of moderator tooling](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling)

Comment: @hichris123 be careful, [that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251175/2140173) was posted on the 1st of April ;P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is about 6-8ish months in the making but I've thrown together a few stats on flags in the SO moderator queue.  SO gets a lot of flags, many of these are handled by the review queues but the mods still process a ton of flags on a monthly basis.

I excluded close flags from these stats because those go directly into the Close Review Queue.  The data covers flags from **2015-01-01 to present**.  Since the start of 2015, there have been <strike>**445,665**</strike> **979,050** flags raised.

### Total Flags By Type

Of the total flags raised, here’s a breakdown by type of flag; this includes auto-generated system flags that the mods have to review (they don't hit a queue):

```
+----------------------------------------------+----------------+
|                  Flag Name                   |  Total Flags   |
+----------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Answer Not An Answer                         | 359,759        |
| Post Low Quality                             | 141,536        |
| Comment Obsolete                             | 105,485        |
| Comment Not Constructive Or Off Topic        | 86,079         |
| Comment Too Chatty                           | 64,579         |
| Post Spam                                    | 63,524         |
| Post Other                                   | 58,074         |
| Comment Rude Or Offensive                    | 21,246         |
| Answer Duplicate Answer (Auto)               | 19,389         |
| ReviewLowQualityDisputedAuto                 | 18,078         |
| Comment Other                                | 12,230         |
| Post Offensive                               | 12,095         |
| Post Too Many Comments (Auto)                | 6,452          |
| Post Excessively Long (Auto)                 | 3,021          |
| Question Consecutive Closures (Auto)         | 2,416          |
| PostExcessiveEditsByOwnerAuto                | 2,209          |
| Post Vandalism Deletions (Auto)              | 1,009          |
| Post Rollback War (Auto)                     | 811            |
| Post Vandalism Edits (Auto)                  | 464            |
| QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedForAllTimeAuto | 227            |
| Mod Revision Redaction Approval              | 144            |
| QuestionExcessiveAnswersPostedRecentlyAuto   | 141            |
| QuestionContestedDuplicateAuto               | 75             |
| PostExcessiveEditsByOthersAuto               | 7              |
+----------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

It's important to note that while many of these flags go into a review queue they also appear in the moderator queue.  There is a [delay before some of them appear for the mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243145/hide-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-in-the-moderator-flag-queue/247658#247658) but if a moderator [comes across the flag they most likely will process it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288450/426671) instead of letting it linger.

### Flags Processed by Mods By Month

Over the same timeframe, here are the totals by month so you can see a few more details; including Total Flags, the Total number of flags processed by the moderators, and the total processed by mods for each of the flag types that were requested in the question.

```
+------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
|   Month    | Total Flags | TotalHandled By Mods | Comment Flags Except Other | Comment Flags Other | Other/Custom Flags | NAA Flags Handled By Mods | VLQ Flags Handled By Mods | Spam/Offensive Flags   |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
| 2016-05-01 | 12,017      | 7,292                | 2,958                      |                 106 | 638                | 2,505                     | 467                       | 486                    |
| 2016-04-01 | 59,123      | 39,559               | 14,754                     |                 706 | 3,303              | 14,294                    | 2,463                     | 2,415                  |
| 2016-03-01 | 66,093      | 45,499               | 16,344                     |                 749 | 3,401              | 17,329                    | 3,210                     | 2,434                  |
| 2016-02-01 | 61,241      | 43,249               | 16,564                     |                 665 | 3,263              | 15,575                    | 2,961                     | 2,284                  |
| 2016-01-01 | 65,260      | 43,942               | 16,741                     |                 959 | 3,579              | 14,860                    | 2,851                     | 2,658                  |
| 2015-12-01 | 63,981      | 38,267               | 17,213                     |                 675 | 3,501              | 10,303                    | 1,550                     | 2,829                  |
| 2015-11-01 | 57,047      | 36,010               | 14,980                     |                 643 | 3,319              | 10,297                    | 1,834                     | 2,383                  |
| 2015-10-01 | 63,171      | 41,153               | 14,975                     |                 664 | 3,775              | 13,645                    | 2,450                     | 2,578                  |
| 2015-09-01 | 62,032      | 41,465               | 17,433                     |                 736 | 3,775              | 11,706                    | 2,320                     | 2,506                  |
| 2015-08-01 | 56,583      | 38,697               | 17,240                     |                 592 | 3,386              | 10,388                    | 2,063                     | 2,154                  |
| 2015-07-01 | 56,789      | 40,188               | 15,547                     |                 706 | 3,376              | 12,313                    | 2,476                     | 2,796                  |
| 2015-06-01 | 64,433      | 43,188               | 15,519                     |                 816 | 3,546              | 13,789                    | 2,420                     | 3,320                  |
| 2015-05-01 | 62,668      | 37,651               | 14,626                     |                 729 | 3,880              | 9,773                     | 1,657                     | 3,017                  |
| 2015-04-01 | 60,921      | 33,732               | 12,597                     |                 824 | 4,241              | 7,700                     | 1,620                     | 2,531                  |
| 2015-03-01 | 55,914      | 34,068               | 11,794                     |                 669 | 3,794              | 9,505                     | 1,698                     | 2,529                  |
| 2015-02-01 | 54,532      | 32,165               | 11,339                     |                 516 | 3,604              | 9,066                     | 1,423                     | 2,598                  |
| 2015-01-01 | 57,261      | 31,783               | 12,297                     |                 557 | 3,693              | 8,068                     | 1,216                     | 1,885                  |
+------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+--------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+------------------------+
```

You can see that the moderators are really busy...all the time.  I've done some analysis on some of the low-hanging fruit to help alleviate some of the flags that the moderators have to handle, and we've made some minor tweaks to some of the auto-flags they get, but there is still a whole lot flags.

### Flag Result by Mods By Month

Update: May 2016 as requested here is a breakdown of the result of the flags handled by the mods.

```
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|   Month    | Total Flags | Total Helpful By Mods | Total Declined By Mods | Total Comment Flags Helpful By Mods | Total Comment Flags Declined By Mods | Total Other Flags Helpful By Mods | Total Other Flags Declined By Mods | Total NAA Flags Helpful By Mods | Total NAA Flags Declined By Mods | Total VLQ Flags Helpful By Mods | Total VLQ Flags Declined By Mods | Total Spam/Offensive Flags Helpful By Mods | Total Spam/Offensive Flags Declined By Mods  |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 2016-05-01 | 12,017      | 6,743                 | 513                    | 2,948                               |                                  116 | 312                               | 245                                | 2,439                           |                               66 | 457                             |                               10 | 377                                        |                                     73       |
| 2016-04-01 | 59,123      | 35,914                | 3,502                  | 14,563                              |                                  897 | 1,856                             | 1,306                              | 13,727                          |                              564 | 2,265                           |                              197 | 1,761                                      |                                    515       |
| 2016-03-01 | 66,093      | 40,908                | 4,373                  | 16,123                              |                                  970 | 1,836                             | 1,561                              | 16,550                          |                              748 | 2,697                           |                              501 | 1,709                                      |                                    550       |
| 2016-02-01 | 61,241      | 39,154                | 3,898                  | 16,336                              |                                  893 | 1,882                             | 1,381                              | 14,906                          |                              624 | 2,548                           |                              394 | 1,589                                      |                                    562       |
| 2016-01-01 | 65,260      | 40,144                | 3,657                  | 17,053                              |                                  647 | 2,069                             | 1,510                              | 14,277                          |                              573 | 2,558                           |                              291 | 1,913                                      |                                    616       |
| 2015-12-01 | 63,981      | 34,288                | 3,830                  | 16,991                              |                                  897 | 1,956                             | 1,545                              | 9,803                           |                              499 | 1,278                           |                              272 | 2,152                                      |                                    529       |
| 2015-11-01 | 57,047      | 32,059                | 3,779                  | 14,867                              |                                  756 | 2,010                             | 1,309                              | 9,631                           |                              646 | 1,326                           |                              492 | 1,780                                      |                                    467       |
| 2015-10-01 | 63,171      | 37,375                | 3,584                  | 14,938                              |                                  701 | 2,423                             | 1,350                              | 12,995                          |                              592 | 2,036                           |                              402 | 1,923                                      |                                    531       |
| 2015-09-01 | 62,032      | 37,702                | 3,637                  | 17,322                              |                                  847 | 2,325                             | 1,450                              | 11,272                          |                              434 | 1,945                           |                              375 | 1,863                                      |                                    517       |
| 2015-08-01 | 56,583      | 34,575                | 4,000                  | 16,952                              |                                  880 | 1,965                             | 1,421                              | 9,824                           |                              561 | 1,471                           |                              591 | 1,520                                      |                                    516       |
| 2015-07-01 | 56,789      | 35,495                | 4,433                  | 15,316                              |                                  937 | 1,747                             | 1,629                              | 11,575                          |                              644 | 1,885                           |                              555 | 2,008                                      |                                    658       |
| 2015-06-01 | 64,433      | 39,265                | 3,772                  | 15,544                              |                                  791 | 1,924                             | 1,622                              | 13,268                          |                              479 | 2,093                           |                              318 | 2,695                                      |                                    525       |
| 2015-05-01 | 62,668      | 33,688                | 3,818                  | 14,508                              |                                  847 | 2,163                             | 1,717                              | 9,382                           |                              385 | 1,351                           |                              306 | 2,320                                      |                                    558       |
| 2015-04-01 | 60,921      | 29,703                | 3,883                  | 12,645                              |                                  776 | 2,373                             | 1,868                              | 7,399                           |                              284 | 1,236                           |                              381 | 1,856                                      |                                    549       |
| 2015-03-01 | 55,914      | 30,322                | 3,567                  | 12,007                              |                                  456 | 2,030                             | 1,764                              | 9,109                           |                              362 | 1,046                           |                              626 | 2,061                                      |                                    349       |
| 2015-02-01 | 54,532      | 28,857                | 3,045                  | 11,372                              |                                  483 | 1,933                             | 1,671                              | 8,567                           |                              408 | 1,169                           |                              203 | 2,202                                      |                                    275       |
| 2015-01-01 | 57,261      | 28,126                | 3,452                  | 11,907                              |                                  947 | 1,988                             | 1,704                              | 7,648                           |                              348 | 1,005                           |                              175 | 1,540                                      |                                    248       |
+------------+-------------+-----------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you know why the NAAs handled by mods jumped in June? Thanks for the information bluefeet.

Comment: @Andy Probably because there were more of those flags in June.

Comment: @Andy Lots of flags, Martijn is a machine who can do everything...but seriously nothing really stands out as to why except we have more flags in June than in other months.

Comment: June... Ah, June. Spring is in the air and a young Stack Overflow user's thoughts turn to flags.

Comment: I'm curious how many of these were validated vs rejected... it would be interesting to see how accurate the site as whole is at flagging properly.

Comment: @TylerH What do you mean validated vs rejected?

Comment: I mean how many of all those flags were marked helpful? And how many were marked declined. Sorry, I used the wrong terminology in my last comment.

Comment: @TylerH I finally added a breakdown of helpful/declined.