# Is an unsalvageable question a very low quality question?

Tags: support, flags, triage

Recently I flagged a question with the very low quality flag with the idea that it had two options. It would perhaps gain some sort of redemption in the Triage queue, or perhaps could be improved in the Help & Improvement (hugs for questions) queue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219141/how-to-create-a-calculator-for-gamehostingjs

My flag was declined, presumably because this post was deemed unsalvageable, but a moderator thought that deleting it was heavy handed and the community should handle it.

But didn't the community just handle it by calling it unsalvageable? I am a little confused as to how I should handle these in the future, because I was under the (false?) impression that questions which could possibly be redeemed should enter Triage / potentially Help & Improvement.

Am I misunderstanding the use of the very low quality flag? And if so, will these questions ever naturally enter the Triage queue?

Comment: All I know is that for now I act on these flags based on these guidelines: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288450/19679 . If the post requires immediate deletion, delete. Otherwise, if the review queues have had an hour to act on it and this doesn't require special intervention by a moderator, decline.

Comment: @BradLarson - I am fine with the flag being declined. But since it was declined I figured I must have been doing it wrong and as a result posted this question. Should I not be placing VLQ flags with the intent of them hitting these new queues?

Comment: Just vote to close with the relevant close reason.  Flagging it so that someone else can vote to close it is just adding more work.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now but VLQ means it needs to be deleted immediately. This didn't and doesn't fit that definition. Vote to close the question instead.

Comment: @bluefeet From what I understand, it's good behavior to flag as Very Low Quality **if** you are in the HIQ queue, and come across an **unsalvageable question** (not necessarily delete worthy, but should be closed) as [stated on this chart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288387/3041194). The very low quality flag isn't even an option most the time when viewing questions outside the HIQ, but if you do see it outside, I'd definitely not flag as VLQ unless it needs to be deleted immediately.

Comment: So to answer this question's title. I think yes, an unsalvageable question is a very low quality question **ONLY** when you are inside the Help and Improvement Queue (HIQ).