# Standards for Low Quality Flag

Tags: discussion

I flagged the following two questions as low-quality after coming across them in the Help and Improvement review queue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31767146/multiple-currencies-one-base-currency-possible

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798614/how-would-you-make-a-number-o-views-vs-time-graphic

Both flags were declined, and then subsequently closed by moderators. Apparently 'VLQ' flags are for only questions that are complete garbage (according to numerous other meta questions)... but the 'Help and Improvement' queue does not offer 'close' options. Using 'Edit' is invalid because as an editor I cannot simply add information that is missing.

Is the proper action really to simply skip these questions? (That seems like a waste of everyone's time.) It seems like either a close option needs to be offered, or the 'VLQ' flags need to not be declined on such a strict basis. Or, if there is another pathway the reviewer is supposed to take it needs to be made *much* more obvious.

Per a question in comments, these were definitely declined:

> very low quality – Nathaniel Ford 20 hours ago   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Comment: Users in triage like marking posts that should be closed as "should be improved" even though they can't be improved.  This is just a by-product of that.

Comment: Were the flags actually declined, or were they disputed? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288440/under-the-new-triage-system-when-and-how-should-moderators-act-on-very-low-qua

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When it comes to moderators acting on "very low quality" flags on questions, we [have been instructed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288440/under-the-new-triage-system-when-and-how-should-moderators-act-on-very-low-qua/288450#288450) to treat those flags as requests for immediate deletion. If we feel the posts are irredeemable and should be immediately deleted, we do so. Otherwise, we're to decline the flags.

This may mean that we decline some of these flags, yet still close a question. If we think there's any chance of it somehow being improved, we tend to close and let the Roomba deal with it if no improvements are made. For new questions, I tend to only delete when they are way off topic, spam, or I'm otherwise certain there's no hope they'll be improved.

The workflow around flags in triage [has just changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289658/lots-of-disputed-flags-since-yesterday/300787#300787), though, and this may impact how these are handled going forward.

Comment: I would note that due to this, I am now completely unable to flag questions because 'too many recent ones have been declined', despite the fact that all the declined ones had moderator action taken on them.