# Is there a way to ask moderators to look closely for a particular tag?

Tags: discussion, support

Google opensourced its neural network library tensor flow and this immediately gave rise to garbage-like questions. Out of **13** questions that popped up this day, in my opinion only like **3** are normal. Other in my opinion fall in the category:

- no idea what happens ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33622019/pip-install-tensorflow-successfully-on-mac-but-when-use-it-encounter-an-errorim), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621547/docker-tensorflow-returning-error), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619190/trying-to-install-tensorflow-errors-while-uninstalling-with-pip))
- give me some code, I do not care checking tutorials/documentation ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621643/how-would-i-implement-k-means-with-tensorflow), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620794/how-to-build-and-use-google-tensorflow-c-api), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620285/object-detection-using-tensorflow), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33616593/1090562))
- opinions or guesses ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621602/tensorflow-strengths-over-other-open-source-deep-learning-toolkits))
- let me write answer for obvious steps to get some points ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33616732/1090562))

My attempts to close/flag end up with pending flags mostly because this is a new library and I believe not a lot of people want to resolve flags for something they do not really know.

I am afraid that due to the hype more are more 'how to do something with this cool tool' will appear which will encourage answers like 'I am not sure, but I believe ...'. My question is: is there a way to ask moderators to take a look at this new shiny tag for a couple of days, till the hype will disappear?

Comment: I guess you can use the "other" flag on one of the posts. That's a lot to ask from the mods though. I'd just throw close votes at them and move on.

Comment: @approxiblue the problem is that flags will be pending for a lot of time during this time the question like "how to do X in tensor flow" will be answered with. "Do not know, but I have heard" and will get upvotes. This will invite other people to post crappy questions (actually I am thinking whether should I write right now something like "how to install TF on my macbook", answer it with a link and copy from documentation and wait a month till I get 20 upvotes.

Comment: You can always ask the [SOCVR regulars](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to review those question.

Comment: @Deduplicator this is a great idea. Thanks

Comment: I checked 1, 2 and 3, here's the summary: 1 don't know how to read python error messages, 2 had a misconfigured docker image, 3 for some reason pip was thinking it installed six as root, I suspect the user itself did this before hand for some unrelated stuff. All in all, those are general problems unrelated to programming. Any user would find the same messages.

Answer (score 7):

To be honest, I looked over this tag and didn't see anything terribly wrong with the early questions coming in. Sure, some were lazy questions that we see asked about any new technology, but those seem to be getting dealt with naturally. Even the ones you pointed out didn't look awful or completely inappropriate to me.

A number of "very low quality" flags seem to have been cast on these questions and so far most have been declined by moderators or review. Those flags should only be used on content that requires immediate deletion, and these questions really don't qualify for that.

Every time there's a new Android or iOS release we see a flood of bad questions, some even getting upvoted (people seem to think Stack Overflow is the bug reporting system for Google or Apple). The community does a pretty good job of handling these, and moderators step in when things really get out of control (getting flooded with duplicates or non-answers).

I don't think there's much for moderators to do here beyond what the community is acting on.

Comment: *'"very low quality" flags ... cast on these questions'* those flags go to the triage queue first. Right now, it doesn't factually mean a "request for immediate deletion" on questions.

Comment: @Braiam - I'm working off of [this guidance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288450/19679): "Is this an exceptional case where the community isn't able to get rid of trash fast enough? Delete. Else, Decline." In any case, most of the flags here were declined in triage.