# Can we see which moderators are active and their activity (at least percentage) in flag queues?

Tags: discussion, support

I am not a flagger-man, 'til today I've done 9 flags... And those were simple flags.

But all them waited hours 'til one moderator took action.

StackOverflow is a big site, with a lot of flags (I think), but then, are our moderators really doing a good job, or are there not enough moderators?

Sorry if I am being rude by asking this

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276946/can-we-have-some-moderator-queue-stats

Comment: upvoted. I like this idea. (If only because maybe they'll fix the 'all time history' for the moderator queue now).

Comment: And depending on who you ask on any given day, we're either doing an awesome job or a terrible job. Or no job at all.  It's a good day if any moderator pleases more than half the people half the time.

Comment: See how many downvotes you get in order to count moderators online

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Have you checked the all time history lately?  It's recently been tuned and should load for mods.

Comment: @bluefeet Just checked it. You're right. Thank Nick for me?

Comment: [What advantages do moderators enjoy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45961/what-advantages-do-moderators-enjoy). Probably should have a "Moderator Appreciation Day," considering all the work they have to do :)

Comment: @PetahChristian But how would we get the drinks to all of them?

Comment: You don't, you drink them all in their honor :^) @ryanyuyu *cheers*

Comment: *all of them waited hours* - so what? First, not all flags go to moderators; most go into the flag review queue, where users handle them. Second, what difference does it make to you how long it takes for them to get handled? Unless they're rude or offensive, it shouldn't matter how long they take to get handled as long as they do eventually. Why does everyone expect instant gratification for everything, even things that are unimportant? *My flag wasn't handled for hours.* What real-world impact does that have on you?

Comment: @PetahChristian a 'Moderator Appreciation Day' would be grossly unfair on those mods that are nocturnal.  The vamp-mods would need a 'Moderator Appreciation Night'.

Comment: I could honestly not care less how long it takes for a flag to be handled currently, no flag takes very long to be handled unless the content is truly controversial; however, I would very much appreciate more consistency in the handling of said flags. That goes for users in the LQPRQ (who have a very bad collective habit of reviewing flags incorrectly) as well as moderators (who do a much better job than the aforementioned reviewers, but still have differences of opinion in how flags should be handled)

Comment: I don't like this idea because it will encourage even more hasty flag-grinding over careful reflection. The internal stats already place sufficient peer pressure on moderators; we don't need public scrutiny skewing things even further.

Comment: Considering how few we have and considering the site has not collasped in on itself and considering that most flags are handled within a day of beeing raised, I would say they're doing a pretty good job. Lets also remember they're volunteers.

Comment: @MartinJames: A "Day" can be considered a 24-hour period. Not just between sunrise and sunset. That'd be a little tricky with time zones, any way.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused - what kind of flags did you raise? Are we looking at activity for diamond mods (They're janitors that work triple overtime) or reviewers (umm... can I even say anything without having shots fired?)

Answer (score 18):

I think that this is a tough question to answer. Moderators are not required to put in X hours of work or go through X amount of review queues per day.

Consider this:

What if you have a moderator that is lucky, and does not work due to some sort of wealth.

And then you have another moderator that works two shifts per day, and can only dedicate 2 hours of his time to stack exchange per night.

2 hours is not insignificant, but if our other moderator that has extra time on his hands spends 6 hours per day.

Granted this is an exaggeration, and probably not true... There will always be moderators with more time on their hands than others.

While the percentages will show exactly how much each moderator does in relation to each other, it won't show actually how much they are helping the community.

Also, flags are not the only thing moderators do. Which is another reason why the percentage of flags a moderator deals with is not a great representation of how valuable they are.

**Don't get me wrong,** part of what makes StackOverflow (and the entire SE network) so unique is the instant answers. If flags are taking hours to be dealt with we should look for solutions.

**However...** I don't think that we should make this a finger pointing kind of situation. Not only are percentages inaccurate (as I said earlier) but they are very critical.

Instead of trying to see exactly what moderator does what percentage of the work, I suggest the following:

Currently we have 19 moderators. All of which have dedicated hours and hours of time to this community.

I think we should collect some statistics looking at the following:

- Average number of flags needed to be dealt with.

and

- Average time it takes for a flag to be dealt with.

Based on this data we can decide if we have enough moderators, and in what areas we could use extra help.

Then maybe we can decide if we need new moderators!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure that user-facing statistics could be meaningful, or even properly interpreted. Some flags are easier to deal with, and can be handled very quickly. Other flags are aged away, instead of declined.

Comment: @PetahChristian Fair enough...

Comment: [More information on automatically dismissed flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347/288751)

Comment: Actually moderators are expected to at least spend 30 minutes of their time per day on the site([source](http://stackoverflow.com/election/7))

Comment: They're not required to though. It's not like any of us gets our diamond stripped immediately if we even so much as vanish for an entire 24-hour period with or without notice. Expectation != requirement. Of course we will do what we can in our own time. But the proposal by the OP will only put undue pressure on us and turn something that we already naturally do (which is what "expected" means) into, *effectively*, an obligation. Remember that moderators are volunteers just like everyone else.

Comment: @BoltClock Having hard requirements on volunteers just makes their job more stressful, and consequently means that less people are willing to do it for less time in total.

Comment: @Magisch: To add to that, in my experience, public scrutiny like that on a volunteer job is counter-productive for the volunteer's motivation. _"That mod is not volunteering enough of his time!"_.

Answer (score 3):

On a big Stack like StackOverflow, this may be nice feature, but Stack wide, not so much, since on a Stack with low activity it would allow users to infer which moderator acted on a flag and basically trace moderator actions to individual moderators, which seems undesirable to me.