# What is a flag?

Tags: support, flags, terminology

I have read on Meta about flagging, and I see the badge descriptions and whatnot, but I cannot for my life find out how to flag something. It feels like I have looked everywhere, and it's like hunting a ghost.

Is there a link somewhere in the posts that you're supposed to click to flag it, or am I perhaps not able to see it because of low reputation?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image: The option to flag is located below the text and tags of a post on the left. It's in the same group of links as share, edit, and close.]

Comment: and there it is, right in front of my nose

Comment: @scy7he: LMCtrl-FTFY

Comment: The upvotes on this answer ruin its recursive Inception-esque nature `:/`

Comment: @cupcake: well, points don't matter on Meta, so I'll downvote **only** to restore this Escheresque image :)

Comment: Joining the down voting campaign to restore order to the loop!

Comment: `The upvotes on this answer ruin its recursive Inception-esque nature` I wonder what that means... And actually I wonder what are those 2 more post controls and 2 more voting controls on the screenshot...

Answer (score 13):

> <sup>*The term and the expression "to raise the red flag" come from various usages of real flags throughout history. The semaphore red flag (or red light) on railways means an immediate stop, while a red flag is frequently flown by armed forces to warn the public of live fire exercises in progress, and is sometimes flown by ships carrying munitions (in this context it is actually the flag for the letter B in the International maritime signal flag alphabet, a red swallow-tailed flag). In many countries a red flag is flown to signify that an outdoor shooting range is in use. The United States Air Force refers to its largest annual exercise as red flag operation. Red flags are used for various signals in team sailing races (see Racing Rules of Sailing). A red flag warning is a signal of high wildfire danger and a red flag on the beach warns of dangerous water conditions (double red flags indicate beach closure). Red flags of various designs indicate dangerous wind and wave conditions for mariners. In auto racing, a red flag indicates a stop to the race due to dangerous conditions.*  
>
> -- [Red flag (signal) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_flag_%28signal%29)</sup>

"Flags" are the metaphorical name for a signal raised on a post to indicate a problem. The nature of the problem can be indicated by the *type* of flag that is raised: common flag types include "Spam", "Not an Answer", and "Close". Flagging is the most basic form of *moderation* available to members of Stack Overflow, and most folks' first introduction to the community-led moderation system that drives the entire site.

Flags can be *handled* by other members who've earned the privilege to participate in more advanced forms of moderation, by [elected moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and by [the system itself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

### See also:

- [The Flag Posts privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)
- [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)
- [Flagging a post for moderator review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24560/flagging-a-post-for-moderator-review)
- [Raising a Red Flag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/) (historical)

Comment: also worth reading: [Stack Overflow is not yet a vast wasteland: a history of moderator tooling](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251175/839601)