# Why were these flags declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently (in the past week) flagged two posts as "**Not an answer**":

- [This one](//stackoverflow.com/a/24935068/1190388) is clearly a comment, and NOT an answer at all (the question is a typographical error from the OP)
- [This another one](//stackoverflow.com/a/24975887/1190388), provides a link to a separate question on SO itself, along with a comment like sentence.

Both of those flags got rejected by the moderators.

How are those *answers* acceptable?

Comment: The first one *could look like an answer* to a mod quickly skimming because it does have code but I agree it should be a comment. The second one was probably rejected because it also summarized the problem along with the link

Comment: I could find myself with these declines considering I barely know JS and it isn't exactly clear what the problem was in the first one. I've had more questionable declines than these in the past few days I must say.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not one of the moderators who declined your flags, but I would have.

"Not an answer" is meant for posts that do not even attempt to address the problem the OP has. Things like:

- I'm having the same problem too...
- Thanks!
- I like birds.

In each case, the answer addresses the problem, in the first it affirms the OPs code 'should work', in the second, it gives another Stack Overflow answer as its answer, along with an explanation below the link. In both cases, they're attempts to answer the question.

They are, indeed, answers.

Comment: I like birds too, especially blue footed boobies!

Comment: @bluefeet That was an *homage* to you.

Comment: I thought "Not an Answer" goes into the LQQ - not to moderators anymore? That's what has been posted I believe by Brad Larson recently. So the community rejected the Not An Answer reason, not a moderator.

Comment: @staticx two moderators did. I know because I can see the flags and their outcomes.

Comment: Ok, this makes it sound like it hits the community before the moderators but since you can see how it actually played out, there is no argument. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251175/2591612