# Where is the option to remove "looking for a job?"

Tags: feature-request, advertising, stack-overflow-jobs

It is **bold** blue or **bold** yellowish and it wasn't there not so long ago, at least for me.

So is it possible to have a setting somewhere to explicitly say: Don't show "looking for a job?".

I'm not looking for a job and since you changed the site. When it is showing the first thing my eye see is that **bold** box on the right side.

Also I'm used to see Hot Question right there.

[image: bold blue]
[image: bold yellowish]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236776/no-i-am-not-looking-for-a-job-but-thank-you-for-asking - not going to happen.

Comment: Amusingly (as I'm not looking for a job) it thinks I am in a tiny village in Kent (Hildenborough) where unsurprisingly there are no jobs, as opposed to reasonably central London, where there are lots of jobs, which is where every GeoIP service I can find puts me.

Comment: @abligh Now you mention it, there's no jobs in my area so it tends to show me random jobs, I checked it just now and it was giving me job options from the US and UK, & I live in neither of those two countries.

Comment: I am not looking for a job and as such have no interest in these ads. In any case, I'd be willing not to block them since it helps SO pay the bills but it would be nice if you only displayed them every 15-20 page loads instead of on every page. Currently, every page displays them and that is just **so very much annoying** that some people might just end up adding them to the black list.

Answer (score 30):

You're seeing our Stack Overflow Careers ads, because they have no dancing monkeys, hula girls, or "marching ants" borders, so AdBlock Plus put them on their "unobtrusive ads" list.

Now, Careers job listings help us keep the LEDs on, and we've worked hard to never allow any that wiggle, dance, encourage harming monkeys, or take their clothes off. Plus, we're working hard to [show you jobs that might actually excite you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/).

But, as always, our ultimate goal is help developers, so if you can't fathom ever finding a better job, you get hives from even the most tasteful of ads, or you simply detest orange borders...

**You're welcome to have Adblock Plus block these, too. We'll even show you exactly how.**

We hope most of you will look at the ads (are you *sure* you have [the best job on the planet?](https://stackexchange.com/work-here)) but if you want Adblock to keep blocking them, we don't want to stand in your way.  Here's how to change the setting, from [AdBlock's site](https://adblockplus.org/en/acceptable-ads):

> You need to "Allow some non-intrusive advertising" in Adblock Plus's
> settings:
>
> On Firefox: click the Adblock Plus icon and choose Filter Preferences
> from the menu. Uncheck "Allow non-intrusive advertising" and you are
> done.
>
> On Chrome: right-click the Adblock Plus icon in the address bar on the
> right, then choose Options and uncheck "Allow non-intrusive
> advertising."
>
> On Opera: click the Opera menu button in the left corner at the top
> (on OS X: click Window at the top), choose Extensions, find Adblock
> Plus there, click on Options and uncheck "Allow non-intrusive
> advertising."
>
> On Internet Explorer: click the Adblock Plus icon in the status bar on
> the right, then choose Options and uncheck "Allow non-intrusive
> advertising."
>
> On Safari: click the Adblock Plus icon in the address bar on the left,
> choose Options, and uncheck "Allow non-intrusive advertising"
>
> On Android: click the Adblock Plus icon in the notification bar at the
> top, then uncheck "Acceptable Ads / Allow some non-intrusive
> advertising."

**Note:  Some users are reporting this ABP setting isn't working for them. We've contacted them to report the issue, as it should be simpler for you, but here's a workaround for now:**
(Borrowed from [Barmar's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285269/347414)).

> - Go to a page with the "Looking or a job?" ad
> - Click the ABP Extension
> - Select "Block Element" (Nothing much will happen)
> - Highlight the outline of the ad, which will select all of its components
> - Click to select
> - It'll look like you've blocked only one color ad ("blue" or "orange") but in our tests, it covers both.

At the end of the day, we think it's our job to serve you ads that *may actually be useful to you*, but anything that makes it harder for the kind of users who post here just isn't worth it.

Comment: _We'll even show you exactly how._ That would be nice. However it doesn't work for me. I have unchecked "Allow non-intrusive advertising" but the (to me totally useless) noise still pops up. (FF24.8.1ESR, AdblockPlus2.6.6)

Comment: @TaW, okay - sorry.  That shouldn't be.  We'll test a coupla browsers and try to see what's happening there.

Comment: @TaW, thanks for the report - see my edit above.

Comment: Now it is working, at least it looks like it. There was a time when I had it woking on one Tab but not on another n the same Browser instance. I have upgraded Adblock to the last version and now it seems to work.. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I have the latest AdBlock Plus (2.6.7), and it's not working. Nor is there a "Block Element" item in its menu, so I have no way of doing the workaround.

Comment: @RobH I had the same situation. I found a workaround, check out my answer on this question.

Comment: Block Element has been working for me since I posted my answer, but suddenly tonight it stopped working. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: And today suddenly it has started working again. Any idea what's been going on this week?

Answer (score 17):

I've also only started seeing this. Last week I cannot remember it being there at all, despite other questions about this being created many months ago.

I have several problems with it:

1. I'm always open to being made aware of jobs in my area - even if I'm not especially looking for a change, but I don't want this forced upon me. It should be my choice.
2. Most of the jobs listed do not appear to be at all relevant to my skillset. In the screenshot I've posted below you can see the *Android Developer* job - I have **both** the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tags toggled as *ignored*. Why am I even seeing this?
3. It's incredibly intrusive on my Stack Overflow experience. The background is unnecessarily dark and it doesn't even load at the same time as the other elements within the sidebar. If I refresh the page, I see my favourite tags and the hot network questions list, then all of a sudden this jobs box appears between the two.

I hate to say it, but even though I'm a frequent user of StackOverflow's Careers site, upon navigating through around 10 pages I've been forced to block the *Looking for a job?* box with my browser's ad blocker. It's just far too much of an annoyance in its current state.

Why can't it just look like this?

[image]

Comment: Because if it looked like that, fewer people would click on it, and they'd have to display it even more often to maintain current revenues. (They explicitly told us that click-through increased very significantly when they added those colors.)

Comment: "Most of the jobs listed do not appear to be at all relevant to my skillset.": http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/

Answer (score 13):

I'm guessing you're a user of Adblock Plus?

It seems the jobs sidebar ad was recently added to the whitelist. If you turn off ABP's "Allow some non-intrusive advertising" option, it will be hidden again as it was before.

If you want to suggest specific changes, I recommend asking a new question. An option to remove the ad entirely is almost certainly not going to happen.

Comment: Interestingly I use Adblock, not Adblock Plus, and I too have only recently started noticing these.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly same here. right-click->'block this ad' and playing with the slider a bit worked.

Comment: And Microsoft Azure ads are coming through too... To get rid of them add `stackoverflow.com##DIV[id^="adzerk"][class="everyonelovesstackoverflow"]` to the adblock list (adblock->options->customize).

Answer (score 8):

I'm a Stack Exchange employee and I also see these ads every time I load up Stack Overflow and Server Fault. Unlike our regular ads, there's no [privilege level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) to reduce the number of Careers ads. I've only been at this job for a [year and a half](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/please-welcome-jon-ericson-community-manager/) and have no desire to change employers right now. Even if I did, I'm not often enticed by the listings I see. So I sympathize with your annoyance.

The specific thing you are asking for, an option to remove these ads altogether, is unlikely to happen. Partially that's because the [revenue from showing Careers ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236780/1438) helps pay our developers who add new features, fix bugs, and keep our servers running efficiently. But the larger reason is that we *really do* want to help every developer have a better experience at their job than they do now.

Joel talks about Stack Overflow being [programmer Jerusalem](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/andreessen-horowitz-invests-in-stack-exchange/). Metaphorically speaking, we think Stack Overflow can be a place where all programmers gather and find security. In one way, our existing collection of questions and answers does just that. We as a community haven't solved all our problems (nor are we likely to), but Stack Overflow has succeeded in drawing all sorts of programmers and giving them practical professional guidance. It's a minor miracle achieved by thousands of [user-moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling).

But that's not really enough. While it's great you no longer need to spend days or weeks searching for some poorly documented feature or tracking down some tricky bug, many of you still work out of an [open office plan](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/why-we-still-believe-in-private-offices/). Many of you are required to waste hours of your life travelling to work rather than [working remotely](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/why-we-still-believe-in-working-remotely/). Many of your employers pinch pennies by not providing the tools you need to do your job. We honestly believe that Stack Overflow Careers can help.

In my own experience it's easy to get settled in a good, but not great programming job. As an intern, I had a private office, flexibility in choosing the technology I worked with, access to well-configured computers, and managers who left technical decisions up to me. Over the course of 15+ years at the same job, cost-cutting and changes in culture slowly eroded those "perks" to the point I was miserable and unproductive. It's easy to blame my former employer, but as a professional in demand, it was my fault for not speaking up or seeking a new position.

You can read about [improved targeting](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/targeted-jobs-for-stack-overflow/) being developed by [Kevin Montrose](http://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/) and [Jason Punyon](http://jasonpunyon.com/). We are looking into ways of helping you find jobs with the benefits you are actually interested in.* We will be watching the responses to our [annual survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285178/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2015) to improve our Careers product. While there are [succes stories](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8917986), there is still a lot of work left to be done. At least for the moment, one of the few tools we have to connect employers to great programmers is sidebar ads.

---

* Looking through random listings just now, I found a job that advertises it's ["Doggie Friendly"](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=Doggie+Friendly). That's a benefit I'd never known existed if I hadn't stumbled across it. There's got to be a way of matching employers and candidates who care about unusual benefits like this one.

Comment: I understand the purpose of the ads and agree with the view SO has in terms of bettering the developer community by helping us get better jobs, but... What about those of us that aren't looking for better jobs? or don't wish to look for better jobs **while in the office at my current job!** I've blacklisted the site as much as i can here at work simply so that i don't accidentally end up at the careers portion of the site while at work. I feel like while on SO i have to be very careful where i click because i may end up at a job searching site.

Comment: @KevinB: I get it. It was odd to be be fiddling with my resume when my former boss came by my cubicle. Maybe we should provide a [boss button](http://www.buzzfeed.com/erikmalinowski/the-evolution-of-the-march-madness-boss-button)? But one advantage of having ads available for _everyone_ is that there's plausible deniability. But, yeah. Ads are far from perfect.

Comment: The one place that gets me the most is the link in the header, just under meta so. It is colored to look just like stackoverflow, but it is in fact stackoverflow careers

Comment: @KevinB: You mean the one in the [top bar](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/)? Hmmm... I wonder if that's actually helping people find the Careers site or if most of the clicks are accidents? That might be something we can test.

Comment: I doubt *"most"* of them are accidental clicks, seeing how it's the primary link for getting to it from stackoverflow/stackoverflow meta, it just catches me every now and then. Fortunately for me i have that domain pointed to localhost.

Answer (score 8):

I use AdBlock Plus. I just discovered that I could get rid of this by using its "Block Element" feature. Click on the ABP icon, select Block Element, dismiss the menu, then click on the blue border around the job ads.

Comment: +1, Thanks - I put this into our "official" answer as a workaround until ABP squishes the bug.

Answer (score 5):

Using AdBlocker plus, go to **Options** -> **Add your own filters**

Add this one:

### stackoverflow.com##div#hireme

Note that I did it this way since unchecking the "Allow some ..." option didn't work.

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me, on Firefox using AdblockPlus 2.6.7

In AdblockPlus, click on "Filter Preferences..."

[image]

1. Click on Find
2. Type in `domain=stackoverflow.com`
3. Find all the matching exception rules and uncheck their checkboxes

I found two exception rules, and I unchecked them

```
@@||engine.adzerk.net/ados?$script,domain=stackoverflow.com
@@||static.adzerk.net/ados.js$domain=stackoverflow.com
```

In AdblockPlus, if a filter rule starts with `@@`, then it is an exception rule, that lets ads through rather than blocking them. So, you want to find those exceptions, and disable them. That will allow AdblockPlus to block the "Looking for a Job?" ad.

Comment: Thank you for this. I spent a very long time trying to figure this out (albeit in AdblockPlus for Internet Explorer).