# Stack Overflow Annual Survey 2015 - Now Closed

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2015

> **This year's survey is now closed. Thanks for participating and stand by for results.**

<del>[To participate, click here.](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/so2015)</del>

Windows vs. OS X. Vim vs. Emacs. Tabs vs. Spaces. Lots of questions about who you are, how you work, and how you use Stack Overflow. It's all in there. Joel wanted to include a dozen "Would you rather fight..." questions involving herds of pygmy creatures but we left those out. This year's survey is a little long. That's because we know you have a lot to say.

The survey will be open for 2 weeks.

We're looking forward to compiling and publicizing results.

Comment: I got stuck on the first page. It asks me tabs or spaces. What if we have our tabs set to be converted into a certain number of spaces? *Technically* I'm using a tab, but it's producing spaces. What to choose!?!?

Comment: @animuson 'Spaces' then. You've essentially turned your [tab] key into a keyboard shortcut. What is *really* missing is the *'I really just don't care'* option.

Comment: Are there any tmz.com-style "Who'd you rather" questions? If there aren't, forget it.

Comment: How about if you just tell me exactly how many M&M's are in the jar?

Comment: For the *Which of the following would make you most likely to respond to a message about a new job opportunity?* question, the first option (*Message is personalized*) feels redundant when the next two options only work if the message is personalized, perhaps because that's how most such messages have been personalised to me?

Comment: The list of occupations includes students but not those teaching them...

Comment: So who's the poor sap that actually has to sit there and count the M&M's?  Intern season seems a little far off.

Comment: "How involved are you in purchasing the products or services you need or want at work? (**select all that apply**)" - This question has radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: "I don't use source control" -> Account destroyed.

Comment: @Servy I recall one of those challenges where the lid was off. It was a question of "how many m&ms when the conference is over" challenge. But harder and tastier,

Comment: @MichaelT: what wise-cracker put down *zero* and took off with the lot?

Comment: there are 787.34567897654567890 M&m's duh!

Comment: I think I spent longer counting M&Ms than the rest of the survey combined...

Comment: @wyatt Oh dear, I thought my guess (in that ballpark) was very unique.

Comment: No "some college" option?  Seems like I'm either self-taught or graduated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was long ago (there were demos of new software on the Apple ][+) so my height estimates may be off, but I recall something like 2'x2'x4' or so for the size of the holder. As a kid trying to eat 2'x2'x1" is a daunting prospect. 0 was not a sensible answer.

Comment: If I am familiar with SO Careers, I am immediately asked what made me want to try SO Careers. That doesn't exactly follow.

Comment: @Servy, we use Price Waterhouse Coopers for all our M&M-related activities to ensure the integrity of the count.

Comment: @samthebrand could you add some kittens too? I was disappointed that no kittens were added with the university update despite you saying that "some kittens added". More cats, kittens, and cutes are needed.

Comment: It would be nice if there were an option somewhere between "Rarely" and "Once a week" for the question "How often are you contacted by recruiters?". Maybe something like "Once every few weeks" or "About once a month".

Comment: The "How do you feel about the frequency with which you're contacted by recruiters?" question doesn't really have a meaningful answer for people who answer "Never" to "How often are you contacted by recruiters?"

Comment: @TheBlueDog FWIW, we used the list of countries found [here](https://openconcept.ca/blog/mgifford/text-list-all-countries-world). If we were doing it again, we'd probably have included "countries within countries," which I'm told might apply to Scotland and Wales. We'll get it right next year.

Comment: @Retsam There is also no option for "The current rate is acceptable."

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaay too long survey.

Comment: "*Which of the following languages or technologies have you done extensive development with in the last year*" - gives the choice of "SQL" and "SQL Server". That's a bit strange. Why aren't other DBMS also listed there (Oracle, Postgres) or other procedural SQL languages (PL/SQL, PL/pgSQL) assuming that "SQL Server" is a synonym for "T-SQL"

Comment: When it stopped being a stack overflow survey and turned into a stack overflow careers survey I decided I didn't want to take it from work.  Now I don't want to restart from scratch on my personal computer.  Odds of my actually completing it now, slightly less than that of correctly guessing the number of M&Ms in the jar.

Comment: Can we use windows on a mac?

Comment: The "no, I'm a student" options didn't work for me, since I'm a student but I also work full time.

Comment: @MichaelT He didn't say *ate* them all, he said *took off* with them all. That would certainly be a valid answer, albeit a bit thieftastic. Reminds me of a great snarky response in a random book I'm reading current - math question, you work at blah, you make blah, gas costs blah, how much do you have to work to take it blah miles? One kid wrote: quit your job, get a job at the gas station, steal gas when nobody's looking, it costs you nothing. (The test was looking for lateral thinking: he got great marks, but the teachers made sure to watch their valuables around him afterwards. :D)

Comment: Can I start a bounty to determine the amount of M&M in the box?

Comment: The question "What motivates you to answer questions? " should have another answer "To gain reputation and boost my ego" ;)

Comment: @fedorqui I can't stop you or anyone else from screengrabbing and asking in Meta (or Math or Stats or ....)

Comment: The survey seems to exclude those who program only as a hobby.

Comment: `What is your current Stack Overflow reputation?`, i didn't find any `50,000+` , `100,000+` :(

Comment: I'm calling it now, 324 M&M's in the jar!

Comment: "I have never been on Stack Overflow. I just love taking surveys."

Comment: The selections on some questions are weird. For example, there are no job levels between developer/programmer and VP.

Comment: I love peanut's. >:)

Comment: How many M&Ms are in the jar? **None, they're skittles.**

Comment: Again, like every year... annual compensation is NET or GROSS salary? For me, living in the EU, is very, very different...

Comment: Since I don't keep up to date with the current GBP-USD conversion rate, I have no idea which salary bracket I fall into.

Comment: My country isn't there, please add Guernsey & Jersey..

Comment: for the Tab or Spaces question, there should be an option "Fake Tab".

Comment: The boxes in which you want to fit developers are much too small. I'm not a "full stack web developer" or a "designer" or a "data scientist" or I don't know what, I'm a developer.

Comment: I sure hope you realize that "Health Insurance" is 100% irrelevant for people who live in countries where thats not a special (like Germany) but mandatory stuff, that everyone has anyway.

Comment: @LorenzoDematté I assumed they meant GROSS.

Comment: Answering the survey with the keyboard is no fun, because the focus is not visualized #justsaying

Comment: I read the 'it depends' option for Tabs vs Spaces as 'it indents'... (by the way, I agree with the others, it is focused to much on the American market, quite a few questions I wasn't sure what to fill in as European...)

Comment: If angularJS is a language/technology why not also Backbone or Polymer?

Comment: Call me a pessimist...It seems less like a SO survey and more a Careers2.0 "lets do some market research to help us better monetize our careers site" survey...

Comment: Heyyyy, where's the M&M counting part of the survey? I never saw any mention of M&Ms, Skittles, or any other rounded candy! I want a chance at that T-shirt! Or is it over? :(

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Added a free response for country. Better late than never!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness How'd ya miss it!? It didn't go anywhere.

Comment: @samthebrand What step is it? I totally saw nothing about M&Ms and I was looking for it (main reason I took the survey ;)

Comment: Just re-took the survey and I *definitely* did not see any mention of M&Ms.

Comment: I'll have to wait for some 79 points on SO in order to change my Reputation Bracket.

Comment: @TheBlueDog: You lost your referendum. Get over it already.

Comment: @MattBurland: Aye, we should have done it the same way you guys did ... ;)

Comment: @samthebrand Yup. Looked it up in private browsing mode (no cookies set) and the M&M jar came up. I pulled it up again while logged in (cleared my cookies) and no cookie jar...

Comment: *facepalm* I meant candy jar. Is it somehow linked to my account, eg. only above a certain rep or age can guess because of shipping/legal reasons? I really want to have a shot at that T-Shirt!

Comment: Shame there were no survey questions on the recent design changes. It feels very much like the criticisms regarding that on meta are being ignored.

Comment: Is the survey exclusively for en.so users?

Comment: @emrakul I have mixed skittles into an m&m dish on April 1 in the past. The reactions are priceless.

Comment: @ento The survey is for anyone who wants to take it and can understand this sentence.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I hope "don't care" means, "Either one consistently by codebase." Have you seen the comic where it's got Mac & PC, and one says "Tabs," the other "Spaces," and then somebody walks up and says, "Both," one frame before he gets beaten senseless? ;^)

Comment: well i loved the survey and almost all the answers but thing which is worrying me is that why i dont get any job proposal from career 2.0 of SO? i have almost 6.1k+ reputation . what to do to attract more recruiters?

Comment: not sure what m&m means but I counted the jar and got 576 pieces:D I need that Teeshirt badly :D ^_^

Comment: I wish there were some more answers regarding hobbyists and open source developers.

Comment: Current rep? You tell me, you're the one with the database!

Comment: [Perhaps it is obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey-2012#comment458266_158456) but what is the privacy policy for the survey?

Comment: What kind of answers are acceptable for the M&M questions? Because I answered: "not enough" since there is never enough peanut M&M's.

Comment: I love the `How frequently do you read Stack Overflow questions or answers?` => `I have never been on Stack Overflow. I just love taking surveys.` pair

Comment: Too long, ABANDONED!

Comment: How many peanut M&M's are in this jar? If my answer won then will I get T-Shirt delivered in India? :)

Comment: `"What amount of formal or professional programming training have you received?" Some CS...but not degree, or BS in Computer Science.` Why specifically highlight "Bachelor of Science", as opposed to any Bachelors degree? Some schools don't offer a BS, even though they have a Computer Science major. It should just be a Bachelor's in CS (like the Masters and PhD options). Otherwise someone with a BA in CS, strictly speaking, is stuck answering "Some college coursework...but no degree."

Comment: Hongkong and Macao are missing as countries of residence.  Can they please be added?

Comment: Let's not forget, it's just a survey..

Comment: I missed the mixed tabs and spaces option.

Comment: @samthebrand **Which desktop operating system do you use most?** *No* button for Linux...*really*?...really?  Relegated to "other", un-bloody-believable.  I'm so disheartened I can't finish.

Comment: " You have a Careers site? I want an invite. (please enter your email address below)"  I have it so invite me again, because why not.

Comment: That was one of those rare "I actual feel good about this survey" moments.

Comment: @Emrakul They're not [peanut M&Ms](http://www.gumball.com/images/products/display/peanut-mm.jpg)? sadface

Comment: @LorenzoDematté +1 on the salary observation.  Taxation is much different here and I know my monthly salary but not my annual income.  In the end I took monthly salary * 12 * 1.2 (approx EUR to USD exchange rate; now that I googled I see it's closer to 1.1 right now) and rounded up to account for completely different taxation and social security regimes ... Rather than rounding, I suppose I ought to double it to make it roughly comparable, but this is definitely not my area of expertise.

Comment: There were no CSS and HTML in the tech list and also, including the profile URL is like I can just pull link of any user and post the survey, or do we have a check for that?

Comment: This is a wonderful opportunity to give valuable result.

Comment: I am most concerned that there is no "I don't drink coffee" option on the advert your sending around for it, SE has a non-coffee drinking discrimination ;)

Comment: Barely made it in time. Just filled it out :) Thanks for continuing to make Stackoverflow a great place.

Comment: That's not how you close... oh sod it.

Comment: When the results of the survey will be published?

Comment: I guess results of the survey are too embarrassing to publish.

Comment: Btw. can anyone link to the results of the survey of last year? I only got them from 2012 and 2013: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/?s=survey+results

Comment: @Trilarion I may be wrong on this, but I think the 2014 survey may be the one that they're talking about in this post... Take a look at the survey results and the post dates in the link you posted. The 2013 results were posted on 02-19-14.

Comment: @Trilarion What apaul said. The 2013 survey was conducted in 2013 and results were published in 2014. The survey after that was conducted in 2015 and will be published in 2015.

Comment: @samthebrand Ok, simple mistake. So until 2014 they named the user surveys always after the previous year and now they changed to current year. That's why there isn't a User Survey 2014. Fine by me.

Comment: I am waiting for survey result only to know `How many M&M's were there in the jar?` :P

Comment: @samthebrand , When will the results get published? Could you give us an ETA?

Comment: When the result will be available ? I need to know how many M&M's in the jar

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan The results were released! The full results: http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015 The M&M's: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288605/how-many-mms-are-in-the-jar

Answer (score 230):

Could there *please* be a way to avoid the endless job/career questions next time (ex. if you say "Unemployed/I'm a student" once, then you don't get any career-based questions for the rest of the survey)? I'm still in middle school and although I did my best to answer them speculatively, I doubt they'd be of any use in terms of actually gathering statistics.

Anyway, [my answers here](https://gist.github.com/KeyboardFire/646e015079e8862ae59e) for the curious.

Comment: Very impressive rep for a Middle School student.

Comment: I get that the survey is a great opportunity to get feedback on the main revenue generating part of SO/SE, but @Doorknob is right, that was too much. Perhaps have a few mandatory (for non-students) job/career questions and then give people the option to either end it there or continue to the full set of job/career questions if they want to.

Comment: "I'm still in middle school"  The heck?  Impressive, man.

Comment: First year college student in the same boat. Must be even less relevant to you...

Comment: @PM77-1 If you think a middle school student is impressive, you should visit the LAMP tags: They are full of infants. ;P

Comment: Doorknob, you're in Middle School? Holy crap, that's impressive! I'm in High School and don't have *nearly* as much rep.

Comment: Youth is wasted on the young.

Comment: Question, @Doorknob. Did you get the Jar question? I'm wondering if it's an age thing barrier thing...

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness There was indeed a severe lack of M&Ms when I took the survey.

Comment: @Doorknob Yeah, I'm thinking there's an age barrier :( I loaded the survey in Private Browsing (no cookies) and it came up :(

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness - Doorknob is very bright.

Comment: @MartinJames I've gathered that ;)

Comment: Alas that survey (which I didn't fill, but thanks for showing us the questions) coupled with the increased job postings ads I see on SO makes me think this site is going the way of LinkedIn: http://corcodilos.com/blog/5913/linkedin-just-another-job-board

Comment: I'm also in middle school, but it was pretty easy to speculatively answer the job questions... however, I do lack experience, anyway... and what about remote freelancers? Also, I felt *this whole survey* was to gather statistics and improve careers SO

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I didn't get the jar question, so it must be. What did it ask?

Comment: @TheWobbuffet It just showed a jar & asked you to count them.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: Answer: one? :)

Comment: My answers very similar to yours, except my rep is is not that high :D

Comment: I'm 26 and this kid is probably a better programmer than me.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello never judge yourself by your reps. The more one is active on SO, the more reps he will earn. As simple as that. But yeah, OP is a good programmer.

Comment: Haven't you guys heard about ICT? I was a Telecommunications engineer.

Comment: I disagree. There *should* be a way to say "I'm a student" and answer the career questions anyway, For example for university students that are going to look for a job in a few years and might have clear ideas in what they want. There are also people that had a few years of working experience, then decided to take a degree, and they may know full well what's good for them. In the end, I'd simply put a checkbox "I'm interested in career related questions" for everyone and be done.

Comment: @MattBurland re: youth... so true... this kid will probably quit programming at 25 and have it all be a distant memory by 35...

Comment: I don't agree with this. I'm a student too but I also work as a freelancer (having my own business) and looking for a job. This makes me interested in the job questions. So even if I fill "I'm a student" I still want to have the job questions.

Answer (score 86):

Not bad, this. Not bad at all. Good job!

Some thoughts, not important:

- I wish the "Which of the following best describes your occupation?" question allowed multiple answers, as literally four of these fit my job description depending on the day of the week. Not all of us are in single-track roles!
- Also, including distinct options "C++" and "C++11" doesn't make much sense (at least make the former "C++98 or C++03"), especially when omitting "C++14"...!
- The M&Ms question is great (in general you've balanced this survey *really* well) and lol @ wanting "health insurance" from a job... peasants!

---

*Edit:* Reading the comments above, there are a few things I hadn't considered. Foremost is that I hadn't even *noticed* how this really does seem like a Careers 2.0 information-gathering-for-monetisation exercise, since there were really very few questions that seemed to pertain to SO activity itself or the community in any way that relates to our SO lives whatsoever. And the fact that I hadn't even *noticed* that is really disturbing!!!

Comment: `)`. And +1 for the "health insurance", not every dev lives in a third world country without public healthcare.

Comment: Yeah, I got to the occupation question and didn't bother going on. I use my math background to design machine learning algorithms that I then implement on embedded systems where I write everything from the device drivers to the HTML5 frontend.

Comment: @Katie: I don't think it was enough reason to stop answering though!

Comment: Thx - those are great points for next round.

Comment: The predictive modeling is obviously very important for Careers but it can also be used for improvements to the SO home page/interesting questions tab, which is not about monetization. So it has some co-benefits.

Comment: @animuson: It was "needed" because it was a fairly substantial edit after votes had already been cast. It's unethical not to include it. What is this, "fundamental alterations" day? :( BTW thanks for locking that other answer - appreciate it :)

Comment: @l4mpi: in that case, the survey-taker has the option of not checking the "health insurance" box, right?

Comment: @Teemu: "What is your favourite sport? [ ] American Football [ ] Baseball [ ] Bucking Bronco [ ] None of the above" "Well, I have the option of picking 'none of the above' but this is kind of insulting!"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, that would be silly, but not really the same as having one US-specific choice for an answer. I surmise that a significant percentage of StackOverflow's users are in the US, and therefore, this choice would be relevant to them, so I don't find it insulting. I guess it might be puzzling to non-US developers who aren't aware of the US health care situation.

Comment: @Teemu: It's something like 30% US last I checked (need to find new data for that, though). So an overwhelming majority have nothing to do with the US whatsoever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: OK then. Anyway, I've said what I wanted to say on this issue.

Comment: For the description of my occupation, I was hoping for some *“It’s complicated”* answer like social networks allow for the relationship status…

Comment: +1 for the Edit about Careers 2.0 information gathering

Comment: I didn't get the "M&Ms" question :-(. After reading this answer I opened the survey in Incognito mode and scrolled through it and found the M&Ms question. Is appearance of the question in the survey based on country/karma/employment or something like that?

Comment: @AndreyRybak: Are you sure you didn't accidentally click past it?

Answer (score 57):

I have had a dilemma:

> Are you familiar with Stack Overflow Careers?

"Yes!"

> What made you want to try Stack Overflow Careers?

"Uhm... I didn't try. As I did not see the need yet..." *(missing choice, it seems)*

So should I pick "Yes" and get into trouble later and be unable to opt in for an account. Or fake that I even did not have heard of it and get the account?!? (something I did not have heard according to my answer)

I saw what you did there: a trick question!

---

On a more serious note, something to think of in the next survey:

- I suppose it is not too unexpected that someone knows something but did not try it (for reasons)?
- I would like to have an account (I did not earlier, but at the moment I would like one), which was not possible as I choose "Yes!"...

Comment: I had the same reaction, including becoming interested in a Careers account as a result of the survey. So what I did was change my answer from "yes" to "I want an invite" and select "other" for the motivation question.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit confused about whether they were asking if I knew what the site was or whether I was familiar with using it. I'm familiar with the *idea*, but I've never used it, so I picked "No".

Answer (score 34):

> What are the most annoying things about searching for a new job?

I kinda feel like this should include "salary negotiation". I guess it counts as part of the "interview process", but it's a very specific part that I have a gripe with.

Answer (score 21):

I like the field to enter in your own job title, that should take care of many problems.

I do think a significant answer was missing from "Why do you answer SO questions", which is to learn new stuff. Personally I learn tons from trying to help others out, and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Like the jar question as well. Wonder how close I got. Hmmm... I've long wanted an SO t-shirt, and it'd sure be nice to finally get it...

Comment: Where was this jar question? I took the survey once seriously and again to just look for the jar question and both times saw no mention of a jar!

Comment: D'oh - using the challenge of answering to learn is something we talk about a lot.  Totally should have included it.  Great note for next year.

Comment: I was kind of surprised to not see it, which is why I made the mention... Good to know it'll be there next year, and for this year, there's always the other field...

Answer (score 19):

The list of occupations looks like buckshot. So many orthogonal options. A full-time student co-founds a startup business as CIO, and in that capacity spends her time developing software and administering databases; which option does she choose? Maybe you're more interested in her choice than the full picture, but you don't know why she made that choice and whether it aligns at all with your motivations for asking the question (Providence, presumably).

At the very least, student status could have been its own question. Full-time, part-time, less/none. Boom, done.

The inclusion of a category for other scientists and engineers would have been nice. I'm far from the only user here whose formal educational and professional background are "adjacent" to IT/CS but with some overlap. I'm interested to see the makeup of "other" occupation responses.

Comment: Yeah, this is tough. And you nailed it, we're interested in seeing how you self identify in terms of occupation. Also yeah we hope to see how this measures up vs. Providence. We probably could have phrased the question better. Right now about 9% of respondents are selecting a write-in.

Comment: I think the tradition (requirement?) of people having A Job Title is what makes it potentially hard to tease out that self identification. The executive who spends most of their time engineering probably very much *wants* to identify as an engineer, but their nameplate says CTO/CIO/etc. and they probably put a lot of effort into *getting* to that nameplate so they want to express that too.

Comment: that's a good point. This could make for a really interesting blog/meta post.

Answer (score 18):

Will the raw data (please) be published once the survey is done? I'm particularly interested in knowing the answers per participant (i.e., some anonymous ID) to do our own attempts of analysis.

The format should include a verbose list of answers per question, and a list of answers (or answer IDs) per question per participant ID. (Including the candy box, of course!)

That would be great!

Answer (score 17):

- **TABS vs SPACES**: Do they mean hitting the tab key, or using tabs (the character)? I hit the tab key, yet use spaces as soft-tabs.
- **OPERATING SYSTEMS**

  - I wish I could select multiple for things like operating system and occupation. I am relatively new at my job, and my main projects involve both Rails testing and Bootstrapping the app.
  - Asking which OS is used for work and home (if different) would be nice. It shows whether IT/programming industries work more with Windows or Linux. I use Linux at work, but Windows at home.
- **GENDER**: Finally, I am interested in finding out how many other female users will take this survey.

Comment: I did, do I count? :)

Comment: Yeah, I feel like a lot of people who use linux also use windows.

Comment: I use Linux at work, but need Windows to play 97% of my Steam games. I prefer Linux for straight up coding, research, data entry, etc.

Comment: I'd like to select multiple OSes as well. At work I'm on Win7, at home I have an iMac which triple boots OSX, Win7 and Ubuntu and I have a laptop with Win8. I'd say my time is split fairly evenly across all those environments as they're all good for different things.

Comment: I use OS X at work and Linux at home. I selected OS X because I work more than I use computers at home.

Comment: I think I use my phone much more at home than my computer. I wonder if anyone put android as their main OS

Comment: *Windows* at home? Sicko.

Comment: @tripleee yes, windows, doors, carpet, and walls.

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR**

This is a good survey, I like it!

*But it could be better!*

**Ok, let's be honest..**

Generally, I liked questions in survey (especially, the jar), but let's be honest - some of them will not be answered correctly. I will provide an example:

> **When evaluating a new employment opportunity what's most important to you?
>   *(please select 3 things that matter most)***

What is fine here - is first part. What is not fine here - is the second part. I always could not understand why HR-related questions are trying to restrict a person with "N conditions". Yes, we are living not in ideal world, but:

- Most likely, I will have more conditions for job place in order to satisfy my requests. I'm quite sure in my professional qualification, that's why I will choose, judging by **"Work/life balance"** AND **"Company stage"** AND **"Industry"** AND **"Salary"** AND **"Office location"** AND **"Tech stack"** AND **"Opportunity for advancement"** - and it's hard to say for me which one is "better" or what is desired more. Because - all of them are important.
- May be I will have two groups - primary and secondary - thus, is some things don't fit my primary group, I won't even pay attention to position / offer. And then - if I will find several options, I will take a look to "benefits" which will be in secondary group - such as **"Remote working options"** for example (but, remember, those are only for me - other people may have other preferences).

So the point is - in the example above - the people who are on advanced professional level - will not just able to answer properly. Because - it's how it works, if person knows that his/her knowledge is valued enough, he/she will be more strict and expect more from next career opportunity. Thus, I am not sure such things as "select N from.." should be proposed - if some precise/honest answer will be expected.

**Cross-checks?**

And now I see:

> **When evaluating job opportunities how important is the ability to work remotely?**

with an option to answer **"Very important"**. So, what if a person didn't check that in previous question (see above, there is such option there)? Will it be considered as a "lie"? (because it's "yes" + "no" answers for same question). Ok, I understand, that previous example doesn't say *"Select ONLY 3 and others don't matter"* - but then, I think, such overlaps should be reconsidered, so this question should be removed and "count of options" for previous question should be increased by one. I hope this is not about "checking applicant for lie" - in my opinion, this is a greatest mistake for each HR process, because it is about - lack of trust.

**Public projects?**

Here is another thing:

> **Which of the following would make you most likely to respond to a message about a new job opportunity? (select up to 3)**

With options: **"Message is personalized"** and **"Code or projects I've worked on are referenced"** (same as **"Stack Overflow activity is mentioned"**). I found these as an odd options for one question - because - how message could be not personalized and in same time mention projects on which I am/was working? So, it is about some "public projects" (so, let's say, open-source), but then, most probably, message will be somehow aware of me. Or, more, about SO activity. How it can be non-personalized and in same time, contain some data of my SO activity? It is confusing at lest - thus, one option includes others. It might be fine, if, again, there was no limitation on 3 possible choices.

**Conclusion**

Things above are not "just bad" - but they might be improved. Some things I just don't like in HR process and some questions in survey partly reminded me about that. So I created a short list, while was going through questions - and placed it above. I hope it will help SE team to improve such events in future.

Comment: _"how message could be not personalized and in same time mention projects on which I am/was working?"_ So don't pick the one and not the other. Simple. (Note that the reverse case is sensible.)

Comment: But that was the thing. What's the point to leave a possibility for ambiguous combinations? And, more, it is a possibility to "select 4 out of 3" (because, if I select "my SO activity was mentioned", I automatically will add "Message was personalized" implicitly)

Comment: *"how message could be not personalized and in same time mention projects on which I am/was working"* <-- simple. It could have a script that pulls the top projects by stars and inserts them into the body. There's a huge difference between "I saw you worked on x, y and z" and "You seem to really understand abstract concept a. I've been looking at the stuff you do and your take on it is really interesting. Have you thought about b and c?". The first is just regurgitation. The second actually shows comprehension (and while isn't applicable to every dev, is to many).

Comment: ^ nailed it....

Comment: @ircmaxell well, makes sense, but not always it is as in described scenario. Also, it's not only overlapping with that option about projects, but about SO activity too. I was thinking about - that every possible choice should have sense by design.

Comment: No, not always. That's why you don't "always" pick those options. What am I missing here.....?

Comment: Personalized, yeah, that will make the marketing OK. Some of the nigerian spam is also now personalized. Somehow, addressing me by my first name doesn't help Prince Bufuku seem any more relevant or trustworthy on his request for my aid in moving $31,415,900 hidden in a trunk box marked 'raspberry pie'.

Answer (score 11):

I'm particularly interested in the Tabs vs. Spaces debate. *I'm on the* <kbd>Tab</kbd> *side, by the way.*

Also, I'm not sure what is the criteria for the jar question to appear, but here it is for anyone who missed it:

> [image: how many m&ms are in the jar]

Comment: any gueses on this?

Comment: Yeah, I nearly answered this wrong, but after a closer look, I noticed that only 43 of them are actually *peanut* M&Ms. The remaining 121 are *normal* M&Ms.

Comment: @Marco13 Are you sure it is 43 and not 42?

Comment: How the heck did u calculate that?

Comment: No idea what peanut M&M's are since M&M's are not popular around here and I don't remember if I've even seen any being sold. I thought everything in that jar was a peanut M&M and answered accordingly.

Comment: I did the same as @mcmlxxxvi. I don't even know what an M&M is (and couldn't care any less), so I just assumed that each of those things is an M&M (whatever the heck that means), and answered accordingly.

Comment: See the problem for me is that i don't even know how peanuts look like. I later Googled for the peanut look and it's like almost all those marbles in there are peanuts

Comment: Lets say I did get it right, Do they deliver to African countries also (as the tradition goes, FOR FREE)

Comment: The answer is simple: 0

Comment: I couldn't get hold of Dr. Dre and since Slim Shady is not an answer, I followed @mcmlxxxvi reasoning too.

Comment: What the **** are M&Ms anyways? No, I'm not going to google :P

Comment: The M&Ms might be a reference to [Van Halen](http://www.entrepreneur.com/article/232420).

Answer (score 11):

This question:

> When evaluating a new employment opportunity what's most important to you? (please select 3 things that matter most)

seemed to be missing an option along the lines of "I was out of work for so long I accepted the first serious offer I got" option. The options I selected weren't irrelevant, but what mattered the most is that they actually wanted to hire me.

Answer (score 10):

The survey was pretty good except for the points that Doorknob made, but... why is everyone mentioning something about a jar question? I didn't see any question asking me to put how many M&M's are in the jar like many people are complaining about. RPi Awesomeness pointed out that it may have to do with age. Can someone clear this up for me?

Edit: I viewed it again, leaving nothing for age, and it popped up... so I guess it shows at random? Anyway, I think that's unfair... let EVERYONE try out for the t-shirt!

PS: My guess is 550, so you guys can take that number with your friend's and yours and divide it by 3 or whatever, just felt like putting it there :P

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's 42 M&Ms

Comment: @ivarni Oh, yeah, that answer is also valid.

Comment: Maybe depending on the country? They don't want to send it to Afghanistan?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Shipping isn't that expensive from the US to Afghanistan.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Might not be related to shipping cost, but more with other reasons. Maybe embargoes or similar. (Afghanistan seems a bad example.)

Answer (score 10):

A list of nice question(excluding the careers questions), But there is only one thing which is really killing me,

> Why I really have to count the M&Ms to get a Stack overflow shirt

Why don't we just get a Shirt if we get our rep passed `10,000`(not too many people achieve that 10,000 count, not even me), Those people are really worthy of getting that as a gift for serving the site, aren't they.

I know this looks like some kind of question, but cheers

Comment: If you can see [this](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) you would surprise that there are 6k+ users who're with 10k+ reputation. This is just **too many** users. I'm sure SE would give such t-shirts to each of them (even I'm not in that league). But one who would really guess to the approx. & nearest value of peanuts in the jar would may get this t-shirt. So you only have to guess, don't need to count it. I used my mind to get approx. count in 5 seconds. Cheers!

Comment: i required more time about 10 minutes.. but its ok

Comment: I bet, that's just for a fun. No body gonna guess the exact count out of it.

Answer (score 9):

I did stop halfway, too, sorry. As for many other surveys I did happen to try to fill, it doesn't take reality into consideration. Do not take offence, however, because this is a standard among surveys.

Examples:

I'm a freelancer, how am I supposed to work in only 1 industry and not starve? I've got a number of customers, every one in its own sector, probably half of those listed fit my current/last two month/next two month customers, and I work on a few projects at the same time often for the same customer in different industry.

Being a freelancer means I'm obviously responsible for each thing bought at work, because I am my "work place", I'm not going ask anyone if I want to buy a new PC (well, except the bank, but that is another story), so whatever answer I do choose it's the wrong one.

And so on...as I said, however, this is the same with every single survey (found some where they ask if you are a freelancer and then ask how many employee your company has. Wait, which company? Can't have employees while being a freelance...)

Answer (score 7):

This survey was way too long. I don't think it is very effective for collecting data, because my guess is 90% or more applicants don't complete it. Most people are completing this at work and they are *busy*

Comment: Yup, it's long. But I don't think necessarily too long. Right now about 80% of respondents are completing the survey.

Comment: Wow. That number is much better than I guessed

Answer (score 7):

**Which of the following would make you most likely to respond to a message about a new job opportunity?**

How about an option for "*If I was looking for a new job*" ... if I'm not looking, I'm unlikely to respond to *any* message!

Answer (score 6):

I didn't see an option for my level of education (2-year Associates Degree in Software Applications and Programming). There were options for Bachelors (4 years) and Masters (8 years), but no Associates.

Also, I needed more time to count the M&Ms... wish they hadn't been mid-survey.

Comment: What does the position of the M&M question have to do with the time it takes to answer the question?

Comment: @TylerH I was impatient to finish the survey that is all. I didn't want to stop to count M&Ms, but I wanted more time to count the M&Ms later on :)

Comment: Ahh. I saw the counting question at the very beginning of the survey. I didn't know its placement was random.

Comment: In most of the world, I think Bachelor is 3 years and Master 4-5 years.

Comment: @Lundin: It might depend on the major, but in the US I've rarely seen a Bachelor's (especially in Science) under 4 years. Edit: maybe I should add, for reference, that I graduated in 2008. Perhaps times are a changin'.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Perhaps it depends on whether or not the education requires real-world practice at a company before you get the degree, and whether or not you count that time as part of the education.

Answer (score 6):

Would be nice if self employed developers who sell their own products get some love in the *current employment status* question.

I don't identify as freelancer or contractor, I sell my own products.

Answer (score 5):

Here is probable answer for M&M's question:

The `container` is logically integrated shape for `Square` and `Circle`.
It has `9 x 6` (`rows x columns`). In last smaller row it has `9` M&M's and gradually `1` M&M's added in each row from bottom to top, right?

So mathematically it is:

```
9*6 + 10*6 + 11*6 + 12*6 + 13*6 + 14*6 + 15*6 + 16*6 + 17*6
```

On simplefication:

```
6(9 + 10 + 11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 15 + 16 + 17)
= 6*117
= 702.
```

So answer is `702`.

Have fun!

Comment: I used the volume of a trapezium and multiplied it by 6, hence my answer landed to 540.

Answer (score 4):

After Suvey has been closed... what was the final Answer to the M&M question?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, to start off with - I don't have a thing to say about the M&M question.

The survey was good, except some of the "pick only 3" were a bit much.

My only comment is whenever the survey is over, if it could be compared with the previous year's survey result (is that even possible? I remember last year's survey being more SO oriented) that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of M&Ms isn't 1,337 or 9,001, I will be very disappointed.

Comment: Did you take the survey twice?

Comment: No, it's leetspeak. The former means "elite" and the later is from a pretty popular meme.

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled the survey but i was totally confused by 1 thing:

you put `frontend developer` as job title, but when you have to answer about language/technologies used, there is no checkbox for the backbone of this job (and also of this page you're reading),  like `HTML` and `CSS`, or other frontend stuff like `sass`, `zurb-foundation` framework, `jQuery`, `jquery-ui` etc. etc.
even if these tags are in the top-10 popular chart
https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular

just tell me, why?
i think that this "detail" will invalidate the questions about tech/languages

Comment: Which compiler did you use?

Comment: Why do you think a compiled language is a prerequisite for serious work? If something really needs to be optimized for performance, that's the last step of the research and development process.  Recall Hoare's dictum.

Comment: Compiler? for what? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can do the survey a second time?

I just tried to look at my submitted answers, but when I used the link the survey wasn't filled in, and I coudl submit it once again.

Isn't it linked (under the hood, semi-anonymously) to my SE account?

Is there a way to find out my own answers?

Answer (score -2):

According to me survey is very long. It should be short and effective. I think most of people left it in between.

I just completed survey and looks good collection of questions. It seems some things can avoid like salary specific questions/options. Also options should be limited.

In questions where allow to select max. 3 options at there  it should allow at least 5 options to select. Jar question was funny and interesting also. We can say its refreshment from continue survey questions...

Answer (score -2):

"**how message could be not personalized and in same time mention projects on which I am/was working**" 
It could have a script that pulls the top projects by stars and inserts them into the body. 
There's a huge difference between "I saw you worked on x, y and z" and "You seem to really understand abstract concept a. I've been looking at the stuff you do and your take on it is really interesting. Have you thought about b and c?". The first is just regurgitation. The second actually shows comprehension (and while isn't applicable to every dev, is to many).

Answer (score -5):

I started servey.. and I closed it halfway. Reasons? I get annoyed by questions, which makes no sense **to me**.

Some page has a question *"Are you interested in new job opportunities?"* and I say **Nope**, and then **several following pages** (shortly after cookies picture) are basically **keep asking me about job opportunities**.

Sorry, but no. Just no. Clever survey - yes. Stupid survey - no.

P.S.: I don't want T-Shirt anyway.

P.S.S.: there are `0` M&M's.. I think..

Comment: You should go back and count the M&Ms again... I removed the blue ones so there's a negative amount now.

Comment: I think, it's P.P.S.

Answer (score -7):

I got the impression that StackOverflow tries to disguise the preparation of targeted spamming with career "opportunities"  by a few kind-a-fun questions. How witty.

Comment: Funny as a comment.

Comment: Even if much of the questionnaire is aimed at increasing the value of careers.SE, "Preparation of targeted spamming" is pure fantasy.

Answer (score -16):

I hear people qalking about a M&M question but I didn't get to see it :)
Now I can't get a t-shirt. (Little sad)

Anyway I think the answer should be 1111 because 11 is the magic number of awesomeness and 1111 are 2 times 11 behind each other, therefor making it twice as powerfull and awesome as 11, making it the number of M&M's in the jar (Warning: the amount of M&M's change to 1111 after reading this answer due to it's enormous power.)

Also I would like to mention that you might now want to ask so many job questions if somebody is a student of is less than 20 years old.

Try mixing up the questions better next year so unemployed people or yougsters also have some intresting questions. I am shure that it is possible.

Also a nice poll (Next to the Tab vs Spaces poll) would be

```
If (Condition){
    Statement
}
```

vs

```
If(Condition){
    Statement
    }
```

Note the closing }

Or how about this one `If (I=1)` VS `If(I = 1)` Note the spaces.

Anybody has more Ideas, leave them in the comments.

Comment: These syntactic preference questions really depend on the programming language.

Comment: That's true but the most used ones are using these. If you have some better ones feel free to comment them so everybody can see

Comment: Why the downvotes these suggestions are good right

Comment: @CoderGuy On Meta, downvotes mean  disagreement.

Comment: so that means I am the only one that agrees or are there any people that agree

Comment: It means some of the people who agree decided to upvote, and some of the people that disagree decided to downvote. You don't have enough rep yet to see how many voted in each direction. At the time of this comment, you have 5 upvotes on this answer.