# Where can I see the 2014 Stack Overflow User Survey results?

Tags: discussion, survey

Some days or perhaps even a month ago, I saw a survey on Stack Overflow. I found [this survey result](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/), but that is for 2013.

Where can I find the results of the 2014 Stack Overflow survey?

Comment: Be patient. They're counting M&Ms.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat Wow, hmmm, maybe they should discard all those entries as a lesson.

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I find it interesting that not even programmers realise that you can jump around in a dropdown by typing.

Comment: @keyser They probably realize it but are just lazy. Might be related to that misguided axiom "the best programmers are lazy programmers".

Comment: The question remains partially unanswered because the full sanitized results for the 2014 survey are not available. On the page for the 2015 survey I find results from 2013-2015, but only the data set for 2015.

Answer (score 38):

## Results are now live:

https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015

About time, right? Thanks for your patience.

And you can now download full sanitized results at the link in the footer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#download-data

Comment: I bet one of them wasn't me.

Comment: I bet the other one wasn't me.

Comment: I rather suspect those two people correctly *estimated* the number of M&Ms. ;)

Comment: Chance that those two didn't guess the correct number of M&M's: `(26000! - 25998!) / 26000! == 0.9999999985206531`. Do I win some M&Ms now? :D

Comment: I bet I would eat them all.

Comment: I was hoping more people to get the correct M&M's number; the real number of M&M's has to be way smaller than 26k

Comment: What *was* the correct number of M&Ms?

Comment: If only two people got it right, I'm gonna assume my guess of 1337 wasn't correct :P

Comment: Could you please disclose the number of M&Ms now instead of making us wait for *few weeks*?

Comment: @Cyber That's assuming that everyone has the same chance of correctly estimating/guessing the number of M&M's. Some people never saw that question in the survey. Some people didn't know what an M&M was. There's no evidence to suggest that those two aren't the world's foremost experts in M&M Estimation Science™. _(I also have no evidence that suggests they are.)_

Comment: I think they're going to have to redo the survey data now that they have learned from this post that clearly the most serious concern of most members of the community is their ability to extrapolate the contents of an M&M jar from a picture.

Comment: When you disclose the number of M&Ms, can you also remind me what I incorrectly guessed?

Comment: I never saw that question on the survey. It was not presented to me.

Comment: I want a histogram of M&M count guesses.

Comment: So was the entire jar filled with peanut M&M's, or was it a [trick question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285372/1858225)? Also, I second Avilyn's question about reminders for our incorrect guesses.

Comment: Also, how many weeks is a "few"?

Comment: Where are the results?

Comment: @KyleStrand Evidently it means enough to start calling them "months"...

Comment: Are the full sanitized results for the 2014 survey still available? On the page for the 2015 survey I find results from 2013-2015, but only the data set for 2015.

Comment: Sam, when can I see 2016 survey results? we even got 29th feb this year :)