# Where can I find the full sanitized results for the 2014 Stack Overflow User Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey

On the page for the 2015 survey I find results from 2013-2015, but only the data set for 2015 ([Survey 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015)).
The 2013 data set is available in a blog post ([Survey 2013](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/)).

Where can I find the data set for the 2014 survey?

Related question (answer only refers to the 2015 results):
[Where can I see the 2014 Stack Overflow User Survey results?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287346/where-can-i-see-the-2014-stack-overflow-user-survey-results)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find a list of all survey results here:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/survey/info

> - [2011 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/survey-results/) (published in 2012)

- [2012 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) (published in 2013)
- [2013 Stack Overflow Survey results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) (published in 2014)
- [2015 Stack Overflow Survey results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2015-the-results/) (published in 2015)

You'll notice we seem to have "skipped" 2014 - in fact it's just officially named the 2013 Survey since that's the year it was conducted. You should find [the sanitized data dump](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16C6ZeNSvd-qIg45J9E-vx2YCsD8w5oZaSTUtJ-52e-w/edit?usp=sharing) linked there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have the raw results? Not to distribute to everyone... But I am curious about my own answers to the survey from last year. (I did include my profile URL)