# When can we see the results of the 2016 developer survey?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2016

The survey is over now, can someone on the team tell us when we'll see the results? I'm not the only one who is excited to see them.

How much longer will it take before the results are released?

> **Edit:**
>
> Waiting is now over. Survey results declared. **[Full Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016)**

Comment: 6-8 weeks. Results need to be compiled, trends detected and a website designed for displaying the results and their writeup. Patience is a virtue.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314186/2564301: "*Just like last year*, we'll be compiling the results over the next month". The Full Results Excel document from last year is dated 21-Apr-2015, so apparently it can take a while.

Comment: Still no results, more than 1 month has passed.. ://

Comment: 21-Apr means that we've got almost 2 more months to go.

Comment: In 2014 were released right around the current date (March 6th).  So it could be any time between now and...  whenever? :-p http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287431/3033053

Comment: @ketan I think oded means it can be at any time but not exactly to the max of 8 weeks. check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/196352).

Comment: @Oded It's now been 8 weeks ;)

Comment: :D i think people are in hurry now. Can't wait and make pressure on moderator to declare result.

Comment: Extrapolating, the results of the 2020 survey will be published around xmas (2022).

Comment: @Trilarion So, results of 2016 survey will be published around xmas (2018) ? :p

Comment: @Rob - soon, young cricket, soon.

Comment: Woah, there's only 10 days since I posted here. Feels like ages.

Comment: When i participate in survey i have reputation below 10k. Now, i have 10k+. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the results now:

**[2016 Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/03/stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/?cb=1)**