# How many M&Ms are in the jar?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2015

This question was included in the latest [Stack Overflow user survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015). It is not a trick question (there are *only* peanut M&Ms in the jar). 15,486 respondents answered. 80 respondents guessed "a lot", 46 guessed "many", 43 guessed "not enough", and 22 guessed "none." All of these respondents were disqualified because their guesses aren't numbers.

500 was the most frequent guess (541). It is an underestimate by more than a few hundred M&Ms.

3 people guessed correctly. 2 left contact information. We are reaching out to them now.

[image: The M&M question]

And we're putting the finishing touches on the rest of the survey results. The big release will be published within the next few days.

Comment: And what was the correct number?  Damn, you people are teazes.

Comment: Can I find out how much I guessed? I think I estimated it around 1000, but I totally forgot what number I entered. Well, I don't think I left contact information anyway. So I must be the one who guessed correctly, and won't get anything. :)

Comment: @Will I suspect its the "if you don't follow the UI / workflow properly of answering your own question, you will find it difficult to promptly post a self answer."

Comment: I second the request for knowing our individual answers, if that is possible. It would be interesting to compare our answers against the rest of the sample, and I, like I'm sure many people, totally forgot how I answered most everything. :)

Comment: `All of these respondents were disqualified because their guesses aren't numbers.`  Where did the rules state that the answer had to be numerical?

Comment: If I add my own answer to this meta post and it gets more upvotes than the one claiming it's 940, does that mean my answer is more right? Hmmmmm

Comment: I was the one who didnt leave contact info. You may contact me whenever :)

Comment: Do any hardened Stack Overflow users seriously expect the correct answer to be the one with the most upvotes?  @DavidG

Comment: I didn't see this until just now, but I guess there are 940 M&M's in the jar. What do I win?

Comment: my guess would have been 588

Comment: ENOUGH M&M'S TO FEED A WHOLE NATION, A WHOLE NATION OF PROGRAMMERS EAGER TO FEED ANOTHER NATION, ANOTHER NATION, OF OCTOPUSES

Comment: If I remember correctly it was stated that they are peanut M&M's and I hate peanuts. Damn! You people have no taste buds.

Comment: The answer was zero!  John Skeet ate them all.

Comment: I forgot my answer. Anyone know a way of finding out what it was? Or at least a link to the survey so I can search my history? :)

Comment: Oh wow...found it. My algorithm was: `(approx volume of cylinder - PI*r*r*h) / approx volume of one M&M (837?)` and then assumed it's only about 80% full. So my answer was 1516.8.

Comment: I guess nobody read this... http://www.sciencemag.org/content/303/5660/990  ...or this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_close_pack

Comment: Urrgngen! Sorry, pet peeve, but couldn't you just *contact* them, rather than 'reaching out'?

Comment: Where did the survey even take place? I visit SO every day (literally), and never seen it. And more importantly, what is its meaning / significance?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Around the beginning of february IIRC. It was pinned to the "Hot Meta Posts" area for the 2 weeks it was available.

Comment: I love surveys. Will there be a survey about the survey?

Comment: @samthebrand It's now been approximately "the next few days" three times already. When will the rest of the survey results be posted?

Comment: I still maintain the answer is 42, for sufficiently large values of 42. Just sayin'

Comment: That *is* correct @DavidPointer I don't even remember how many I guessed, but if asked under duress I would say 42.

Comment: Why did so many people underestimate the number of M&Ms? I think either because the size of the jar was not in the right context (looks rather small to me -- where's the banana?), or because the size of the peanut M&Ms were overestimated. Was the stackoverflow sticker supposed to be a hint? Or at least provide judgement in size?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

## 940

[image: M&Ms guesses - Stack Overflow survey 2015]
(among 13,296 respondents who guessed actual numbers)

Best guessers by **occupation**:

```
                               Mean    Median
Quality Assurance            762.58    576
Machine learning developer   759.28    632.5
Mobile developer - Android   742.87    576
Developer with a statistics  697.47    588
or mathematics background 
Graphics programmer          661.61    583
```

Guesses by **rep**:

```
                              Mean     Median
10,000+                     713.04     589.5
5,000 to 9,999              699.14     574
3,000 to 4,999              701.60     555
2,000 to 2,999              715.31     550
1,000 to 1,999              672.58     554
500 to 999                  704.83     565
200 to 499                  714.39     550
100 to 199                  682.67     546
50 to 99                    696.35     543
2 to 49                     686.90     544
1                           695.92     546
I don't have an account     702.06     542
Not sure                    649.73     512
```

Comment: The real question is, who ate 940 M&M's?

Comment: @bluefeet: I probably ate more than that, but certainly not those...

Comment: I really don't think 940 M&Ms could fit in that container...

Comment: @TylerH you weren't the only one.

Comment: @samthebrand I demand a video of them being withdrawn and eaten one by one! :-D

Comment: paging math.se! can someone get the volume of the container and the average volume of each M&M so we can really figure this out?

Comment: @rlemon There's already some good information on the web about the packing density constant of peanut M&M's. I know, because I looked it up to answer this!

Comment: Is there anything that **isn't** on the web?

Comment: Interesting that most of the wild guesses seem to have been wildly high considering the mean is so much higher than the median in every case.

Comment: `We are reaching out to them now.` for what?

Comment: Insulin.... ---

Comment: @JacksonTale a box o' swag!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Because math. People can seriously can guess 2940, and be 2000 M&M's high, but there aren't nearly as many people who would seriously think that there are negative 1060 M&M's in the jar, and guess 2000 too low.  Since you have a hard minimum to the lowest guess, but no hard maximum, having the mean higher than the median is exactly what you'd expect to happen.

Comment: @rlemon 940 M&Ms would occupy around 880 ml in that jar. I'd say it looks a bit more than two thirds full, which would make the jar volume around 1.25 liters.

Comment: @TylerH I counted about 10 along one dimension. Since the whole content is approximately a cube, it would contain 10^3=1000. I really do wonder what I guessed, I might have been close.

Comment: Someone took time to *actually count the M&Ms* to find out the correct answer. I find this fact alone amazing. *That's* dedication.

Comment: @AurélienGasser If you're referring to me, I only counted to 10. :) The rest was multiplication. Of course you can't really count them, because you can't see them all.

Comment: @RetoKoradi No, I mean physically remove the M&Ms from the jar and count them!

Comment: @AurélienGasser Oh, I see. Well, that was probably an employee. Must be nice to get paid for counting M&Ms. :-)

Comment: We counted them. We used surgical gloves. We returned the M&Ms to the jar. I give you assurance this was a precise and waste-free operation.

Comment: I hope no M&Ms were harmed in the process

Comment: @RetoKoradi It was told in the question that they are peanut M&M's and I hate peanuts. So that would probably be the day I would get fired for disobedience and disrupting the work flow and it's not even funny.

Comment: Some poor guy probably had the right guess, but put it in binary...

Comment: I might guess the same but I forgot the digit I answered. Where can I see my own answers? :p

Comment: "Due to the popularity of M&Ms not only around the world, but including programmers community (e.g. recent Stack Overflow's survey question, " How many M&Ms are in the jar?"), we have decided to name the next version of Android, "the M&M". Android 6.0 M&M will be featuring..." ... (j/k, but I found it amusing the power of guessing on Android developers :p)

Comment: @samthebrand joining Rikesh request above, is it possible somehow to view our Survey answers? I really don't remember what  I answered and wonder how off I was... :)

Comment: @JacksonTale , For giving the winners the jar consisting of 940 M&Ms? ;)

Comment: Can we get a CDF instead of a bucket graph?  (# respondants who guessed <= x).  I think it would look pretty.

Comment: @samthebrand, please accept this answer, as it is the correct answer, for the correct reasons.

Answer (score 122):

Clearly the correct answer is explained by the following program.

```js
function strdiff(s1, s2) {
  function aClosureCalled(str) {
    var i = str.length, n = 0;
    while (i--) {
      n += str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return n;
  }
  return Math.abs(aClosureCalled(s1) - aClosureCalled(s2));
}

(function() {
  var nMandMsAGuessing = "How many peanut M&M's are in this jar?",
      // oh no they changed the number of lines in the logo :(
      sixStacksOverflowing = 6,
      fiveVariablesLexing = function() {
        return justCauseImRounding(
          strdiff(nMandMsAGuessing, oneSiteOverflowing) / twoStringsAssigning
            ) - sixStacksOverflowing;
      },
      // 4 & 3 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
      twoStringsAssigning = 2,
      oneSiteOverflowing = "stackoverflow",
      justCauseImRounding = Math.ceil;

  document.write(fiveVariablesLexing());
}());
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @jakekimds you press `►Run code snippet` and it does display the correct number. You're welcome.

Comment: @jakekimds it just gets the Unicode difference of `"How many peanut M&M's are in this jar?" - "stackoverflow"` *(the two strings that are found in the image in the question)*, divides that value by `2` *(because there are 2 strings)*, then rounds up *(I am a glass half full kind of guy)*, then it subtracts `6` *(the number of lines in the SO logo)*. All this results in the number `940`

Comment: This is strangely brilliant.

Comment: @Duncan, thanks, but I think it is more strange than brilliant.

Comment: @robbmj Is this how they actually decided on the number of M&M's?

Comment: @jakekimds, I hope not. This answer is intended to be humourus not factual.

Comment: I wish I knew this before!

Comment: @TLama, know what before when?

Comment: Know this *algorithm* when I was filling the survey :)

Comment: Now, did you use tabs or spaces for that algorithm?

Comment: normally I would use tabs, but I think SE saves everything as spaces.

Answer (score 79):

Ooooh, I just received the following email. Guess I was "reached out" to :-)

As soon as I've sent the money to this kind soul, I'll report back on what the prize is!

> Dear Sir or Madam
>
> I am writing this to you for very important reason namely that I have
>   been given SPECIAL PERMISSIONS to supply you a reward for counting
>   peanut M&Ms correctly. The CROWN PRINCE of Stack Overflow has officially
>   named the number equal to 940 (nine hundred forty) M&Ms and we must
>   urgently seek a recipient of the SIGNIFICANT PRIZE MONEY, equal to no
>   less than $100,000 (one hundred thousand dollars).
>
> I am writing to you because I too recently guessed 940 M&Ms and got a
>   LOT OF MONEY as a reward for this. It ONLY cost me $400 (four hundred
>   dollars) administrative fee to move the PRIZE into my account.
>
> Please, let me help you to claim this valuable prize.
>
> Kindest warm regards,
>
> FELLOW WINNER

Comment: Not enough grammar mistakes and passages lifted from random books.

Comment: I can move said "LOT OF MONEY" to your account for only $300 (three hundred dollars). I will also just need to know your on-line banking credentials in order to securely transfer the funds from the CROWN PRINCE-REGENT of Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 44):

What we see is not an actual jar containing M&Ms, it is an image of a jar containing M&Ms. So that "jar" actually "contains" no M&Ms. If you are asking how many M&Ms "are" in the actual jar, there is no way to determine that, as the jar cannot currently be observed - its contents may have changed since the image was created.

Comment: Please allow me to introduce you to the [Gricean Maxims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle) of conversation. Or, to be clearer: you know exactly what's being talked about, and are being deliberately obtuse. It's not helpful or funny.

Comment: @AakashM so much serious, I took this in a light hearted way.

Comment: @AakashM Yeah, I think this was just a reference to quantum physics and/or Schrodinger's cat.

Comment: Lol at this answer. The feedback to it should be YOU THINK TOO MUCH.

Comment: Counterpart to https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: Obtuse -> Shawshank

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images

Comment: I don't know if I upvote or downvote you, really.

Comment: I feel like the best solution is to play ball here--nobody said "how many M&Ms are in this jar?" The conversation's version of "the jar" was only implicitly related by the presence of the image (I don't remember what the survey text said, of course). So really, the point about this being an image and not an actual jar is an unreasonable conjecture made by this answer, if we're being like that. Onto the second point, the question never said it was answerable, so the premise remains in tact. Ultimately, the only valid part of this answer is the conclusion "I don't know." Great answer.

Comment: Seriously uptight people on meta *(26 downvotes??)*, it's obviously a harmless bit of fun WHY U SO SERIOUS?

Comment: That said, yeah, Lankymart is totally right, this doesn't matter even a little, so I voted up.

Answer (score 7):

roughly

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I did, but I miscounted the 17.  I keep coming up with 14 so was short by a few hundred.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not sure it's that you miscounted the 17 as much as the 17 is a bit of a stretch :P

Answer (score 4):

The thing that is most interesting to me about this question is not the jar or even how many M&M's are in the jar. It is the scoop that people use to take M&M's out of the jar with.

So yeah, that sounds weird, let me explain by asking a question.

What is the point of the scooper? Probably so that people don't sick their dirty hand in the jar.

On the outset that sounds like a good idea, but in actuality it's not. Instead of everyone touching a subset of the M&M's everyone touches the same thing to get any M&M. I suppose this argument is made void if the scooper is sterilized after each use or if the scooper is handled with a disposable item, or if you did not use the same hand to put M&M's in your mouth that you used to operate the scooper, but that does not seam likely.

But fear not there is a better way to get your M&M's from a jar.

I purpose a foot pedal that attaches to the jar, and the jar is on a swivel. depressing the pedal lowers the mouth of the jar releasing a small quantity of M&M from the jar to your serving apparatus. Be it your hand or  any variety of container.

Comment: Well, everybody touches the scoop, but nobody sticks it in their mouth (hopefully). Some people might be less bothered by touching something that somebody else already touched, compared to eating something that somebody else touched.

Comment: Well you would probably use the same hand to operate the scooper as you would to put M&M's in your mouth.

Comment: Maybe. At least it's good to see that all problems on SO are carefully analyzed. :) The real solution is gesture or voice input, with a mechanism that shoots the M&Ms directly into your mouth. That would be more hygienic, and a whole lot more entertaining.

Comment: I fully support this idea. Lets get the robotics.stackexchange guys in on this.

Comment: Only on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This answer describes [a common plumbing fixture](http://www.chicagofaucetshoppe.com/Foot_Pedal_Valves_s/2515.htm). Go forth and implement sanitary snacking.