# When will the annual Developer Survey be released?

Tags: discussion, survey

Has an official release day for the developer survey been announced yet or does it happen on a specific date every year?

I have not found any announcement other than [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=+title%3A%22Topic+suggestions%22+), which only specifies when results will be posted.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The survey is announced on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/tag/developer-survey/). Prior to the announcement there is often a call for review on the technical responses of the survey. To stay on top of things watch the [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tag.

Note that the survey is open to *everyone who codes* so you don't need a Stack Overflow account to participate.

Here is the list of prior announcement posts and their dates:

- The 2023 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424565) on May 8 '23
- The 2022 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417991) on May 11 '22
- The 2021 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407914/take-the-2021-developer-survey) on May 25 '21
- The 2020 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393644/take-the-2020-developer-survey) on Feb 5 '20
- The 2019 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379281/take-the-2019-developer-survey) on Jan 23 '19
- The 2018 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361588/take-the-2018-developer-survey) on Jan 8 '18
- The 2017 survey was [announced](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/11/the-2017-stack-overflow-developer-survey-is-now-live/) on Jan 11 '17
- The 2016 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2016) on Jan 7 '16
- The 2015 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285178/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2015-now-closed) on Feb 2 '15
- The 2013 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211850/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey-2013-edition) on Dec 16 '13
- The 2012 survey was [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey-2012) on Dec 12 '12