# When will the Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2021 be released?

Tags: discussion, support, survey, survey-2021

We are at the end of January 2021, and still I do not see any discussion or timeline for Developer Survey 2021.

Stack Overflow is planning for that, right?

This time it's too interesting to know how [this pandemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus_disease_2019) affected developers' lives across the world.

---

**It's 5th March 2021, and still there isn't any official update/announcement.**

Why has it been so late this time?

In *[When will the annual Developer Survey be released?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359679/when-will-the-annual-developer-survey-be-released)* the latest date the Developer Survey was announced was February, 5th (2020).

Comment: Last year the developer survey was announced on Feb. 5th. Just wait for it.

Comment: Since it's never been this late to announce it before, and the "duplicate" answer is out-of-date, I'm also curios when this will happen.

Comment: Here is the latest update of **30 April 2021** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407253/review-our-languages-and-platforms-for-dev-survey-2021

Comment: Update: The survey was launched on **25th May 2021** https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/25/the-2021-developer-survey-is-now-open/

Comment: It is kind of funny to see "Why is this late?" right below the line pointing out that we're in a pandemic.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Here's Teresa's update from today's [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/10/state-of-the-stack-community-product-q1-2021/).

> Update on our annual Dev Survey. Last year, we opened the Dev Survey
> on February 5, 2020 and released the results on May 27, 2020. As you
> well know, an awful lot happened during that stretch and we learned
> our lesson around needing a faster turnaround between the two
> milestones. This year we plan to launch the 2021 Dev Survey in or
> around June and have results back to everyone within 1-2 months. We're
> focused on shortening the window from when the survey runs to when
> it's released given how rapidly the world is changing right now.

Comment: Can I see the survey result from now? (sorry I'm new to StackOverflow and don't know when surveys results are released)

Comment: @ZeyadShaban as of today, not yet. They will post the results at https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey and probably at their blog.

Answer (score 1):

It was released in August 2, 2021.

https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/02/2021-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/

https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021

Comment: Yes, the title is somewhat ambiguous. The ***results*** of it was released on 2021-08-02. [Sample](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#developer-profile-experience) (*"Writing that first line of code"*). You could add the release date of ***the questionnaire*** ([2021-05-25](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359680)) to your answer. [Another meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397027) keeps track of the results release dates