# Review our languages and platforms for Dev Survey 2021

Tags: discussion, survey, announcement, survey-2021

> **Update on May 10th, 2021:** Thanks for all the responses, we'll be compiling and acting on the ones provided so far but can't commit to reviewing further ones.

As Teresa mentioned in her [quarterly update](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/10/state-of-the-stack-community-product-q1-2021/), we are planning on releasing our annual Dev Survey in or around June. In preparation for launch, we want to ensure that the list of technologies we ask about is up-to-date. Please see the different categories below and let us know if there are any relevant options (language, platforms, etc.) that aren’t listed. If you notice an omission, please post an answer below with the name, which category it falls into, a brief description, and any references to where it is used and why it should be included in the survey. **One suggestion per answer, please!**

On Friday, May 7th we’ll review the suggestions and decide which makes sense to include in the survey. Please make sure to add and vote by then!

Programming, scripting, and markup language:

```
Assembly
Bash/Shell/PowerShell
C
C#
C++
Dart
Go
Haskell
HTML/CSS
Java
JavaScript
Julia
Kotlin
Objective-C
Perl
PHP
Python
R
Ruby
Rust
Scala
SQL
Swift
TypeScript
VBA
```

Database environments:

```
Cassandra
Couchbase
DynamoDB
Elasticsearch
Firebase
IBM DB2
MariaDB
Microsoft SQL Server
MongoDB
MySQL
Oracle
PostgreSQL
Redis
SQLite
```

Cloud Platforms:

```
AWS
DigitalOcean
Google Cloud Platform
Heroku
IBM Cloud or Watson
Microsoft Azure
Oracle Cloud Infrastructure
```

Web framework/libraries:

```
Angular
Angular.js
ASP.NET
ASP.NET Core
Django
Drupal
Express
Flask
Gatsby
jQuery
Laravel
React.js
Ruby on Rails
Spring
Symfony
Vue.js
```

Other frameworks, libraries:

```
.NET
.NET Core
Apache Spark
Cordova
Flutter
Hadoop
Keras
Pandas
React Native
TensorFlow
Torch/PyTorch
```

Tools:

```
Ansible
Chef
Puppet
Node.js
Terraform
Kubernetes
Docker
Unity 3D
Unity Engine
Xamarin
```

Development environments:

```
Visual Studio Code
Visual Studio
Notepad++
IntelliJ
Vim
Sublime Text
Android Studio
Eclipse
PyCharm
Atom
IPython/Jupyter
Xcode
PHPStorm
NetBeans
Emacs
RStudio
RubyMine
TextMate
```

Primary operating systems:

```
Linux-based
Windows
MacOS
BSD
```

Comment: Btw, I am not sure if this was the case before, but how come Node.js ended in the "tools" category?

Comment: @OlegValter probably they meant npm.

Comment: @Braiam since you mention it, I don't see package managers at all in the "tools" category...

Comment: @OlegValter yeah, I don't get the tools category, it seems to be orchestration, CI/CD and application packaging and then node.js. Node.js is nearer IIS, fastcgi, wsgi web servers than the other things.

Comment: Why both Javascript **and** Typescript? I think it would make more sense to combine these.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - probably not a good idea, not every JS developer is TS developer (plus, it just would not be fair to those who prefer Flow)

Comment: True, but frankly all TS developers are JS developers. And I guess we're not being fair to our friends using ecmascript. Maybe an item "Javascript / Typescript / ES6 / ..." Honestly I'm not sure what useful information you might get from segregating them

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - so what? You do know that TypeScript is officially a compile-to-JS language of its own, right? ECMA versions aren't separate entities as well. What I am more worried about is why there is no Flow [probably under the "Tools" section] in the list (maybe paired with TS, but they are rivals, so it makes sense to survey them separately).

Comment: That's... Great? Good for flow, put it in an answer. I was talking about the (lack of) necessity in disambiguating between ts and js an es.

Comment: Is there any reason why some of the lists (languages, database environments, web framework/libraries, other frameworks, tools) are in alphabetical order, while others (cloud platforms, developer environments) are not?

Comment: The official name of the library is "React". Yes, it is hosted on reactjs.org and the tag here is [reactjs], but just like Stack Overflow is two capitalized words, React is one word, no adornment.

Comment: It would be nice to include major version options in this survey, especially for rapidly evolving languages/frameworks where a significant amount of people are still on older versions. C++, Python, Java, C#, .NET et al., Angular, and so on.

Comment: Why are Flutter and Xamarin in different categories?

Comment: Might be worth bringing in Deno as a Node alternative. Also, my general worry is this list already struggles to categorise. E.g. Kubernetes is a tool? Perhaps? In some ways it's really not helpful to think of it like that. And what about cross-cutting software such as NextJS, which is a development tool and runtime in one? (And isn't currently in either?)

Comment: I agree w/ @RobGrant; Xamarin should be in "Other frameworks".

Comment: What about Ajax & Codeigniter?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour - AJAX is not a concrete technology, nearly everyone (and I am gracious in the estimate) doing JS these days is using it in some sort of way (be it `XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch`, or libraries, I don't think it warrants a separate item

Comment: @OlegValter Agree but what about Codeigniter under framework at all i added another tools https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407381/14945696 - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407378/14945696 - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407379/14945696 -

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour - I responded to the first edition of your comment - no thoughts on Codeigniter, I am not a PHP guy :)

Comment: These surveys are far less fun after you removed the option to trash talk Visual Basic. It always got rated as the worst language when you still included it. I kind of agree that it isn't a programming language though.

Comment: Notably embedded systems development is 100% absent from this list. You might want to make it clear to anyone taking the survey that it's about web/PC development only.

Comment: I would still spell it "DB2", but it is now [officially "Db2"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Db2_Family).

Answer (score 76):

## Git

Where is git? No, really, where is it? Or it has reached such ubiquity that we all just presume that everyone uses it (sorry mercurial fans).

Comment: I don't use it... Google Drive is good enough for me for archives and I store 100% of my code in my computer as simple fies, and my IDE has somewhat of a "git commit". I do have git just in case.

Comment: Actually, this is good questions. We should have VCS question that also includes Zips or other kind of plain archiving tools, and None.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam There is more to VCS than archiving files. And you don't need to use remote servers or any kind of servers to use Git.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes I know there's no need for a remote server but I think all those complex stuff are just overkill for single person and non remote projects. So yes, there should be plain archiving tools as people should use them for small projects.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam If you thing Git is overkill for single developer and small projects, you don't fully understand what Git is for. It is not archiving tool. It would be in your best interest to try learning more about it and start using it. Even if you start with only single branch, it will soon become indispensable tool. If you think Git is too complex, you can also try Mercurial.

Comment: You should also consider VCS cloud/web platforms like Microsoft TFS (and its own VCS) and github.  Maybe older VCS too like SVN and CVS, still in use to this day.

Comment: @Zilog80 github isn't a VCS, github is a service that offers git repositories. Anyone using gitlab, github, bitbucket, etc. are using git.

Comment: @Braiam I Was talking about web platform with a VCS backend. Github has git as backend, TFS has it's own VCS and can be used with git also.

Comment: @Zilog80 if we go that way, then the sky is the limit. I prefer going with specific products rather than products as services.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam Just expect to lose all access to that code if you do something that Google thinks is not OK.

Comment: @TylerH I have a different account for storing my code and a different one for doing all sorts things that google hates.It's a perfect plan. Not that I will never use a Coding specific repository but for now, with my low stake code, it's fine.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam honestly, given that I have really bad code and stuff, I find Github so useful. It's changed the way I store projects, allowing me to work on them for longer, and develop better code.

Comment: What about Perforce? This great tool should have opportunity to be marked as "don't want to work".

Answer (score 60):

I would be interested in seeing how many people use something like  "Proprietary Internal Tool" to each of the categories.

Comment: Yeah, especially "proprietary internal OS" and "proprietary internal programming language" ...

Comment: @JonasWilms The latter is surprisingly common, and even the former is not unheard of.

Comment: @JonasWilms, could you clarify?  Your answer sounds equally valid both agreeing with the question or disagreeing with a sarcastic voice.

Comment: @bergi I know :) @ mark no sarcasm involved, just wanted to point out that I'm extra curious for these categories ...

Comment: @JonasWilms, thanks, that's what I thought, until I saw the second comment!  I myself use an internally developed supply/demand modeling language, and I've always been curious how much of the developer population has similar kinds of tools.  I used to work in the telecom area, and it seemed that most equipment at the time had proprietary firmware/os's built around whatever it was the hardware did.

Comment: Sorry, but what is "Proprietary Internal Tool"? I can't find wiki entry for this words combination.

Comment: @Sinatr, it is software written by your company, used internally.  For example, a telephone switch might use a proprietary operating system written by the company.

Comment: Then I guess we just need an "Other" field in each category which can be filled with what is missing or not commonly known.

Comment: @sinatr that would make aggregation difficult, also depending on corporate policies exposing actual names might be not allowed, whereas checking a checkmark is probably okay.

Answer (score 35):

## Matlab

Programming language.

Widely used in scientific and numerical computing.

---

<sub>The official name of the language is MATLAB, but I don't want to seem like I'm shouting with an all-caps title.</sub>

Answer (score 33):

## Erlang and/or Elixir

You might want to add Erlang and/or Elixir to the programming languages.

Comment: This. The main reason I've stopped caring at all about the SO survey is how Elixir still isn't taken seriously (despite still primarily working with C# these days).

Answer (score 29):

## NumPy

Consider adding it to the list of libraries. It's a bit surprising that Pandas is on the list but NumPy isn't, being one of the largest third-party Python libraries (and the *de facto* foundation of numerical coding with Python, underlying Pandas itself).

(I'd also suggest SciPy for the same purpose but it probably has a lot fewer users. And we'd have to draw the line somewhere. Although it's not completely clear why some parts of [the former SciPy Stack](https://scipy.org/stackspec.html) should be included and others not, with the exception of the now-defunct nose project.)

Answer (score 24):

## COBOL

I think the programming language COBOL would also be interesting as it gained [some attention last year](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/04/20/brush-up-your-cobol-why-is-a-60-year-old-language-suddenly-in-demand/).

Comment: What about BCPL? Or the Elder Furthark? Surely I'm not the only one carving my source code into rune stones?

Comment: LOL! They added COBOL, but under *tools*, rather than *languages*!!!

Comment: @CrisLuengo yeah, and NodeJS is now a programming language ...

Answer (score 22):

.NET Core has now been renamed to .NET.

.NET (as you have it listed) is actually called .NET Framework.

Comment: Just take it as *.Net*  and let MS marketing deal with the mess ...

Comment: There are still developers who use .NET Core, and did not yet migrate to .NET 5, so dropping the "Core" may be confusing. Probably it makes more sense to rename the categories to `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core / .NET 5+`.

Comment: Or better yet, three categories, .NET Framework, .NET Core, and .NET 5+.

Answer (score 22):

I don't see the venerable

## make/cmake/*ake

for the tools yet I see plenty of things built with them in mind.

Answer (score 22):

Programming, scripting, and markup language:

## [APL](https://apl.wiki) ([apl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apl))

*Note: **not** [alexa-presentation-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alexa-presentation-language)*

APL is the original [**A**rray **P**rogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) **L**anguage. It pioneered many ideas that became popular later (functional programming, Unicode glyphs, interactive programming, higher-order functions, etc.) and is lately seeing increased attention after having been around for almost 60 years.

Answer (score 21):

## Clojure & ClojureScript

(as programming languages)

Comment: Definitely. Wasn't Clojure listed as one of the top "languages I want to learn" in the last survey?

Comment: tangentially related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399362/11407695

Answer (score 20):

## [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/)

under frameworks.

Answer (score 19):

## Rider

## Webstorm

There are at least two JetBrains IDEs missing:

- [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) (for C#/.NET)
- [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (for JS/web development)

Comment: And [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) for C++.

Comment: And - special purpose - their MPS IDE...

Comment: Also GoLand for Go.

Comment: Might be useful to split these into 2 answers

Answer (score 19):

There are some build tools such as

## [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/), [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), and [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/)

that you might want to add to the tools section.

Comment: ...and maven :)

Answer (score 17):

## cmake, bazel

## conan, vcpkg

I like to see some tools added in the C++ area - specifically Bazel and CMake for build tools, and conan and vcpkg for package managers.  This area (C++ toolchain) is evolving *rapidly* and it would be nice to get a sense of the momentum ...

Comment: I think this should be split into 2 answers.

Comment: Or maybe improve @Braiam answer?

Answer (score 16):

Add

## F#

as a programming language.

Answer (score 16):

Another older core programming language which is allegedly [undergoing a revival](https://www.zdnet.com/article/this-old-programming-language-is-suddenly-getting-more-popular-again/) is

## **Fortran**

I think it would be an interesting addition to the list.

Answer (score 16):

## **LISP**

programming language seems still alive, many questions this day under the tag [lisp]. It's one of the two oldest language (1958... "Milestones in computer science and information technology") with Fortran, however new releases of some dialect implementations like [newLISP](http://www.newlisp.org/) shows that it is still in use to this day.

Thus, i suggest you to add it under *Programming, scripting, and markup language*.

Comment: I felt that this was too broad. Is this referring to the original lisp programming language, or all programming languages in its family, such as Common Lisp, Scheme, and all of their derivatives, such as Racket?

Answer (score 15):

Development environments:

## [Dyalog](https://apl.wiki/Dyalog_APL) ([dyalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dyalog))

Dyalog refers both to the specific implementation/dialect of APL that Dyalog Ltd. develops, but also to the entire development environment/tool suite that backs the RIDE (Remote IDE) and (local) IDE frontends. Dyalog has emerged as the modern torchbearer that brings APL development environments into the 21st century.

Answer (score 15):

## [Mojolicious](https://mojolicious.org/)

Under Web framework/libraries.

Since we are adding Perl as language we should add its web framework(atleast one).

Comment: Also add Dancer and Catalyst

Comment: Before adding 'Mojolicious' we'd we'd need to add CGI and mod_perl.

Comment: Why? CGI and mod_perl are not developed or recommended anymore.

Answer (score 14):

## Delphi

[Delphi](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi) under following categories:

- Programming, scripting, and markup language
- Development environment

Comment: Isn't the language Object Pascal and Delphi just a tool chain? Been 25 years since I used it, my memory is a lil rusty :)

Comment: @Lundin It is complicated... There have been some variations and attempts to call language Object Pascal, but at the moment language is officially called Delphi http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Programming_Languages IDE is also called Delphi, even though another name is RAD Studio, because other used language is C++. But if you purchase just Delphi language, you actually run IDE as Delphi, not RAD Studio (even though it is basically the same thing).

Answer (score 14):

## Qt

Under development environments (maybe also libraries)

Answer (score 14):

## Deno

Seen Node.js is listed as tool, it might be worth writing down Deno, the new-ish (reached the first major version in May 2020) secure runtime for JavaScript and Typescript.

Comment: Yeah, it was strange to see it missing (but the list itself is very bizarre with so many prominent tools missing)

Answer (score 13):

Thoughts about IPython/Jupyter (*Development environments* category):

1. **Remove the "IPython" bit.** It has been a long time since IPython became the Project Jupyter. I think many more people are familiar with "Jupyter" rather than "IPython" today. The IPython is still a great project but grouping it it together with Jupyter makes less sense nowadays than it used to (the meaning has changed).
2. **Use "Jupyter Notebook"** (with capital *N*). Jupyter is just a name of the project/set of standards rather than of an IDE. Many editors (VSCode, PyCharm) provide support for Jupyter toolset but are distinct IDEs.
3. **Add "JupyterLab"**. JupyterLab is the new interface for Jupyter notebooks; it uses the same backend as the "classic" Jupyter Notebooks but the UX and capabilities are very much different (in the same way as Visual Studio Code and
   Visual Studio are distinct). If it would be too many options, make it just "Jupyter Notebook/JupyterLab" (but then, by analogy to Visual Studio Code/Visual Studio, it would make sense to split it as well).

Answer (score 13):

### [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)

under Web frameworks/libraries. It is gaining a lot of popularity these days among Data Science and Machine Learning practitioners.
Since it uses ASGI instead of WSGI, it is much faster than the flask. It has a data validation system that detects any invalid data type at runtime and returns the reason for bad inputs to the user in JSON format.
I'm pretty sure a lot of people will vote for FastAPI.

Comment: Agree, although did it [make it to Mars](https://github.com/readme/nasa-ingenuity-helicopter)? :)

Comment: @Rob Grant maybe next time XD. Surely, it will be de facto for creating API endpoints for ML/DL models in the next few years.

Answer (score 11):

## VB.NET

under languages?
Note that this is a separate language from VBA.

Comment: They've missed VB.NET for at least a couple of years. Visual Studio Magazine [said this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/02/12/tiobe-feb-19.aspx) of it a couple of years ago: "By retaining the No. 5 position and exhibiting the highest year-over-year growth percentage among the top 20 languages..."

Answer (score 11):

How about UI technologies?

### [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)

### [Winforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)

### [Webforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Forms)

One may argue UI technologies aren't so big as e.g. Xamarin. Still there is a huge gap between WPF MVVM and Winforms programmers, and it would be interesting to distinguish them in statistic.

Answer (score 10):

Programming language

## **ML** (including SML and OCaml)

Comment: Today I learned that ML stands for something other than 'machine learning'. That being said, if you _do_ list "ML" I would be concerned that people like me who weren't aware that it's actually a programming language family might misunderstand the choice and throw off your statistics.

Comment: It stands for [a lot of things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML), but I think in a question that asks about programming languages it would be reasonably clear. But yeah, better safe than sorry, and disambiguate.

Answer (score 10):

**Online Code Editors**

Online Code Editors has become more popular in our daily which I recommend also to be implemented which we use sometimes to show someone something or to edit something quickly.

The popular Online Code Editors that I know:

- [JSFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)
- [CodePen](https://codepen.com/)
- [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)
- [Replit](https://replit.com/)
- [Try it online](https://tio.run/#)

Answer (score 9):

Aren't package managers also tools we use in our day-to-day? Granted, package managers and build tools should probably have their own section, but since you already compare JavaScript runtime to a game engine in one section, why omit them?

It is proposed to expand the "Tools" section with [APT](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/), [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/), [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/), [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) and [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=package%20managers) (not necessarily all of them, but at least some).

Comment: +1 for pkg managers. But I think it's better to not lump it with "Tools" like Docker. Maybe better as its own list, or as a sub-list from each programming language? For Python for example, the list would be specific pipenv, anaconda, poetry, etc. Though I don't know if that works for each language on the list.

Comment: @GinoMempin - I'd go for a separate list, but it doesn't seem like SE asks for feedback on the structure of the survey itself, only what items to include. :( Frankly, I don't even understand the comparison of Docker to Node.js to Unity - they have their own fields of use that don't intersect much.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe

## Android and iOS

should be added as primary operating systems.

I'm not going crazy. These days many programming related apps have popped up for these platforms. They are mostly used by ones who have their proper computers for repair ***but are used by quite a few people as primary operating systems*** like me. I only stopped using those a couple of months ago. There surely are people using those platforms right now.

They can even be preferred choice for ***small*** projects which are going to run natively for those platforms as no virtual environment set ups and heavy IDE(Android Studio, that's you) won't need setting up.

Note I said for "small" projects.

Comment: This is a really good point. There are a lot of people who develop with Termux (obviously not for enterprise).

Comment: I second this. (Even Apple's TvOS and WatchOS)

Comment: @0-1 Are we really going to code in our televisions and watches? That's just outright weird although that's possible.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam I code for [TvOS](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/). And [WatchOS](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/) is the reason [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/) exists. Oh wait never mind, I was mistaken. You are correct.

Comment: I think that is should be made explicit that these platforms are operating systems to develop on, not platforms that are targets.

Answer (score 8):

Cloud Platforms:

## [Cloudflare](https://workers.cloudflare.com/)

Comment: Cloudflare isn't really a platform so much as a tool/service that is used to prevent DDOS/overload issues.

Comment: @TylerH: It's traditionally been a CDN, but it now is a cloud platform too.  Click through the link to learn more.  See especially Cloudflare Workers and Cloudflare Pages.  Cloudflare absolutely has a cloud platform solution now.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen many recent questions regarding the **Microsoft batch** scripting language, with [batch] corresponding tag. I suggest you to include it in `Bash/Shell/PowerShell` as `Bash/Shell/PowerShell/Batch`

Answer (score 8):

Under Development environments:

[**Google Apps Script**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Google's server-side JavaScript-based rapid development platform. It became very popular lately, so it makes sense to include it in the list. Take a look at the results of a question activity [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261578/trend-of-questions-tagged-with-tag?tag=google-apps-script&offset=5&metric=year#graph) (counting *only* positively received questions):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Maybe add Spyder to the list of Development Environments?

[Here's some more info on the IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_(software)).

Answer (score 7):

## [Neovim](https://neovim.io/)

Under development environments, either as its own option or combined with vim.

Answer (score 7):

## [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/)

under **Programming, scripting and markup language**.

Answer (score 7):

## [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)

Under web frameworks

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if makes sense to separate **Dotty** (Scala 3) from Scala and **Raku** (Perl 6) from Perl? They seem different enough.

Comment: Since Dotty has now been renamed Scala 3, I don't think it should be considered a separate language. It's like Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @user I think the differences are much larger than between Python 2 and 3, but even for Python I'd be curious how many people are still using Python 2. Similarly, Angular and Angular.js got two different entries in the frameworks list. I don't necessary want to consider them separate languages, but I think that the used version is relevant as well.

Comment: I think the Raku separation should be implemented.

Comment: Raku should be added as separate language.

Answer (score 6):

## [Neo4J](https://neo4j.com/)

Under **Database environments**.

Answer (score 5):

## Groovy

The list of programming languages should perhaps include groovy.

Answer (score 5):

Also add those under Tools:

[Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) / Yarn is a package manager that doubles down as project manager. Whether you work on one-shot projects or large monorepos, as a hobbyist or an enterprise user, we've got you covered.

[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) / Build amazing things (Which mentioned in comments);

Answer (score 5):

## CUDA

Nvidia's language for GPU computing.

Comment: Under which category? CUDA is API. If this is included why not OpenMP, MPI, or OpenGL and GDI?

Comment: @LazarĐorđević I am confused, I am in no way saying that any of those should not be included? But I see your point. The main reason to suggest it is because CUDA and CUDA-using APIs/frameworks have exploded in the recent years. There are a handful of those that directly (not indirectly, like "python") use CUDA in the original post.

Comment: Yes, it will be interesting if there is section like Parallel APIs - languages, to see how many people are using them. But there is only category for Web frameworks, and there is no huge interest on SO for languages like Chapel.

Answer (score 5):

## [OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/)

under **Other framework/libraries**.

Answer (score 5):

## [Dancer](https://www.perldancer.org/)

Under web frameworks

Answer (score 4):

Add

## **Pulumi**

under tools.
That is an alternative to Terraform

https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi

Answer (score 4):

## Winapi/MFC/ATL

Windows application programmers/maintainers will be using this.

Answer (score 4):

## [Kusto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/)

under databases

Comment: @Sinatr I separated the XAML suggestion from the Kusto suggestion per the question requirements. See my updated [XAML](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407403/5587356) answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Gitpod

I wonder how [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/) has arrived in the community.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't mind seeing

### **Industry Specific**

as an option for pretty much all of these categories.

eg if you work in healthcare, there's a high probability you use MUMPS or a variant. Erlang is similarly an industry-specific language (mostly by telecom). Both are also used in some finance capacity but primarily are used in their domains.

This is meant as a corollary with "Proprietary Internal Tool" (Mark Harrison's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407261/11573842)).

Answer (score 4):

## [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm) and [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm)

It might be interesting to see the intersection between full time Salesforce developers, part time Salesforce developers, and other tools and languages they use along with these languages.

Answer (score 4):

### Tcl/Tk

There is still some questions under the [tcl] and the [tk] tag from time to time. It might be a desirable addition under *Programming, scripting, and markup language*.

Answer (score 4):

Programming, scripting, and markup language:

## [Elm](http://elm-lang.org) ([elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elm))

> A delightful language for reliable web applications.

Elm is a purely functional, strongly statically typed language compiling to JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

LLVM, under Tools.

It is used for compiler design.

Comment: Wouldn't LLVM fit better under the Tools section, unless you are talking about LLVM IR.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider adding

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org)

under programming languages.  They had their v1.0 release earlier this year.  Ruby-inspired syntax and C-like speed.

Answer (score 3):

Add **[Flow](https://flow.org/en/)** to the list of "Tools".

As much as I love TypeScript, it is not a reason to exclude other type checking tools from the survey.

Comment: It's ok. I had a hard time finding what I was looking for. Thought that this would help others. Got the idea from Code Golfing site.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk - that's just a personal preference, I actually find your idea quite nice :)

Answer (score 3):

[Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)

An intuitive Git-based workflow and powerful serverless platform to build, deploy, and collaborate on web apps.

under Cloud Platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Programming language:

## Haxe

Primarily because it's one of very few true write-once-run-everywhere languages (including all major desktop and mobile targets). Yes it acts as a tanspiler, but it's a "real" / "complete" language because: a) it's a true compiler for some targets such as JVM bytecode b) it's standard library provides single code base access to all target platforms, c) when it is used to transpile it's single source to multiple output

There are several large, well known companies which use it as part of their stack: https://haxe.org/use-cases/who-uses-haxe.html

Answer (score 3):

Other frameworks:

## ML.NET

It's a complete machine learning framework, and one of the only ones built for .NET. It's relatively new, but is created by Microsoft - it seems likely to gain popularity over time, and it would be interesting to track that. Besides basic model building, training, and deployment/consumption, it's also got a simple user-friendly GUI (ML.NET Model Builder, a Visual Studio extension) and AutoML tech.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/ml-dotnet/what-is-mldotnet

Answer (score 2):

## **Solidity**

under Programming, scripting, and markup languages
That is an object-oriented programming language for writing smart contracts on various blockchain platforms.

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity

Answer (score 2):

## [Hbase](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html)

under the **Database environments**.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scheme](https://www.scheme.com/tspl4/)

under **Programming, scripting and markup language**.

Answer (score 2):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/)

under **Programming, scripting and markup language**.

Answer (score 2):

## [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)

Under development environments

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib, under tools.

It is a Python library for plotting graphs.

Answer (score 2):

SystemC, for modeling embedded systems, under programming, scripting, and markup languages

Answer (score 2):

I think the database market has seen a ton of advancements and it would be great to understand how this market is shifting at least with regards to categories (despite of course the established players that of course continue to be used a lot; the overall DBMS market has grown significantly, despite it being such an established market, in the last 2 years, so there is room for more), e.g.

- a time-series DB (at least one, better 2, e.g. Influx)
- a graph database (at least one, better 2, e.g. neo4j) and
- a distributed/NewSQL database (e.g. Cockroach)

Also, MariaDB has gained a ton of traction

But maybe some of these will show up under Other: ___________ ? - and one can find out more by downloading the data sets (if you will share that again)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess

## **scikitlearn**

is now really *that* forgotten as a machine learning framework now? Or is there something I'm missing on why it's not here? (Please enlighten me)

It's super easy to learn and has consistent API so usually beginners use scikitlearn to fast-track their Python machine learning understanding.

Answer (score 0):

## XAML

under programming, scripting, and markup languages

[XAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is a markup language based on XML and developed by Microsoft.

Answer (score -4):

Programming, scripting, and markup language:

## [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/)

Comment: [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) alone is just a meta-format, like json or ini-files. It does NOT describe anything apart from structure of document. No operands, barely only `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line, opening/closing tags, attributes, namespace syntax, done. One can learn the whole XML in 5 minutes. Unless you start adding on top of it some technologies which are using xml as a host.

Comment: If `XML` were to be listed, we'd also need `JSON`. But imo we shouldn't, it's just a human-readable data format, like `CSV`. We don't want to list things like `Protobuf`, `Markdown` or `TXT` either.

Comment: The category is *Programming, scripting, and **markup language***.  To omit e**X**tendable **M**arkup **L**anguage, (1) a successful W3C Standard, (2) the centerpiece for an ecosystem consisting of XSLT, XPath, XSD, etc, and (3)  an extremely active [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) here on Stack Overflow, would be a gross oversight.

Comment: @Sinatr Sadly, if you could learn the whole of XML in 5 minutes, we wouldn't have to spend so much time answering questions from people who failed to realise that you can't.

Comment: I agree with @kjhughes. If the category description includes markup languages, then you have to include XML. If you want to restrict it to programming and scripting languages, then (a) change the category description, and (b) include XSLT, which has a similar number of questions to many of the languages on your list.

Answer (score -4):

## [UML](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML)

under **Programming, scripting and markup language**.

Answer (score -4):

## [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor)

Under Web frameworks/libraries

Comment: I believe they've stopped taking feedback for the languages, as the [2021 Developer Survey is live](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407914/take-the-2021-developer-survey?cb=1).

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But can anybody explain why all the down votes?

Comment: Likely because your answer is now outdated and not needed because feedback is not being taken any more.

Answer (score -5):

There's no section for the compilers, is this expected?

Answer (score -5):

What about

## JSF (JavaServer Faces)

Comment: Mind to add description and thoughts why you think it should be added? Never heard/used JSF.

Comment: JSF is a popular framework to develop web frontends with Java. Many company websites use JSF.

Comment: Is it just UI technology/library? I've [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407352/1997232) adding WPF myself. Is JSF popular? I would say it is: [35.000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf) vs [160.000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf).

Comment: if Java Server Faces is included, why not Struts ?

Answer (score -9):

## **BigchainDB**

under Databases
The Blockchain Database.

https://github.com/bigchaindb

Answer (score -9):

## Developing For Target Platform

It would be great to know what are the platforms that developers are targeting with their work. Options may include:

1. Web front-end
2. Back-end - Linux-based
3. Back-end - Windows-based
4. Mobile - iOS
5. Mobile - Android
6. Desktop - Windows
7. Desktop - MacOS

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which was asking about items lacking in the given lists, not what other questions we would like to see asked. (Although they totally should ask for feedback on those as well!)