# How to participate in the Stack Overflow survey

Tags: support, survey

**How** do I participate in the Stack Overflow survey?

I'm new to Stack Overflow and have heard there is a survey conducted annually.

I've searched in the 'Help Center and other resources' and in general searched on Stack Overflow and tried several search combinations in a search engine.

[When will the annual Developer Survey be released?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359679/when-will-the-annual-developer-survey-be-released)

Unfortunately, this question, although helpful and seems to be asking the same, does not have answers that explain how to join the next survey or any surveys that may come in the future.

Unless new links are going to be added to the post each time a new survey opens?

I'd love to take part, but I am not sure when or how to do so.

Comment: The survey hasn't happened yet this year. If you check the [[meta-tag:survey]] tag, you'll note that feedback for what languages to include in this year's survey was asked for only *yesterday*.

Comment: "How do I participate in the Stack Overflow survey?" - you wait for it to start, at which point, it'll be painfully obvious that it has started. There's usually a blog post, banner, and IIRC, an email for registered users

Comment: "Are newer accounts blocked from taking part?" - no. In fact, you don't need an account to answer at all.

Comment: That this question has been closed sums up everything about the StackOverflow mindset. Thanks to Zoe for adding an answer in the comments!