# Why not - subscription / job ads - option for users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising

Stack Overflow works great.

But I believe that not everyone is interested in your job adverts!

Could you please allow a subscription model (along with the job ads model) and allow a user to pay for Stack Overflow, if he/she wants to get rid of those job ads for the duration of the subscription?

Comment: related? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285062/where-is-the-option-to-remove-looking-for-a-job/285227#285227

Answer (score 6):

Please be a little more patient. Once you reach 200 reputation, you will see a [reduced number of advertisements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads). You cannot pay for reputation points / privileges, but 200 reputation isn't that much away from where you are now.

Comment: What if I dont want any ads ...

Comment: @vjjj contribute more - I honestly can't remember the last time I've seen an ad on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is, if you don't count the spam posts ...

Comment: @Glorfindel There's one ad in the sidebar of the question list.  It's just not invasive.

Comment: @Servy right, I see now. Says something about how often I visit the question list ...

Comment: @vjjj it does not matter if you 'don't want ads' - you have to earn the privilege to have them removed.

Comment: Just to note - you can't opt out of job ads in the sidebar but at 200 rep the inline ads between Q&A is removed. Interestingly (surprisingly?) someone made a feature request as they missed those - so there's an option in your profile settings to re-enable them.

Comment: @vjjj Is your conscience stopping you from using adblock? In that case, get to 200 rep, you'll stop seing most of them.

Comment: @Magisch - adblock does not change job adverts on the right side of ques

Answer (score 2):

> allow a user to pay for Stack Overflow

I think this could be a bad idea. The bulk of the site's content comes from people volunteering their time. If users start paying to use the site, people will likely:

1. Want to be paid for time spent answering questions
2. Feel (even more) entitled to getting their question answered
3. Assume this is the first step toward requiring people to pay to see the site

It won't matter that the subscription is just to remove ads or that the only thing changing is the source of the income. Combine that with the effort it would take to implement and it's a lot of pain just to fix something that isn't broken.