# Is there a flag review problem, or is it just me?

Tags: discussion

Let's have look at my flag history:

[image: flags history]

1. [Bukkit plugin doesn't work (Spigot API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875327/bukkit-plugin-doesnt-work-spigot-api/32652324#32652324)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530238/creating-a-group-chat-using-java-servlet
3. [Why does NaN - NaN == 0.0 with the Intel C++ Compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195949/why-does-nan-nan-0-0-with-the-intel-c-compiler/32234946#32234946)
4. [Error: "The node to be inserted is from a different document context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019136/error-the-node-to-be-inserted-is-from-a-different-document-context/12405888#12405888)
5. [jquery validation add inputs required dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340021/jquery-validation-add-inputs-required-dynamically/24968540#24968540)
6. [I want to delete a video from my channel on Youtube using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712305/i-want-to-delete-a-video-from-my-channel-on-youtube-using-the-api/9882065#9882065)

The last 6 flags I've raised have been declined. The 3rd through 5th I had to resort to moderator flags to actually get obvious crap to be fixed/removed. It seems I'm going to have to do the same thing with my latest 2 flags, as well as maybe the 6th (which has already been declined by a moderator).

Now, this isn't a deterrent for me - I **will** continue to flag junk until it gets fixed - but surely there are others who will become discouraged when their valid flags are repeatedly declined by robo-reviewers and mods. And of course, having to re-flag things wastes my time; having to escalate to mods when the review queues should handle it, wastes their time.

My main concern is that flags are apparently increasingly being judged by their **content**, not their **context**. Is this something that anyone else has experienced, or am I just being a grumpy old man (again)?

Comment: You've fallen in the "not an answer" trap like many of us. If it looks like an answer (of whatever quality) to _a_ (not necessarily _the_) question, you may not flag it as "not an answer". So yeah, content, not context.

Comment: On "Creating a group chat using a java servlet" did you flag the comment for a moderator to edit the question? Better to just edit the question yourself, then flag the comment as obsolete.

Comment: See also: [Your answer is in another castle.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and [When to flag an answer as not an answer.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/5240004)

Comment: As for whether there's a larger problem, in the last 30 days moderators handled ~26000 flags, with community review processing an additional ~36000. For flags on answers, [97% are marked as helpful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling/251176#251176). Regular users active on Meta only see the complaints, which can make it look like there's a problem. In reality, arguments over flags tend to be fairly rare in the context of the volume handled by the community and moderators.

Answer (score 12):

Flags have, for the most part, always been judged by their content largely absent of context. It's unfortunate, but with the extremely high volume of flags being processed each day it's simply too time-consuming to be evaluating every flag by context.

This is why we advise using the stock flags, NAA and VLQ, only for egregious cases that don't require any sort of context. Where just one look at the answer **anywhere** and we know it's so bad it needs to just go away.

And, trust us, we really don't mind custom flags for non-obvious cases. Because we hate robo-reviewers as much as you do. For example, you're in a much better position than the mods to evaluate whether a code dump is at all relevant to the question at hand. All you have to do is tell us.

While I'm here, I'll just post my thoughts on each of the posts you've listed:

1. While really poorly written, it's not nearly bad enough to qualify as VLQ. In particular, it's not as bad as #5, which doesn't even contain a coherent sentence structure. This one just lacks some proofreading, but it doesn't take a herculean effort to figure out what the user is saying. Of course, whether anyone wants to try and improve the answer on the answerer's behalf is another story.
2. <del>This I can agree; I have no idea why on earth that comment flag was declined.</del> OK I'm guessing it was declined because the text implies that it should be a mod editing the question. I can see a mod declining it expecting you to do the editing instead, and then flagging the comment as simply "obsolete".

   Either way, it's pretty obviously a code dump in a comment and that is one of the absolute worst kinds of comment. I've deleted the comment now.
3. :/ (I was neither involved in the initial rejection nor the later approval of this flag.)
4. This NAA flag was disputed through the review process. Moderators do not dispute NAA flags; we either mark them helpful or declined, if they do survive the review process and wind up in the mod queue. Raising a custom moderator flag is the ideal course of action here, as a simple NAA flag simply doesn't convey the necessary context to reviewers.
5. I remember handling this flag. I hope my response offered some insight as to why your previous flags *could have* been declined, though I cannot speak with certainty for the other mods' decisions. I personally probably would have approved a VLQ flag on this for its sheer incoherence alone.
6. ... I have no idea what to make of this answer. The only text it contains is "I have the following", which makes it sound like a question without a problem statement. But it could also be a really poor way of expressing "Here's how I do it". It's hard to tell. (Based on this, should it qualify as VLQ then? Probably a topic for another day.)