# How to reverse a duplicate question when the second is a clearer duplicate target than an older question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Last week I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51971666/2291321) that then cropped up again as a duplicate today.

The [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52048407/2291321) is a clear duplicate of the first but the question in the second is a better duplicate target as it more correctly covers the root cause instead of confusing it slightly with a tighter scope (around Fluent Bit configuration).

As the first question hadn't accepted or upvoted the posted answer despite solving the problem and with the second question being a clearer duplicate target I figured the best idea was to copy the answer into the second question, comment that I intended to flip the duplicate and then once that had been done delete the answer on the first question.

Unfortunately the second question's answer was deleted (presumably flagged by the system as an exact duplicate) without the comment on the answer being read.

Is there a a better approach to this that I should have thought of instead?

Comment: Isn't it possible to improve the answered question to a state where it is better?

Comment: Since the OP clearly indicated the problem was solved and he wanted to upvote, I've upvoted on his behalf, and cast the first dupe vote.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth as far as I can understand OP wants the dupe the other way around. Hence OP should delete answer on the first one, then post answer on the second one (or better flag for mod undeletion of already existing answer). Wait for accept or upvotes, then the first one can be closed as dupe of second. I will post an answer to explain this

Comment: @PetterFriberg I've retracted the dupe vote, the OP on that second question is disputing the dupe (and I'm not a subject expert, but it sounds to me like he might be right). That would also prohibit this from being a merge/modflag candidate.

Comment: @gnat Not sure, the questions involved are not duplicated (as question was posted), it's more a question about user have posted an answer on one question and OP wants to move it to the other so first question *can* be closed as duplicate as second. (but mod deleted answer since duplicate answer). We would need as duplicate a question asking how you move your answer from on question to the other

Comment: I can't understand your formulations. Which question do you intend to leave open with an answer and which to close as a duplicate? You make it sound as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048407/how-to-have-a-literal-string-of-something-in-a-template-data-file should be left open and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971666/creating-filebeat-configuration-with-terraform closed but I see exactly the opposite happening right now.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev check this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048407/how-to-have-a-literal-string-of-something-in-a-template-data-file#comment91058811_52054288 on deleted answer and you will understand.

Comment: @PetterFriberg that's what I feared, a mod ignored that comment completely. Unless someone else catches the idea, we're at an impasse here since it's impossible to vote to close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971666/creating-filebeat-configuration-with-terraform as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52048407/how-to-have-a-literal-string-of-something-in-a-template-data-file as long as the answer is deleted.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev the mod had to delete, since duplicated answer, they can't act on single comment. OP need to delete the other answer, then that answer can be undelete and the community can close as duplicate (this is not mod business, mod should handle flags, not go around closing dupes). See my answer for more information how we (the community) can make this flow easily.

Answer (score 2):

There are not many options here, you need to delete the answer on the first one, then flag your answer that has been deleted on the target one with custom mod flag.

> Please undelete this answer, since this is a better duplicate target and I have delete my other duplicate answer on this question [Creating Filebeat configuration with Terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51971666/5292302). See also meta [How to reverse a duplicate question when the second is a clearer duplicate target than an older question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373279/how-to-reverse-a-duplicate-question-when-the-second-is-a-clearer-duplicate-targe)

As mods arrive they will undelete (since you deleted the other), now you have inverted the question that you have answered and will simple need to wait for upvotes or accept on the new answer.

Once you have upvotes and/or accept you can suggest to close the original one as duplicate of the new one and then hope that other 4 reviewers (or 1 gold badge holder) agree with you.

---

This is some reference to why your second answer was deleted by a moderator

[Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)

Answer (score -1):

I tried this before, to no avail.

- Mods decline a flag to "reverse-duplicate" as "not their job".
- Reopening and reclosing via review also proved unsuccessful due to reviewers refusing to support the procedure. I can only guess why; my best guess is they only judge the question on its own merits and look no further, or not support the idea of a "two-stage review" as too complicated and/or fragile. See [Questions wrongly closed as a duplicate but still bad end up as an incorrect duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337760/questions-wrongly-closed-as-a-duplicate-but-still-bad-end-up-as-an-incorrect-dup) for a similar situation.

As such, the best idea I currently have is to create a meta Q&A each time.
If the community supports the specific action, raise a mod flag to carry it out with a reference to the Q&A, or retag it to [support](/questions/tagged/support) (and sit around waiting for some mod to look at it, [had a negative experience with this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/362319/revisions#rev70fe2fb2-f12c-427e-9d84-b2852452cc1f)), or create a separate [support](/questions/tagged/support) request referencing the Q&A.