# Allow dismissing the "Flagging is a way to ..." text on the flag summary page

Tags: feature-request, flags

Recently a block of text was added at the top of the flag summary page:

> Flagging is a way to bring inappropriate content or behavior to the attention of the community. See: What is flagging?
>   These are the flags that you have raised, along with their current status. You can filter this list using the links in the sidebar.

Please allow dismissing this text, it clutters the page.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SE: [Allow me to hide the “what are flags?” banner please!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323055/289905).

Comment: @Xufox thanks, I googled on "Flagging is a way" and that post didn't come up.

Comment: Yes, I just remembered seeing this request already and tried different searches. I ultimately found it by [searching _Flagging dismiss_ and sorting by _Newest_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=Flagging%20dismiss).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Flagging is one of those activities that kinda grew up with the rest of Stack Overflow:

- First there was just an "offensive" flag (later changed to "inappropriate", then back to "offensive" again). The number of pending offensive flags [was visible to anyone with 2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18557/23), and triggered deletion at some (fairly high) threshold. It was more of a parallel voting system than anything like the flags we have today, though you may recognize some aspects of the current spam/abusive flag behavior.
- [Then there were three](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/11/raising-a-red-flag/) types of flags: spam and offensive as separate options, "Inform Moderator" as a new free-form catch-all. Now you could flag *all sorts of things* and get a moderator to look at them - [or a 10k user](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/06/new-10k-rep-tools-now-available/).
- Then there were [comment flags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/16/comments-now-with-flags-and-votes/). Apparently Jeff wasn't happy with some of us ruthlessly deleting all the comments on our posts...
- Then there were many: [a kinder, gentler moderator flag dialog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/14/improved-flagging/) launched with the goal of getting folks to flag a *lot* more stuff. This was successful - [terribly, terribly successful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling).
- ...Then there were more. More close reasons, more flag reasons, changes to names and descriptions, review queues, hell-bans, soft-bans, warnings, an explosion of different "result statuses"... All added to try to balance the need for flagging with the weight it imposed on moderators and reviewers.

Have you kept up with all of this? Good for you! I'd guess most folks haven't though. And then there are folks who've never flagged before, and may never flag again: 60% of the folks who raised a flag for the first time in 2018 have still raised only one flag *ever*.

Let's face it: after ten years, a bunch of help-center articles and meta FAQs ain't gonna cut it; we gotta put more of this information *in the UI itself*. Hence the little blurb explaining what you're looking at, with links to more extensive information where possible.

Depending on the width of your screen, it takes up about as much space as one flag - maybe a little less, maybe a little more. If you have enough flags for this to matter, you're gonna be scrolling anyway. If you don't, then you stand to benefit from having the explanation.

I'd prefer to keep the experience as consistent as possible, but if you absolutely must be rid of it then [a user script or style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323055/allow-me-to-hide-the-what-are-flags-banner-please/323062#323062) or any competent ad-blocker should rid you of it fairly easily.

Comment: I guess it especially bothers me because it's not the first hand-holding feature on the network. Let's see if Samuel Liew is OK with adding it to his [Reduce Clutter user script](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js)

Comment: I would like to add *a lot more* of them, @stijn: if the system doesn't provide this guidance, then it's on us - you, me, the moderators. This flag guidance came out of a series of discussions with frustrated moderators who were spending serious time explaining this stuff to folks who you might have expected to know it already... That's time lost all around that shouldn't have to be.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem with hand-holding features, @Stijn? Just-in-time help is a critical component of all user interfaces. Sure, *you* might not need this information, but far more people do than don't, and it's hard to see how its being there is really hurting you.

Comment: @CodyGray there's nothing wrong with hand-holding features in general. I just don't like hand-holding features that cannot be easily disabled, because they only clutter the interface by giving me information I already know.

Comment: @Stijn considering that it's only a one-liner message and only appears on that specific page, I don't see it necessary to add the removal to the userscript

Comment: @SamuelLiew that's fine, I'll make my own.

Comment: Yup, it's good to see some of these (recent) UX improvements!

Comment: Oh yeah, great for those people who are actually able to install user-scripts or at least extensions in their work PC browsers, any option for the rest of us who can't?

Comment: "60% of the folks who raised a flag for the first time in 2018 have still raised only one flag ever." Wow. What is that number in absolute terms (if you don't mind sharing)?