# How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?

Tags: discussion, moderation, chatgpt

Following up from the bustling discussion as a consequence of the [temporary ChatGPT ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831), I guess the [big gaping question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421835) is how can one determine if an answer used ChatGPT?

As an example, @AKX [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned#comment936792_421835) that there are some tells: answers that start with "**It looks like the issue...**", or "**To fix this...**", or those that ends with "**I hope this helps**" are heuristics.

But we can't confirm that the answer is indeed AI generated, as many legit SO users can and do begin their answers like this.

Another [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421835#comment937224_421835) by @drewcassidy is that we can use an output detector like https://huggingface.co/openai-detector/ - using the model against itself -  to determine if the answer is real or fake.

Comment: In addition these phrases are pretty common in use, it's not like these are strong indicators. You might supposed to make an account and check it. No seriously, don't have a clue how this rule is supposed to be enforced.

Comment: You should flag for moderator attention, providing your evidence.

Comment: @snakecharmerb your skipping the point of the whole question. How do we gather evidence in the first place? Or should we just flag every answer that does not look human ?

Comment: I don't really think you can do it based on rules, it'll involve human intuition. Judge the overall style of the post. No spelling mistakes will probably be a big tell :)

Comment: Do we actually need a 100% reliable discriminator? If a user *manually* posts content indistinguishable from a mindless bot without subject matter expertise, misidentifying them as doing it with less effort doesn't seem that harmful.

Comment: I answered your final question no;-)?  More seriously, I think there are some indications from an individual answer, and there may be some patterns in user behaviour.  But perhaps it's like spam, we shouldn't be telling the bad guys how we can spot them.

Comment: @snakecharmerb its hard to keep that a secret since "the bad guys" and "the not bad guys" are exactly the same audience.

Comment: You can usually tell from a user's history on the site whether they are likely to have produced an AI-like answer by themselves.

Comment: I also use the users history as a indicator. A new user posting 5 answers with just a little more than 3 minutes inbetween is a good hint. If you then find an answer that contradicts itself (last example: your problem is that the object is not extendable, solution: use object.Freeze to make the object not extendable), then you have a very good idea of what is happening.

Comment: i found one a couple of days ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522646/copy-a-variation-regular-price-from-an-old-variation-and-add-it-to-all-other-new/74606713#comment131807881_74606713 how are we supposed to deal with these flag the question so a moderator can see it i just put the comment because i did not know what to do with it

Comment: @Barkermn01 lol i love that the user is called `GPT-3` 

Comment: *"we can't confirm that the answer is indeed AI generated, as many legit SO users can and do begin their answers like this"*. Then we should ban the use of those phrases for legit users :P

Comment: Use a ["In need of moderator intervention"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgXro.png) flag, @Barkermn01 (note, I did not submit that flag, as it looks like they've already been handled, at least partially)

Comment: If it was tested and solved your problem, do you care? Isn't that the spirit of StackOverflow? Sometimes we get it from documentations, books, peers or just test/error

Comment: @Sgdva If you can’t tell whether it was tested and actually solves the problem, do you care?

Comment: “Also, which flag should we use if we suspect an answer is ChatGPT generated?” - Just going with a downvote myself. If any user who uses CGPT to post answers has a problem with that plan, they can simply, NOT use CGPT. CGPT is easily detected.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you don't accept the answer and if it goes way out of scope you downvote it, like if we didn't see that before on S.O. Some humans just google it as well, or more ironically, just tweak another answers in the site: should we ban google/SO search engines?

Comment: @Sgdva, IMO if we allow these bot's at all they will start spamming the site, how long is it till some one makes a bot that starts asking questions it can't find and bots answering it, that's a recipe for destroying the site.

Comment: This is it, AI has taken over. I think using the same model to detect those answers is the only way to move forward, but these detection models will be used to train the model even further. And since the model is trained on us, the humans, there will be a day when even your and mine speech will be positive in the detection system ...

Comment: @Barkermn01 It's the same argument "if we allow people to google, how are we going to make sure their facts are right?" crude answer, we don't: we need to be analytical. Going a little off topic: if you want to think that drinking chlorine will cure you from COVID because you googled it or a pseudo doctor told you so (I know for a fact people with credentials suggested to do so), it's the same as thinking that the bot will replace your work. These are tools, users are the ones to be held responsable, we cannot forbid knives just because you can kill people with them.

Comment: @Thingamabobs: Being a native speaker is not a guarantee. They still need to actively learn to write. [52% of Americans falls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxMsgVgeu_M&t=5m48s) **** ***below*** **** literacy level 3. *"Level 3 is considered a suitable minimum for coping with the demands of everyday life in a complex advanced society."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Got you, in the EU we evaluate the level with A1 to C2. However thinking about my fellow (ab-)user of my native language I can see where you are coming from. :D It might be indeed a good indicator for people that are already able to evaluate these levels.

Comment: @Sgdva Lots of things that can be automated are banned from being automated in the real world, case and point planes, in theory, can fly themselves guess what they still have to have pilots & co-pilots in case, Allowing bots to run buck soft on this site, will significantly increase the cost for Stack Exchange, overwork moderation, and will make it difficult for more people to find meaningful answers, an answer should not be Copy and Paste Code only if you expect that you're using the site wrong. they are supposed to explain so you can learn that is why code-only answers are discouraged

Comment: @Barkermn01 Yeah they're banned because they can't reach the 100% and we can't afford the cost to test, in your example, if the automatic system fails, human lives will be lost; in the other way around, gl bulding a cpu without automation: let's not mix apples with oranges. This is only a tool, the bot itself doesn't post, people that think that we shouldn't use tools to ease our work shouldn't be at software, it's shooting ourselves in the foot (IE: I don't trust your python script because I don't know it, therefore I won't use it no matter how much you explain it because it has limitations)

Comment: @Sgdva YET!, it takes a Javascript Dev 10, 15 mins to make a bot that uses a headless browser to start auto-posting, and maybe another 30 mins to build a data store of URLs it's already scanned and answered, my point was not "we should never allow automation in society" it was that automation in this capacity when the bot is not actually testing the code they are giving if we permit it, it won't be long till we get 100% automated systems doing it, and the human answers and point stop working we then lose moderators and site is useless then.

Comment: @Barkermn01 Then that user should be banned, eventually he'll get tired of it if the point is getting rep, yet he's getting banned in his/er accounts and the problem is not GPDT is selenium, should we ban it? Anyways, I think we are going circles here, I'm going to summarize my opinion: I agree that automations should be handled carefully and agree to an extent that the tool isn't the best approach to all scenarios, I completly disagree on saying it's useless and should be banned and not looking a way to get a benefit out of it, as a tool, depends on who uses it.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you want to ask about what flag to use, ask that in a separate post on meta.

Comment: The problem you are not considering is that if ChatGPT is used to provide a reasonable/valid/accurate answer, deleting it because it *looks like* junk answers damages the site.

Comment: @Sklivvz gnerally, ChatGPT answers do not look like junk, they look like great answers *despite* the fact that they *are* junk. *not* deleting them damages the site.

Comment: @KevinB I know, but the content is sometimes "semantically" junk, this is what I meant by junk answers.

Comment: In a fit of irony, I posted this question into ChatGPT and it returned an "internal server error"

Comment: I hope the solution is not that we try to start writing really bad English and cross our fingers that AI's down come down to our level.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "...misidentifying them as doing it with less effort doesn't seem that harmful...." Problem is that using ChatGPT is forbidden and accounts get banned. Just being not very clever and posting useless answers is not forbidden and so far didn't get you banned (or not as quickly). User accounts could simply always claim they were mistargeted and just unlucky with their answers.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the premise behind the indiscriminate block of computer-generated code. Often subject matter experts answer questions. I can see a subject matter expert use ChatGPT to generate code, save time, and verify the code is accurate and useful.  This does not make the answer any less valid. And we vote on the quality of the answer so it seems the SO facility will still work just fine rather hand written, copied, or computer generated.

Comment: @Yepher "I can see a subject matter expert ..." I can see that too but much more often I see people just posting raw output from these bots without checking anything. This positive usage will probably remain an exception.

Comment: This may be of interest: https://www.npr.org/2023/01/09/1147549845/gptzero-ai-chatgpt-edward-tian-plagiarism

Comment: Why does it matter if it's written by an AI if it answers the question? Isn't that the point of this site? To help others by answering question? Or it's some circlejerk for programmers to feel about useless internet upvotes?

Comment: @JohnFire because for now, due to how often they *don't* answer the question, it is banned. People are free to use it themselves, just not to try "helping" others by copy pasting it here. If people want to use chatgpt to get an answer, they can.

Comment: Ultimately, it will be a task for an AI to detect if a human or a AI or bot is typing answers.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The general question of how to detect these posts is something we've been avoiding publicly answering, because publicly describing how we detect ChatGPT generated content provides those people using ChatGPT with specific information which they could use to make it more difficult for us to detect ChatGPT generated content. So, while I/we understand your desire to know, this isn't something we're officially answering publicly at this time.

For moderators, there is a significant amount of information available about detection of these posts in the [Moderator Team](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/q/4873/635) and other locations mentioned in there. Moderators can also get information through the [Teachers' Lounge chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge).

Comment: So, the answer is flagged instantly, I mean will `OP` know in time not to use the answer?

Comment: At this time, there can be significant delay between flagging and a moderator taking a look at it. While we're trying to stay on top of these, there are literally thousands of such posts, and that's over and above all the other stuff we normally handle. We all are, of course, volunteers, so how long it will take to get to each flag is indeterminate. So, overall, the answer to your question is that it's likely the OP, who gets directly notified of any new answer (and who is often specifically watching for answers to their question), will see the answer prior to a mod looking at it.

Comment: Well, modGPT turns out to be a dead end... (pasted from chatgpt) "It is not possible for me to determine whether a given programming solution was produced by me or not. This is because chatgpt is a large language model trained by....", etc.

Comment: "...there is a significant amount of information available about detection of these posts..." Is there? Without details it's difficult to judge how high the success rate of detection really is. Could be anything really.

Comment: @Trilarion The "success rate"  of detection is something that is really only possible to *guess at* in aggregate. In order to *know* the success rate, you'd have to identify everything that was posted that originated from ChatGPT, even the things which were *not* detected as such, which is, obviously, not really possible, if for no other reason than it's, at best, difficult to prove that you've found *everything*. But, yes, members of the public not being able to make such judgements about the efficacy of detection is one of the trade-offs of not making all information public, at this time.

Comment: "yeah we can't really detect ChatGPT with any sort of accuracy but we don't want to admit it"

Comment: @ScottishTapWater Your statement is completely unjustified based on the available public and private information. It's just slinging mud around. If you take the time to identify a notable quantity of A) posts which are ChatGPT generated that *have not* been identified, and/or B) posts which have been identified as generated by ChatGPT, but were not actually generated by ChatGPT, *then* the first part of your statement might have *some* basis. Currently, it's *entirely* baseless. As to "but we don't want to admit it", that's just presuming motivation based on your own, erroneous, assumptions.

Comment: While there have been some of (B), it's a low number and those are typically reevaluated when the author indicates an objection, either by flagging their deleted post or responding to the moderator message. As to (A): of course detection methods are both imperfect and continuously improving. So, of course, there will be some ChatGPT generated posts which are not, yet, identified. So, if you can identify a significant quantity (proportional to the thousands of posts which have been identified as ChatGPT and deleted), then the first part of your statement might have some basis.

Comment: An interesting metric, which you could make public without revealing anything, would be how many answers written before ChatGPT (e.g. before 2021 to be sure) would get flagged as written by ChatGPT.

Comment: @JiK While there are semi-automated processes bringing some posts to our attention, actual flagging is done by humans and the choice to act is done by moderators (most of whom at least claim to be human :) ). Thus, to actually get such statistics would be to perform a double-blind study involving human flaggers and moderators. That would be quite time intensive, so is unlikely to be something that happens. An additional complication is that it would require using the people who are actually flagging and handling the flags, as the experience of the people makes a significant difference.

Comment: More details about how moderators determined if content was AI generated and a short discussion of false positives in [What has happened to lead moderators to consider striking?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424979/what-has-happened-to-lead-moderators-to-consider-striking?cb=1) by Machavity.

Answer (score 32):

I don't think there's going to be any value in having ***you***, a mere mortal, try to determine if an answer or question was generated by ChatGPT.

The reason is super, super simple:  **we don't want this to turn into a witch hunt.**

There are things you can do even today to help with curation of answers; if an answer is wrong or incomplete, you can downvote it.  If you *happen* to notice a trend of similarly bad answers from an account, you can flag for moderator attention with the series of answers you've got as evidence.

This shouldn't be a "those bad answers are more moderatable than others" situation - just vote on answers as you always would, and let the moderators deal with the heavier lifting on this circumstance.

Comment: Makoto makes a valuable point here that I think hasn't surfaced quite enough in discussions like this: witch hunts on the internet are far too common and (especially with anything that requires a subjective opinion) the results are very rarely correct.  I'm glad to see this come into the discussiion.

Comment: I second that, and also, we should focus on what the real issue is exactly, is it that we don't like the Idea of people abusing the system and using chatGPT to effortlessly answer questions and get upvotes or is it about the value and correctness of answers. And what if chatGPT is able to give valuable and useful answers that respects stackoverflow's guidelines what do you do about that? or is someone was to copy/paste an answer from another forum to SO, would that also be a problem ?

Comment: To be very clear about something: The massive effort and hours that the community curators/flaggers and elected moderators spent together over the last 6 months very successfully stemming the tide of the ChatGPT copy-paste flood and shielding _our community’s_ users from having to see all that junk never in any way shape or form came anywhere close to actually resembling anything like a _“witch hunt”_. We had been very accurately identifying the ChatGPT posts with an extremely low number of false positives. And I say that as someone who handled a very very large number of the flags.

Comment: Here are some personal numbers: Conservatively speaking, for the last 6 months (since the beginning of December 2022) every single day **I have been spending _40 minutes a day_ just on moderating ChatGPT flags**. I think that works out to 120 hours in total that I have personally spent on them so far. And in those hours week after week, I have looked at multiple thousands of ChatGPT-flagged posts: I think it must be on the order of 10000 or even 15000 at this point.

Comment: I do assert that in the many hours I have spent actually looking at the ChatGPT-flagged posts, and from the many thousands of those posts that I have actually closely and carefully scrutinized in detail, I have in fact learned to recognize the ChatGPT copy-paste cases (including many of the ones whose contest the posters had edited before pasting in, to intentionally obscure the provenance) and **I can in fact with a very high level of confidence and a very very low level of false positives effectively identify answers whose provenance is ChatGPT or other AI tools.**

Comment: To anyone who claims the elected moderators have been getting it wrong for the last 6 months, with an unacceptably high rate of false positives, and who wants to challenge my personal assertions about how accurately I can identify the ChatGPT cases: I invite you to work together with me over several days looking at least some several dozens of ChatGPT flags as they come in, and scrutinizing together the content of the flagged posts together, and actually honestly talking together in good faith about which posts we think we can agree are highly likely not the poster’s own original work.

Comment: Alternatively, rather than looking at new flags as they come in, I invite anyone who wants to challenge my personal assertions about how accurately I can identify the ChatGPT cases to go together through the logs of my moderation activities, and take some significantly-sized random sample at least of the thousands of ChatGPT flags I have handled, and scrutinizing together the content of the flagged posts together, and actually honestly talking together in good faith about which posts we think we can agree are highly likely not the poster’s own original work.

Comment: Until anybody who questions how well we have been handling the ChatGPT flags actually does something concrete like I have described in my other comments, waving vague suggestions about possible “witch hunts” under the noses of the elected moderators and community curators/flaggers is completely irresponsible at best — but in reality in combination with the other indirect accusations and aggressions that the key company reps driving the communication around this have slung at the elected moderators, it is completely unconscionable and completely unprincipled.

Comment: @sideshowbarker:  Don't think that this was written as a slight to the work of moderators or people who actually are taking the time to do this the right way.  This was mostly to stop people from brigading together, thinking that they were doing something constructive rather than not.  Rest assured, I value and appreciate all the things that the moderation team have done to this point to stop the excessive flood of ChatGPT-generated content to come on this site.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I understand, and I never thought otherwise of you personally. And to be very clear: My comments here weren’t directed at all to you. And I’ll also take the opportunity now to tell you: While I don’t follow the meta sites closely or read nearly as much of them as I should, I’m an avid follower of your meta postings. To cite just one example among many: At the time when I was trying to understand the Collectives feature, I read (and re-read) all your meta postings about it, and they were a huge help to me in making an evaluation of Collectives that I had needed to make at the time.

Answer (score 15):

> how can one determine if an answer used ChatGPT?

Answers by ChatGPT will likely have perfect grammar and punctuation (unless this bot learns to dumb itself down in that regard), a certain length maybe (3-4 paragraphs, typically no links nor code/emphasis formatting but a certain fondness for bullets/numbered lists) and most importantly be kind of useless, missing the point or stopping short of the solution. Unfortunately detecting that would require domain knowledge. Fortunately we have this knowledge but we have only limited time.

Therefore it seems apt to use AI in order to detect AI. Kind of what a [GAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) does. ChatGPT is the generator and what we would need to build would be a discriminator and then see where that leads us.

In the end, [nobody knows if you are a dog on the Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet%2C_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog). I could be one (or an AI).

The really crucial thing is being an expert. That is much harder to fake. People will realize at some point if I just sound well or if there is real substance behind my words. At least for those topics with definite answers like programming.

An important thing would also be to assess the accuracy (false positives/negatives) of such a detection. I guess if one takes all posts before December 2022 as negatives and all self created answers by ChatGPT as positives, it would be possible to estimate these error rates and judge how well that detection system can work. That's really important to know. See for example [Why was my answer deleted for using ChatGPT even when I didn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422066/why-was-my-answer-deleted-for-using-chatgpt-even-when-i-didnt) for what can happen if you start your answer with "Here's an example of how you could use.." among other things.

Finally, we could also include a [stricter trust model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421840/stricter-trust-model-in-the-face-of-bot-flood) to recognize experts in their fields. In the past, we mostly emphasized that the content should stand on its own, but exploiting the link of every answer to a user account could result in additional information about whom to trust and whom not to trust.

---

P.S.: As [Cerbrus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421832?noredirect=1#comment936895_421835) and [ConceptRat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned/421832?noredirect=1#comment938747_421835) mention in another question, a bit of help from OpenAI could make the detection much easier, i.e. if they would have an API that lets you check if a certain part of content was generated by them lately. That might alleviate the problem greatly (unless people start transforming the output before posting here).

---

P.S.2: As a corollary to the difficulty it seems to make to determine if some content was AI generated, it's now also difficult to determine if content was human generated. That's a bit sad, because for example, why bothering typing all that courtesies in emails yourself if the other side will probably just think that an AI created them. That seems to reduce the value of human generated content. That's really one of the major problems I have with AI right now (much more than the allegation of AI being cold and calculating, humans are that too quite often). I don't want to be seen simply as a provider of training material for an AI. But I'm digressing somewhat.

Comment: Many thanks to Peter Mortensen for providing context and improvements. (constantly and over many years)

Comment: _"if they would have an API that lets you check if a certain part of content was generated by them lately."_ The problem is that they don't store output. When the session closes, the data is gone.

Comment: /me starts working on script to add grammatical errors and mess up code a little so it looks human generated :)

Comment: In regards to _"typically no links or formatting"_, the AI does seem fond of bullet/numbered lists, though.

Comment: I don't think this -> `Answers by ChatGPT will likely have perfect grammar and punctuation is right, for me I use Grammarly to avoid such things and correct any mistakes but the post/answer is still written by me @Trilarion

Comment: @Ahmad I see it from a statistical point of view. It doesn't really matter then what a single individual does. I only speak about the average user.

Answer (score 11):

I have flagged several suspicious answers with **in need of moderator intervention** and a comment about answer contents and user behavior (usually there are a lot of low quality answers in succession in different topics) but probably it would be great to add a separate flag/closure reason/deletion reason specifically for this use case.

P.S.

Also it seems there are some AI-generated questions =)

Comment: AI generated questions? If it means no typos and proper markdown, I'm all for it

Comment: "I have flagged several suspicious answers..." To be an answer to the question here you would probably have to say a few words about what raised your suspicion in these cases. Otherwise, how does it answer the question?

Comment: @phil: Uh, no.  Can't use AI for answers?  Can't use it for questions either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey was mostly tongue in cheek but perhaps it could be useful if the prompt was something like _"reformat this question to be suitable for Stack Overflow"_

Answer (score 9):

It's easy to detect ChatGPT answers. Just look at 4 or 5 ChatGPT answers and you'll notice them almost immediately thereafter using your newly-trained basic human pattern matching abilities.

Let's practice! Here's a thread: [What is the best practice solution to embed videos from different sources in a ReactNative app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564711/what-is-the-best-practice-solution-to-embed-videos-from-different-sources-in-a-r) <sup>*[[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huO3s.jpg)]*</sup>

To make it more interesting, here's (only!) the first paragraph of each of the 6 answers, verbatim:

> To achieve the requirements you listed, I would suggest using the expo-video library instead of WebView. Here's a sample code snippet to get you started:

> To achieve the requirements you listed, I would suggest using a third-party library for video playback instead of relying solely on WebView or Expo's built-in Video component.

> There are a few different approaches you can take to embed videos from different sources in a ReactNative app, depending on your specific requirements and use case. Here are a few best practice solutions:

> There are a few challenges that need to be addressed in order to implement a seamless video experience that meets your requirements. Some of these challenges include handling device orientation changes, ensuring consistent playback across multiple video sources, and implementing a player that works well on both Android and iOS.

> You can use Amazon IVS Player for react native: [https://github.com/aws/amazon-ivs-react-native-player][1]. Its a very minimalist video player out of the box, so all the basic functionality you require would have to be implemented by the you, like rotation, autoplay, pause/continue etc. But on flip side, it can be programmed to do anything you need it to do. Plus its not a webview.

> If you want a smooth video playback that can handle rotation and multiple sources, go for the react-native-video library instead of using WebView. Here's a quick example of how to implement it:

Now test yourself: which are AI and which are human? If you're not sure based on first paragraphs, go into easy mode and view the thread or screenshot above for full context.

Great job! 5 of the answers were ChatGPT and one was human. You're ready to start flagging ChatGPT posts! (but wait, [you're on strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an), right?)

See this [meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390376#390376) for more threads you can practice on.

Comment: Perfect spelling isn't an accurate indication, though... My spellign is awlays prefect.]

Comment: No, I just used that as an easy means of identification rather than detection (although spelling can be part of the detection procedure--there's no need to itemize all of the parameters since they're intuitive, and other answers attempt that). Check out the [full thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75564711/what-is-the-best-practice-solution-to-embed-videos-from-different-sources-in-a-r) if you're unable to detect based on this and I can assure you, it'll be trivial. If you imagine the thread without the answers deleted, that's what the site will look like if SO keeps blocking mods.

Comment: Nooooo you can't just use your human intuition. You must be using some sort of tool, and tools (apart from ChatGPT of course) have flaws. Stop doing this. /s

Comment: the comical part is the OP begging not to use ChatGPT :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a few tell-tale signs that can provide a general indicator that answers and accompanying example code were pasted from ChatGPT.

Once you've seen them, it's hard not to spot them when they pop up in the wild. And while not a guarantee that the answer is AI-written, they are strong indicators that are often worth further investigation.

As for code correctness, if perfect-looking example code has a glaring error typically only caught by intellisense, something's probably wrong. ChatGPT tends to prefer explicitly naming variable types over inference, so it's rare (in my experience) to see `var foo = something()` (C#) or `auto bar = another()` (C++).

If reviewing an answer to determine if it is human or not, it's probably worth your time to paste it into an IDE, if you don't already.

### Presumptive Type Classification

Many property classes in C# provide a getter function, named the same as the class name, prefixed with `Get`. Likewise for methods returning a collection, `GetAll`. This is usually by design, but it is not always the case, especially when dealing with code introduced very early on before adopting this naming convention.

```csharp
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties(); // truth
//...
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces(); // truth
foreach (var ni in interfaces) {
  IPProperties ipProperties = ni.GetIPProperties(); // fiction
  //...
}
```

Just because the `GetIPGlobalProperties()` and `GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` methods use their class names verbatim, does not guarantee that a `GetIPProperties()` method is part of the `IPProperties` class. Indeed, such a class does not exist in the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace. `GetIPProperties()` is actually part of the `IPInterfaceProperties` class.

Similarly, the existence of an enum specifically describing common interface types (`NetworkInterfaceType`), does not mean every possible connection type in existence is included.

```csharp
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet // truth
  || ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 // truth
  || ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Bridge) // fiction
{
  //...
}
```

Both of the above errors are easily apparent when pasted into an IDE, but ultimately would go unnoticed except to the most astute programmer with significant first-hand experience using these specific .NET classes, as the following unaltered snippet from a ChatGPT response shows:

[image: AI-generated code excerpt with errors]

### Symmetric Sentences

Example code is often introduced and summarized by a single sentence, using a consistently recognizable sentence structure with very little - if any - deviation from the following:

**Standalone introduction sentences** (meaning a single-sentence paragraph) begin with:

- "To get/display ..."
- "For example, ..."

**Multi-sentence introductory paragraphs** typically use the modified form "To do this, ..." in the last sentence of the paragraph.

**Summary sentences** will begin with one of the following, with very few exceptions:

- "This will display/return ..."
- "In this example, ..."

These tend to be paired, meaning an example introduced with "For example..." will invariably be followed by a summary beginning with "In this example...". Introductions beginning with "To display..." are followed by summaries beginning with "This will display...".

Comment: It is mildly distressing that my normal way of writing answers tends to match what you've described here in the "Symmetric Sentences" section. (And my normal answers *also* often include typos in the code blocks, so maybe I am a bot after all!)

Comment: Re *"ultimately would go unnoticed except to the most astute programmer"*: I suspect this for many (most?) of the "try this" answers on Stack Overflow (code dumps without any explanation) by humans (copied from somewhere?), especially late answers. Though I could be completely wrong.

Comment: @Cody _"so maybe I am a bot after all!"_ - typical bot speak.

Comment: While I appreciate your desire to answer the question, keep in mind that the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421889/11810933) is very clear that *"publicly describing how we detect ChatGPT generated content provides those people using ChatGPT with specific information which they could use to make it more difficult for us to detect ChatGPT generated content"*  I, at least, would appreciate it if you would delete your post.  I understand that security-through-obscurity isn't a great strategy, but neither is providing information on how to circumvent detection ;-).

Comment: Might be worth noting that AI advancements in the weeks following my originally posting this, have long since made these observations obsolete.

Comment: it hasn't, though, tbh. it's still fairly easy to recognize gpt generated content just by looking at it.

Comment: @KevinB to the keen reader, yes. But you won't see the patterns I mentioned consistently anymore. More training data = more versatility in writing style = lower concentration of the nuances I mentioned. At this point it generally boils down to being grammatically "too perfect", or (except for cases when generated with a prompted tone and writing style) an absence of self identity in the writing (the "third person" persona - ie. an article written for programmers, explaining programming patterns, while never once including itself as part of that group as a programmer.)

Answer (score 0):

As the state-of-the-art AI model evolves, it may eventually be indistinguishable from human-written text. So instead of judging by arbitrary "noticeable traits", I rely on my "sense of language" to identify answers that don't "feel natural" to me. Then I check the user to see if they have just posted multiple answers in quick succession, plus other heuristics, like being new users or low-rep users. If it's a single occurrence I'd just flag accordingly (usually NAA, sometimes VLQ), and if there are multiple low-quality answers, I double-check and then raise a mod flag explaining my concern.

Comment: The very AI that writes text can be used to determine if it's likely to have written a certain text. Detection isn't a technical problem.

Comment: AFAIK, NAA and VLQ are not the right tools for this. When I suspect an AI-generated answer, I do the same checks you do and then flag them for moderator attention with a message like “Possible ChatGPT-generated answer.”

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Are you referring to OpenAI's AI Text Classifier?

Comment: @RyanM more in general. The technology that generates this text is what's used to determine if something is likely to be generated.

Answer (score -20):

Yours begs the question; What is the real problem for SO which ChatGPT creates?

It seems to me the primary issue is the rate of ingress of "seemingly good" answers, that is, answers which eat up volunteer time recognizing that while well-written, the answers are not accurate; but humans write those too, just not 20 in an hour.

So then isn't some form of user rate-limiting the solution?
(Indeed SO has done this for users < 125 rep (*good move*!))

On the Temporary ban page:
[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)

I ran into some good discussion about both rate and length of posts. Short answers are much easier to discern:

1. if they actually solve the problem
2. That they probably **did not** come from ChatGPT

Ultimately if a user is habitually pasting in text from ChatGPT, they will also be getting habitually downvoted, so that part of the problem solves itself.

Note that if that wasn't true, we'd be getting solutions and SO would celebrate and not ban ChatGPT.

It's good SO is learning ways to tell the difference, and a good idea not to publicly disclose those.

Part of the *right* answer though was suggested by @polkovnikov.ph on the link provided above:

> Clipboard API supports adding a custom mimetype to data in clipboard. If OpenAI just added a text/x-chatgpt for copied text, at least other resources would have a protection against foolest of fools that copypaste directly from their website.

because this protects ChatGPT, educators, scientists, and yes SO. Whether moderators care to reach out to OpenAI or not, I'm going to, because this is the kind of this which merits a community response.

Then if a user pastes directly from ChatGPT to an answer, the 'Answer/Submit' button can go grey with a banner 'Careful, plagiarizing ChatGPT could result in a ban'

Where users citing and refining ChatGPT answers into actual solutions will have edited out meta-text and have more to the body than just copypaste.

Stack Overflow is a place of earnest effort, where questions have a *required*: 'What have you tried?' field, and frankly, I think that form should have an added checkbox:
[x] Yes, I tried [ChatGPT first](https://chat.openai.com/auth/login)

Which again helps the rate problem (by reducing *question ingress*)

Comment: The first part seems to be missing that ChatGPT answers *look* good. They need more effort to identify as bad and may even receive significant upvotes when wrong. A rate limit would have to be (much) more severe than for human content and ambient downvoting won’t single out such posters.

Comment: "Yes I tried ChatGPT first" -> no: if ChatGPT cannot be relied upon to produce correct answers it should not be recommended as a source of information.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the internet cannot be relied upon to produce correct answers, nor can SO, indeed they are sources of information, and while chatGPT answers are seldom exactly what you were looking for usually a couple of modifications to the query (running conversation) can get you a lot closer. The proposed check-box is a step to ensure you've tried what you can before bothering busy devolopers on SO. (Same reason we're expected to search google and SO before writing a question)

Can google be relied upon to produce correct answers? Directly: No. 
But both services can help you get there.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi in either case humans are the ones copy-pasting chatGPT answers. chatGPT does not have a SO API where its pushing spam answers to SO. The problem is lazy users were copying SO questions -> chatGPT, then the AI answers strait back to SO without; testing, reviewing, refining the answer at all.
The rate limit is for human submissions, and indeed this has been one of SO's early adjustments to solve for this influx.

Comment: _"Yes, I tried chatGPT first"_ is a horrible idea, because ChatGPT is not a programmer, it doesn't understand code, it doesn't validate code...

Comment: @Cerbrus are you a programmer? can you copy-paste its output to validate? then you'll get a stack trace make 2 tweaks and 90% of the time have a solution in a fraction of the time it would have taken to google and formulate.

Work smarter not harder.

Comment: I'm indeed a programmer, and I use Codex / CoPilot instead of a language model that's not made to do code. @DeftconDelta. ChatGPT doesn't positively affect my productivity. CoPilot's impact is... meh.

Comment: @Cerbrus you can't paint everybody with your brush. Many of us make a decent living being much more generalist, and chatGPT is a good tool to get you a serious leap in a language you know almost nothing about. 
is it going to help with a language you code in everyday ABSOLUTELY NOT, chatGPT is only impressive (in any category) when you open your mind and widen the breadth of what you're trying to do, not get exact specifics. 
I hope some of this has inspired you think a little outside the box, and was hoping to benefit similarly. But you've put nil effort into your argument so, bye!

Comment: Please don't presume to know how much time and effort I've put into ChatGPT. It's not of any value to SO, and your suggestion, aside from being yet another iteration of  "Embed it", doesn't help. People lie on checkboxes they need to check to post.

Answer (score -26):

**We can't, and as such we shouldn't waste our time trying.**

ChatGPT is merely the latest and greatest iteration of GPT. As GPT continues to improve, so will the answers it generates, which in turn will make such answers more difficult to detect. The end result is an arms race between the curators of Stack Overflow and the developers of GPT - a race that we the former, with our limited personnel and resources, *cannot ever hope to win*.

But we curators are smarter than an algorithm that is nowhere near being artificially intelligent. And we *can* win, but to do so we have to think deeper than merely curating answers, and instead turn to prevention. Or in short, move the goalposts by **ensuring that all users on Stack Overflow are real human beings, not bots**.

This may sounds ridiculous and unworkable but it truly is the only way to have some sort of protection from more and more sophisticated bots based on more and more sophisticated language models. As more and more of these bots flood the Internet and begin to crowd out human-generated content with computer-generated noise, the only way for human communities where accuracy is paramount (such as Stack Overflow) to continue to function will be via identity verification.

For Stack Overflow, this sort of verification is unlikely to cause much turmoil, as many of the most trusted users already use their real names for posting the content they produce. Whether Stack Exchange Inc. is forward-thinking enough to care is the most important concern.

Of course, identity verification doesn't preclude verified users from using GPT to generate answers, but simple numbers dictate that the numbers of such users will be low, and as such ordinary curation efforts should be able to manage the detection and removal of such content and users.

Comment: _"We can't"_ That's simply not true. The very tool used to generate text can be used to detect how likely it is the text is AI-generated. There are plenty of services out there that can. Even ___if___ all users are humans, that doesn't stop them from using some AI to generate content. The whole problem here is _human_ users using AI-generated text.

Comment: _"simple numbers dictate that the numbers of such users will be low, and as such ordinary curation efforts should be able to manage the detection and removal of such content and users."_ That's the entire problem here. The number of users ___isn't___ low. The content they post is creating ___significant___ work for moderators. You're completely missing the point/reason of this ChatGPT blanket ban.

Comment: @Cerbrus How many of those users are new?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: Because new users who intend to sign up only for the purpose of spamming, are unlikely to want (or be able) to go through the effort of proving their identity. So they won't sign up at all - leading to less spam, ChatGPT or other.

Comment: And existing users will leave the platform en-masse, because ___plenty___ of users don't trust SO with their data. This has been an issue in the past with something as comparatively trivial as usernames.

Comment: So the worst case of trying to fight the low-quality answers is we end up with high-quality answers? https://xkcd.com/810/

Comment: @JohnMontgomery If you believe that a machine learning model with zero comprehension of what abstract concepts like "programming" are or entail, can **ever** provide high-quality answers about such abstract concepts except by accident, then I have nothing to say to you.

Comment: @IanKemp Your first paragraph seemed to imply that you think it could, or else why wouldn't we able to detect it?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery GPT will generate more and more answers that **appear** correct, but won't actually **be** correct. As its sophistication increases the proportion of each answer that is incorrect will continue to shrink, but that doesn't matter: one syntax error is the same to a compiler as one thousand. However, as each answer becomes proportionally more correct, it also becomes proportionally more difficult for a human to detect the fundamental incorrectness that invalidates said answer in its entirety.

Comment: This is uninformed. OpenAI themselves have released tools to detect if something was generated from ChatGPT or not. They have no interested in disguising the output from the bot as something else, quite the contrary. So detecting it is rather a race between OpenAI and OpenAI... and in that race I'm fairly certain that OpenAI can hope to win. SO just have to use their tool intended for this purpose.

Comment: Re *"turn to prevention"*: Yes, after the fact is just band-aid. But it doesn't have to be identity. As most of the post spammers are trying to do the least amount of work (which is why ChatGPT has replaced regular plagiarism), only a tiny amount of friction needs to be added to prevent most such posts. I don't know what form it would take; the most obvious ones are probably easy to circumvent.

Answer (score -37):

You can detect the explanations, but not the code because the code could come from anywhere or ChatGPT might just be reading content from a programming language's official site.

Why would you ban code generated by ChatGPT when other users will post the same exact code from either Python's official documentation site, Java, or C#? So just let it go; don't even try to detect as some other moderators advised. Detect the code explanations or code that does not compile posted from ChatGPT, otherwise just stand down.

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't answer with only code. This whole ban only really affect those that blindly copy-paste the output, any way, so your whole "don't detect the code" is completely irrelevant.

Comment: You guys will struggle and won't be able to completely quarantine SO from GPT code and content

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't *copy* content, including code. It *generates* content using a large language model. While it's *possible* the generated code is the same as some code in the material used to train ChatGPT, it's unlikely that someone will be able to find *exactly* the same code from somewhere else. If ChatGPT *copied* code from somewhere, the code would probably be *better*, because the copied code would likely have been tested, rather than generated by a model that just puts "words" together in ways it thinks "fit", based on its model with *no actual understanding nor functional checking*.

Comment: _"You guys will struggle and won't be able to completely quarantine SO from GPT code and content"_ These blanket statements are just nonsense... Of course _some_ posts will slip through. This whole rule exists so mods have somewhere to point users they're suspending for ChatGPT use. No arguments, no ifs or buts.

Comment: "*You can detect the explanations, but not the code*", well, this not true (at least in the small Tag I follow/answer ('iMacros' for Web-Automation))... // iMacros Code generated by 'ChatGPT' is *hilarious* and fairly easy to spot because 'ChatGPT' creates Commands that simply don't exist in that Prog-Language by *borrowing* Commands/Methods from "popular" other Languages (usually JS/PHP/C++) and trying to apply them in iMacros Scripts with some very approx Syntax, ... that of course doesn't even compile. And such Code is very easy to detect for any Advanced User in that Language.