# Why was my answer deleted for using ChatGPT even when I didn't?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, moderation, chatgpt

I'm a new contributor trying to get more into helping on Stack Overflow, and after spending a while writing up an answer, it was deleted because it seems like I used ChatGPT.

It might have been a mistake since after I answered it the asker edited the post to ask a follow-up question to my answer, so it looked like I didn't properly answer the question.

Sorry if it sounds like I'm making a big deal out of nothing, but it's very annoying after I spent my own time helping someone else, just for someone else to delete it all and accuse me of writing it with a robot.

Here's the link - as it is deleted I'll add a screenshot also. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74754627/14769987

[image: screenshot of the deleted answer]

Comment: Did you try asking in a flag rather than meta?

Comment: There will be bumps in the road with the chatGPT ban -- that's to be expected, but overall, the ban was the right call. Your case is one of those bumps in the road that the moderators should be able to remedy. (and good for your for following through with the issue)

Comment: Maybe we can change the requirements for the [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge. Sounds like you deserve it... ^_^

Comment: This is essentially going to be the real question. Not "How do we recognise ChatGPT answers", but "how do I make my own answers not look like ChatGPT". Man that AI is going to make life miserable.

Comment: fortunately, after the first test phase it's going to become a commercial service. No freebies to post trash then.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre wow, an actual example of where commercialism saves the day. I hope greed is also involved here, so it happens sooner rather than later :)

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine how to ask in a flag?

Comment: Select "post in need moderator intervention". You will get a text prompt, there you can ask questions.

Comment: All I can say is please error on the side of caution.  Make sure something is generated by a bot before marking it as such.  If in doubt, assume it was written by a human.  This is supposed to be a welcoming community!

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Please don't use flags to question/dispute moderator actions, that's not what they are for. Creating a meta [tag:support] post is the most appropriate.

Comment: This *really* looks like a bot answer.

Comment: @AndrewAllen How did you recognize it? To me it looks like an average answer on SO. But then I'm not an expert in that field.

Comment: @Trilarion Overly-formal phrasing ("Rather than", "whereas") and general structure (paragraph of explanation -> "Here's an example" single sentence that's longer than necessary because it duplicates context (mentioning the function again) -> code) are what set it off for me.

Comment: @Izkata Just had a look at some of my early answers from almost 10 years ago. I wasted time on sentences like: "So what you have to do is something like", "So my answer would be" and "I now found that it can be done as follows". Not very great writing, but also not a dead-sure bot signature.

Comment: Simple: You didn't pass the Turing test. Sorry.

Comment: @Lundin Please do use flags to dispute/question moderator actions, doing at least one follows a clear escalation path, there's every possibility a simple mistake was made and a flag is the best way to handle that. If a flag doesn't result in the action you expect, that's when meta is useful, not as a first stop.

Comment: @AndrewAllen can you at least explain what makes you say it *really* looks like a bot answer? Because to me it really *does not*. Just making flat statements is so disappointing, provide arguments so others like me can learn something. Or dispute it with counterarguments.

Comment: @Gimby I’ve nothing much to add since comments following mine perfectly encapsulates what I’m thrusting at. I’d expect “Here’s how you’d use” from human over “Here’s an example of how you could use”. Bot answers tend to hedge. Compare to users last answer “you’ll have to”, “you should”. Lack of a human signal like punctuation errors. Take Jean’s answer. There’s a full stop for the 1st bullet point and not for the others. It’s rare to not have any errors yet not for OP answer. Like I said, not accusing but saying it is suspicious.

Comment: After reading through the comments and answer below I can understand why your answer was deleted, but I don't understand why it's *still deleted.* If the reason for deletion was that the mod thought it was a bot answer, now that we know it's not, that action should be immediately reversed.

Comment: Fighting against ChatGPT is pointless. If the ChatGPT gives a good answer the community should bubble that answer to the top. If ChatGPT gives a bad answer, it will get voted down. I don't understand the backlash honestly. I do not agree with this call by SO. I don't use and probably will not use ChatGPT since they ask for way too much info to use it ( why TF do they need my phone number?), but it's just another tool. GitHub Co-pilot has been amazing and actually keeps me in my work flow rather than task switching to my browser and SO.

I see how that isn't great for the SO business model

Comment: @LouisDuran that is well covered by the original post that explains the ban: the chatGPT answers *look correct but aren't* and we're getting too many of them for effective policing. We *already* have a huge problem with answers that are incorrect or outdated, this is making it 10x worse. Look, I feel for the OP and that sucks and hopefully it gets undeleted but it's a mess.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Oh god, I'm definitely a bot then. Hedging and using proper punctuation?  It's not that bots hedge that gives them away, but the fact that they hedge *irrelevantly*. They bridge together concepts which don't naturally complement each other, often with a transition that doesn't match the distinction between the two ideas or tones. I do hope we're not to be marked down for using punctuation going forward though!

Comment: I'm surprised hedging is considered a tell-tale sign at all. My belief is that ChatGPT is considered harmful because it *confidently* makes \*\*\*\* up.

Comment: @Louis Duran: For that purpose (of getting access to ChatGPT), just buy a cheap prepaid SIM card, put it into a dedicated device only for this purpose, don't power it on, start the registration process, and at the end move yourself away from your current location (the timeout is about 10 minutes, so that is about 5 minutes one way), get the code, power off the phone, move back, and enter the code. It is easier if you have a co-conspirator; then the physical separation can be several hundred kilometers. Or do the registration at a place you will not return to.

Comment: The phone number thing is for the slowing down bots from automatic account creation. That is why *some* of those bot farms are full of SIM cards (the increased cost and hassle is deemed worth it for the operators).

Answer (score 123):

We had a "ChatGPT" attack this week. Most of answers were rather generic, and contained that exact sentence start:

> Here's an example of how you could use ...

Followed by example/generic code that isn't related at all to OP code (and even gets puzzled comments).

So your answer looks very much like a generated ChatGPT answer (even if some other "dead giveaway" parts are missing) which explains that it was deleted.

I've reasons to believe you because

- I tried hard to generate an approaching answer with ChatGPT and failed.
- The answer is within your domain of expertise
- You didn't flood the site with other generic answers since ChatGPT was made available

But the answer seems not tailored to the OP question at all and may very well have been generated at first sight. It was even flagged "not an answer". Not a great answer to the OP question in the current form.

I suggest that you edit it to make it less generic and more related to the original question, and then flag for moderator attention so we can decide if we undelete it.

Comment: What is the idea of deleting answers under the argument that they were apparently created by an AI? It makes much more sense to explain that the answer was deleted because it is not related to the question asked or because the answer belongs to a user who has a proven track record of spamming, which is more objective and saves moderators from having to get into a ton of complex discussions. If an answer is not quality (whether it was created by an AI or not) it will easily fall to the bottom.

Comment: @Tedpac: ChatGPT crap creates a much higher moderation burden than manually-written crap, while taking extremely low effort to post. We don't have the expert resources to carefully read through all the AI crap and verify, yup, it's crap again. Plus, low-quality or wrong answers get upvoted and accepted all the time. They don't just "easily fall to the bottom".

Comment: @Tedpac please read [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/2821954). You probably won't believe it if you didn't see it by yourself, but at that time, too many users flooded the site with ChatGPT answers *as-is* and not caring whether the answer is correct or not (because they actually don't have expertise on that tech stack), and even got accepted by the OP (because they usually don't know better). Wrong answers are not a reason for deletion, AI-generated answers are.

Comment: @user2357112, I honestly don't understand the "much higher", because regardless of whether a response was written by a human or an AI, a moderator will read it, but what will certainly create a higher moderation burden is having to review cases of users who had their responses deleted because they were apparently written by an AI. This situation will worsen as NLP models become more sophisticated, as it will become increasingly difficult to discern between a response that was written by a human and one that was not.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that it is much more accurate and fair to judge a user by their history (e.g., if their frequency of posting responses is exceptionally high) than by a particular response that they gave, plus, algorithms for detecting rogue users would be easier to implement.

Comment: Wait, so now mods are deleting answers because they think they're ChatGPT without even verifying? and how is this answer considered "generic code"?

Comment: @java-addict301, how would you propose that they verify? Unless the poster admits to it (which I've seen a few times) there's often no way to know for sure.

Comment: @Tedpac ChatGPT is a text generator, not a fact generator. It takes seconds for ChatGPT to generate a plausible-looking answer and longer for a human with subject matter expertise to identify the answer as factually wrong. There was an obvious wave of this nonsense recently, mostly copy/pasted by new or low-rep accounts. If you spent time in the review queues you would know that human effort to moderate that wave of junk is grossly outmatched by ChatGPT's ability to generate junk.

Comment: @Chris I think mods should focus first on verifying if an answer is correct rather than worrying so much about whether ChatGPT was involved.  Let's face it; ChatGPT is just the first of very many.

Comment: @java-addict301, please read [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577) and [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy). There are some very good reasons for doing this. For now, it's only temporary.

Comment: @Chris I have read the policy and I agree, however deleting even one valid answer in the quest to stop ChatGPT is like SO cutting off its nose to spite its face so to speak, and will ultimately do far more damage to the community than allowing ChatGPT answers (IMO).  See OP's disposition - "Sorry if it sounds like I'm making a big deal out of nothing, but it's very annoying after I spent my own time helping someone else, just for someone else to delete it all and accuse me of writing it with a robot".  This is not sustainable.

Comment: @java-addict301: Due to a hopefully-short-term flood of essentially trolls posting bad answers (or children playing with loaded guns), we unfortunately have to take drastic measures to keep up with it.  When there is some unfortunate collateral damage (false positive identification of answers as being ChatGPT), well-intentioned humans can communicate and get it sorted out.  This is not ideal, but there simply isn't time for experts and/or mods to spend carefully reading all answers that smell GPT-generated in case there's something useful, instead of doing more valuable with their time.

Comment: And yes, all the ChatGPT answers I've seen in the tags I follow (assembly, cpu-architecture, etc.) have been bad, off-topic at best, full of wrong facts at worst.  Apparently some people have had success getting the bones of an answer from ChatGPT and hand-editing it to fix bugs in the almost-working code it generated, but the problem is people who aren't doing that, instead posting the raw garbage.

Comment: ... and get upvotes for that.

Comment: linking to a heavily downvoted answer of yours isn't really useful

Comment: @PeterCordes "full of wrong facts" - A fact can't be wrong by the very definition of the word. Mistakes. But in this context I would even go as far as to call them lies.

Comment: @Tedpac *regardless of whether a response was written by a human or an AI, a moderator will read it* - so you think the moderators read every answer on SO? How could they and why should they do that? It's not their task and totally beyond their capacity. They'll read an answer if someone flags it.

Comment: @gimby you mention context in your comment about "wrong facts". Facts which are facts in one context can be wrong in another. "Windows are transparent" is a fact but wrong in the context of operating systems. "Windows is an operating system" is a fact, but wrong in the context of glazing. Exactly the sort of thing AIs struggle to understand. In the context of a discussion about AIs, "wrong facts" seems appropriate.

Comment: @Tedpac tell me, did you read 192 answers? In one day, I mean. It's very important to answer because [on Sunday, 11th of December 2022 there were 4998 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2022-12-11..2022-12-12). Of course that's just the ones that are still visible - sans all the deleted ones for any reason. But it's still a number we can work with. [We have 26 moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). And I'm being generous, not all are active. But still. 4998 / 26 = 192.23 answers per mod to read. Did *you* read that many? In one day.

Comment: @Tedpac I should also note that was on **Sunday**. Activity is usually lower. [There are 10 480 answer from last Monday](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2022-12-05..2022-12-06), [10 893 on Tuesday](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2022-12-06..2022-12-07), [10 709 on Wednesday](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2022-12-07..2022-12-08), [10 029 on Thursday](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2022-12-08..2022-12-09), and [7 772 on Friday](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2022-12-09..2022-12-10).

Comment: and even if the moderators would read hundreds of answers, they can't be experts in all the languages, databases, technologies, etc.

Comment: «I suggest that you edit it to make it less generic» is this shift-of-burden suggested in the help center? I mean, is up to legit "human" users to make their posts recognizible as non-CGPT contents?

Comment: @java-addict301 yes, it's the first of many automated bullshit generators that's good enough to pass cursory inspection (actually, that's a lie as GPT-3 has now been around for 2 years) and *all* automated bullshit generators will be banned as they crop up.

Comment: @GrafiCode if you get help from CGPT content (I didn't say _paste it_) and your answer isn't detected as GPT and it works and you get votes, there should be no problem. But the answers it gives are so generic and vague (and/or wrong) that you're better off writing an answer manually. Besides I'm pretty much convinced that OP answer wasn't generated by ChatGPT.

Comment: You mentioned "*Followed by example/generic code that isn't related at all to OP code*" as justification for deleting ChatGPT answers, but didn't discuss whether the author's code here is generic code or whether it's relevant/correct for the question it is answering. That seems to me to be the most important consideration here, by far.

Comment: @Tedpac "*regardless of whether a response was written by a human or an AI, a moderator will read it*" You are sorely mistaken if you think moderators read all answers. Even non-diamond moderators combined with diamond moderators are only able to view a fraction of the total number of posts on the site. You would need at least an order of magnitude more moderators than there are today, maybe two orders.

Comment: "Bogons" are here.  Neil Stephenson has foreseen the problem of "good crap vs bad crap" and "Artificial Inanity" programs (see his [_Anathem_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anathem)).  Can't wait for the ROBEs to show up - or are they already around?  ("ROBE": "Rampant Orphaned Botnet Ecologies".)

Comment: "I've reasons to believe you ..." Then the answer should probably be undeleted, if only to not drive genuine humans away from the site.

Comment: OP failed their Turing test.

Comment: @Gimby: When I wrote "wrong facts", I meant "false statements" as the basis for conclusions.  Like in the deleted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74710329/224132 which begins "*%ax is a 16-bit register, while %ds and %eax are 32-bit registers*".  But in reality, x86 segment registers like DS are 16-bit.  The answer goes on to total nonsense: "*In order to move a value from %ax to %ds, the assembler must first extend the value in %ax to a 32-bit value in %eax, and then move that value to %ds. This is why the assembled instruction uses %eax instead of %ax.*

Comment: @MaxAllan: See my prev comment about [why does mov %ax, %ds assemble+disassemble as mov %eax,%ds, inconsistent with the original?](//stackoverflow.com/q/74689479): No context could make the statement correct.  `%ds` is unambiguously an x86 segment register in any context; AT&T syntax decorating reg names with `%` makes it pretty unique. If I had to guess, the AI might have "learned" from answers about `mov` normally (except with Sreg) requiring its operands to be the same size, so `mov %cx, %eax` won't assemble, a *programmer* has to change the code to `movzwl %cx, %eax` or `mov %ecx, %eax`

Comment: @MaxAllan: So yeah, things that were totally wrong in any context, presented as facts, as the basis and/or conclusion of an answer.  Perhaps ChatGPT does somewhat less bad with code in other more common languages, or with actual code instead of trying to explain why.  (SO answers that explain why are somewhat rarer, but I think are some of the most valuable, or at least the ones I prefer to write.)  Another ChatGPT answer on a debugging question basically reposted the OP's assembly code without changing the buggy loop at all, IIRC.

Comment: Yeah, I think it looks generic because the asker edited his original question to ask a follow-up question to my answer after I posted it, so it looked like I basically repeated the question back to him. But thanks for clarifying why this happened, I'll take it onboard

Comment: the code works, all the variable names line up and the code makes sense and would compile -- that can not be said for ChatGPT code, plus the introductory text is perfectly sensical and uses clearly followable human reasoning with references to antecedents that make perfect sense, which AI is also not capable of doing, so this is ridiculous

Comment: @Trilarion should the answer be undeleted in its current state? probably not. First because I wasn't the mod who deleted, then it needs rework even if it's not A.I. generated (that would collect downvotes because of the meta-effect right now, let's it collect upvotes instead)

Comment: @TylerH It seems to me that most of the people whining about this just don't have a clue about how much effort curation of this site takes (let alone how much is actually needed). A quick look at the voting activity in their profile usually says it all. Just in the case of the user you're responding to... 50-odd votes in 4 years, 3 of those downvotes...

Comment: @DanMašek 50 votes is probably more than what 90% of users do. I wouldn't hold that against the user. An on the other hand, moderators running around deleting random answers (out of millions of bad answers) isn't the answer to the curation issue either. We must find a middle ground somewhere and there must be proper procedure or the new wave of bot answers will only result in a witch hunt.

Comment: *"I suggest that you edit it to make it less generic and more related to the original question, and then flag for moderator attention so we can decide if we undelete it."* - I disagree with this.  The answer should be immediately undeleted.  The deletion reason was a mistake and now that we have sufficient evidence of this, it should not be up to the OP to make a change to their answer or raise a flag.  I'm pretty sure @Martijn Pieters is aware of this thread and knows the OP's feeling about what happened.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue: The main argument for not doing that immediately is to avoid meta-effect downvotes on an answer that apparently isn't very good.  The question does already two other answers, one of which is accepted.  If not for that, yeah, immediate undeletion would be appropriate once the user has said it wasn't a ChatGPT answer; being wrong or misunderstanding what kind of help the question is looking for isn't usually a deletion reason.  IDK if the author of that answer currently wants it undeleted given all those factors; if so, I hope mods would be willing to do so as is.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I get it, but I say let the answer garner votes as the community sees fit. While it may be out of best intentions and consideration for the author, I don't really think leaving the answer deleted in order to soften a theoretical slew of downvotes is the correct course of action.

Comment: Its kind of interesting that some good fitting ChatGPT are deleted because of ChatGPT. On the other hand humans are allowed to answer a question by e.g. saying something like "I recommend to read the docu". Personally I prefer a chatgpt that tries to solve the problem more or less over persons that are not contributing or are hypocritical/rude. Looks like double standards against the AI.

Comment: the debate about chatgpt is done. That ship has sailed. No need to debate the usefulness of chatgpt answers here.