# Lost reputation from deleted bountied answers doesn't automatically get counted

Tags: bug, reputation, bounty, deleted-answers, reputation-history

I recently cast the last delete-vote required to delete a user's [GPT-generated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76707706/1835379).
The answer had a bounty of 500 reputation.

The user's reputation counters still show their rep as if they were awarded this bounty. I would expect the answer deletion to update the user's reputation in (close to) real-time, just like normal votes would.

I just came across that 4-day-old user (22237204) and noticed he had over 650 reputation.

Nothing shocking, at first sight, but seeing as how the user only has 5 (non-deleted) answers, none of which have a positive score, I was wondering where all that rep came from.

He's not been active suggesting edits.
His reputation page shows a couple of upvotes and the association bonus:

[image]

Apparently, the deleted bounty, though gone from the reputation history, has not yet recalculated the user's reputation.

Comment: Most likely deleted answer, takes time for rep synch to run. (i.e. cache.)

Comment: Maybe a bounty not showing up?

Comment: Ooh, I delete-voted one of the user's answers. That might've had a bounty.

Comment: _"I just came across a 4-day-old user (22237204) that has over 650 reputation"_ - could it just be that they're brilliant? Oh, no, ChatGPT, of course. And vehemently denying that they use that, of course. Hey Prashanth, is this the way you want the site to go?

Comment: ^ Which was why I delete-voted that answer, it was an extremely obvious GPT post. I don't recall them actually denying it, just avoiding the subject by shifting blame to the users asking him whether or not he's used GPT.

Comment: The fact the user has already made 27 upvotes suggests to me that they are could possibly be part of a voting ring as well.

Comment: I could have sworn we had a duplicate for the core issue, but I can't find it now. (I mean, the site's issue with reputation accounting, not the ChatGPT usage.)

Comment: Another example can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424264/someone-answered-my-question-i-accepted-and-awarded-bounty-and-then-the-answer), the OP in that question offered the bounty and *it looks like it was not refunded*. So I assume the user that received the bounty would also have 50 rep missing in their graph, because it doesn't include deleted posts. -> looks like its by design, still feels weird though

Comment: Additionally also found this [How are bounties awarded to ChatGPT-sourced answerers handled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422327/how-are-bounties-awarded-to-chatgpt-sourced-answerers-handled), the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422335/5515060) from DavidW also mentions that the bounty *should* be refunded on deletion.

Comment: @Lino this deletion wasn't from a mod action, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh, so it'll only get refunded when it was mod-deleted?

Comment: @Lino afaik, bounties being refunded is an exceptional case that can only be done by moderators, yes.

Comment: [If there's ever any doubt about that user using ChatGPT](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56504977#56504977) That's literally how ChatGPT responds to being corrected.

Comment: I think this [line](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56505021#56505021) is also very indicative due to that random double quote (`"`) at the end; it's from when they copied and pasted that from ChatGPT when it gave them options on how to respond to you, @Cerbrus .

Comment: Looks like the reputation has been recalculated now. Whether automatically or due to manual intervention who knows?

Comment: @Cerbrus: Yes, it reads like an [ELIZA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) transcript.

Comment: Gotta love the periodic flips between "Hugo Award nominee" and "Can't write a 10 word sentence without a muck-up".

Comment: @Cerbrus What I like most about the chat is this reply: "Unfortunately, as an AI language model, I don't have information about specific website accessibility restrictions in different regions." [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56505007#56505007)

Comment: Ironically their profile description can be read as “they are a learning programming machine” which is “eager to know ML”. The obvious differences in writing styles makes the use of ChatGPT obvious far beyond that of somebody just using it to correct their grammatical errors despite the fact they claimed a knowledge of the English language. Their profile description makes that isn’t the case.

Answer (score 23):

The usual explanation is bounties. I don't know if they show up in that view. I think they really ought to, if they don't.

However, I can't let this pass without addressing the elephant in the room.

The user in question vehemently denies (in comments) using ChatGPT to write answers, and has been getting rather heated about it, claiming to have reported comments, questioning whether people have "considered the implications if your statement turns out to be incorrect" and so forth.

Here is a sample of "the user's writing", from the most recent undeleted answer:

> The `DownloadAndRenameImages` procedure is responsible for iterating through the rows and downloading the images. For each image, it also calls the `RenameShape` procedure to rename the picture using the value from cell "A". The `RenameShape` procedure creates a temporary shape using the `AddPicture` method, assigns the new name, and then deletes the shape.

Here is a sample of the user's writing, from the profile page:

> I'm learning programming machine and eager know machine learning. I have started programming in student LOGO programming language in 1993. Now I'm in python.

Another answer shows a bizarre inconsistency in displayed level of English proficiency - consistent with copying and pasting ChatGPT content into an attempt at a hand-written answer:

> Now, when call the toWeirdCase function with a string, it will alternate the case of characters while ignoring spaces.
>
> ```
> console.log(toWeirdCase("asdfghjkl")); // Output: "AsDfGhJkL"
> console.log(toWeirdCase("hello world")); // Output: "HeLlO WoRlD"
> ```
>
> Note: The updated function assumes that you want to ignore spaces while alternating the case of alphabetic characters. If you also want to ignore other non-alphabetic characters, you can modify the condition in the if statement accordingly.

> Hope this help you.

The shift from making basic errors in verb conjugation, to perfectly writing complex sentence structures straight out of a high school essay, and back again, is rather striking.

(Aside from that: the corresponding code offered is nonsensical, and spaces aren't actually ignored. This prose does accurately describe the behaviour of the code; but the desired output for `toWeirdCase("hello world")` is presumably `"HeLlO wOrLd"` instead. The code uselessly "skips" spaces by conditionally "not uppercasing" them; but of course this has no effect on the result, as JavaScript allows uppercasing a space just fine, and the result is just an ordinary space.)

For that matter, those comments themselves read like ChatGPT output in many cases:

> Undermining efforts and devaluing answers to questions can occur when making incorrect statements. Disregarding the rules and regulations of commenting on [When shouldn't I comment in Stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) diminishes the hard work of contributors. While considering the possibility of your viewpoint being correct, it's important to use the specialized chat for debates and speculations rather than publicly expressing such statements. Please raise your concerns in the appropriate chat for a response and resolution.

This is exactly the sort of thing I would expect ChatGPT to output when suitably instructed. It presents a lot of prose that superficially refers to policy, but it doesn't have a clue what the policy actually is (there is no "specialized chat" relevant to the topic), makes up page titles, and takes on a bizarrely academic tone that makes no sense in context.

For how much longer would the company like to pretend that it is not possible in principle to detect answers written by ChatGPT; or that moderators, while not on strike, had any significant error rate in doing so?

Especially when there seems to be evidence that such answers are written in an attempt to collect bounties?

Comment: _"The user in question vehemently denies"_ Did he? I can only find him avoiding answering that. (And threatening with _"implications "_ of those accusations)

Comment: There was mention in the Meta chat room of such denial; I didn't investigate it too closely, but that seemed to be the underlying purpose of the comments you're talking about. "Avoiding answering that" while also aggressively threatening people, claiming to have reported comments, presenting as if offended by the mere suggestion etc.... comes across to me as a denial.

Comment: Another example read (with a ping): "Your message violates Stack Overflow rules. It is an unethical and disrespectful comment. Before disrespecting and devaluing someone's efforts, consider the harm it causes. If you can, provide helpful answers like I do, assisting programmers and those interested in this field. If you can't contribute, why show disrespect? I'll report your comment as per the site's rules, respecting all programming enthusiasts." The underlying premise is some supposition that comments are *not allowed* to raise suspicion of ChatGPT usage.

Comment: (`"HeLlO WoRlD"` is actually the correct output for that function, you might wanna update that here)

Comment: To me, that doesn't look like denial, it looks like a counter-attack to try to scare off users with made-up rules.

Comment: "is actually the correct output for that function" - OP showed simpler code (i.e., without a pointless check) that gives the same result, and then complained "I tried this but it does not account for the spaces between the character. How can I set it to ignore spaces?". Since the given code gives the result `"HeLlO WoRlD"` but does not satisfy OP, I can only assume the desired output is `"HeLlO wOrLd"`.

Comment: Ah, I see, so on top of it being GPT-generated, the answer is _wrong_ :D

Comment: That's what I meant with the "spaces aren't ignored" part, yeah.

Comment: The user can't show denial, because GPT (that generated probably all of that users comments) thinks that it's right. -> Also the overuse of links to help pages is hilarious.

Comment: It *looks* like the user might be using ChatGPT to reword their questions too. Their [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76715756) from yesterday has perfect grammar (and it's not been edited by someone like Peter ;) ).

Comment: Even their comments seem AI generated to me, they say: "_It provided clear steps and sample code for implementing an AJAX request_" to an answer that tells them not to use AJAX and to use a websocket instead and doesn't provide any sample code for implementing that either...

Comment: *"Did he? I can only find him avoiding answering that. "* Check the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693074/select-images-and-rename-with-cell-value/76716839#comment135252993_76716839) @Cerbrus . That's a *very* strong denial that the posts aren't GPT generated.

Comment: No, that's just him trying to shift blame onto the users asking him if he used an AI, @ThomA. He's claiming the accusations are baseless and "inhumane", he's asking people to "prove" he's using AI. He's playing the victim, ignorance and _"you got nothing"_ cards. If he didn't use AI, why wouldn't he just __say so__?

Comment: I'd say that's a denial, @Cerbrus . Those aren't the actions of someone that isn't guilty in my opinion.

Comment: @ThomA Imo, those _are_ the actions of someone that knows they're guilty. Trying to shift the subject. Trying to make others feel quilty for daring to question his integrity, even going as far as to threaten with repercussions.

Comment: *"Imo, those* are *the actions of someone that knows they're guilty"* So we're in agreement.

Comment: @ThomA Eh, actually, yes, in that aspect. But I think it's not a direct denial, it's a _"Hey look over there!"_

Comment: [Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76707706/447356).

Comment: FYI, @Cerbrus , you *might* have been able to therefore find it in your *[delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/?tab=votes&sort=deletion)* page; though I don't know how often you delete vote (there could be lots) and the page doesn't show the author's name, so you'd have to click through each.

Comment: @ThomA I completely forgot there's a page for those...

Comment: Meanwhile, that user [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76719744/1835379) his deleted answer...

Comment: Seeing the comment exchange on the re-deleted answer, it seems crystal clear to me that the user is a troll using ChatGPT to protest the removal as well.

Comment: Note that it's often very hard to tell the truly clueless from the troll. I'm tempted to apply Hanlon's Razor here even though the alternative to malicious trolling is probably more insulting.

Comment: The denial thing is just modern human nature to be honest. Even in the face of irrefutable evidence people will still play dumb because they have nothing to lose in doing so, and having a sense of personal honour is kind of a thing of the past. Present company excluded, of course.