# Not real sure why this answer was deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Not real sure why this answer was deleted. It appears to at least attempt to answer the question. In fact, the answer is of higher quality than the question itself.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75033298/2296441

It was deleted by a mod! So please help me understand.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are looking to contest mod decision, or explanation from mod team on that particular action, or generally why the question should be deleted?

Comment: I got a good answer. I just didn't see the problem with the answer.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at this again, another point of clarification. Why all the down votes here? It all feels like "shut up and go away. If you don't know how things work here you shouldn't be posting, even to gain understanding."

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The answer has all the hallmarks of a ChatGPT created answer. I tried pasting it into one of the common ChatGPT detectors and it confirmed it.

As such it breaks the [policy banning ChatGPT](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) and was therefore correctly deleted by a moderator.

Comment: I don't exactly disagree but the answer isn't authoritative since you're not a mod.  While we can suspect that this is the reason it's better if we *didn't* accuse this person of being a witch until the Constables™ were able to prove that they couldn't float.

Comment: Given the 7 day ban, and the fact that it was deleted by a mod, and the fact that it's a gpt answer,

Comment: @RobertLongson:  That's kinda what I'm getting at - not a mod *here*. I knew you had a diamond somewhere but I couldn't recall where.

Comment: Using /tools i can even verify that this user posted 4 such answers within a very short timespan that are all now deleted

Comment: One other note @RobertLongson:  I'm making a *very* explicit statement that [it's really not my place to guess on these things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421946/1079354); it's the moderation's team to execute, perform and own any actions related to ChatGPT deletions.  Yes there's a pattern to these, and yes there will be people who are curious as to what happened, but it's explicitly not going to be my place to try to read tea leaves about it.  Again, I don't exactly disagree, but I'm simply going to stay in my lane about it all.

Comment: @Makoto I think there are two ways to read the question "I disagree with mod decision, should not be deleted" and "Why the specific mod deleted the specific question" - I read it the former way (and looks like Rober too), while you read it the latter way, but both interpretations look fair to me and hence the answer is ok.

Comment: This answer is correct. The user's recent answers were deleted because they violated the ban on ChatGPT generated content.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The question was not a disagreement with the mod decision because I didn't know the basis of the decision. Now that I understand the basis of the decision, I understand the action.